# unsigned variable is behaving like signed

Tags: c, linux, gcc

This is the code,

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                     
int main()
{
    unsigned int i = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    if (i == -1)
        printf("signed variable\n");
    else
        printf("unsigned variable\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output,

```
signed variable
```

**Why is** `i`**'s value** `-1` **even it is declared as unsigned?**
**Is it something related to implicit type conversations?**

This is the build environment,

```
Ubuntu 14.04, GCC 4.8.2
```

Comment: Look at the type promotion rules in C when unlike types are compared or involved in operations together. When you compare `i == -1`, the value `-`1` is cast to unsigned, and then it's compared. In this case, `-1` becomes `0xFFFFFFFF` and then matches `i`.

Comment: Section 6.3.1.8, Usual arithmetic conversions, of C99 described at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087992/unsigned-int-and-signed-char-comparison.

Comment: There is a good answer to the question in the following post 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863153/why-unsigned-int-0xffffffff-is-equal-to-int-1

Comment: If, (and you should), compile with warnings enabled (e.g. `-Wall -Wextra`), you will be warned at compile time of the comparison between signed/unsigned types. You have just found the reason for the warnings. Heed them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `==` operator causes its operands to be promoted to a common type according to C's promotion rules. Converting -1 to `unsigned` yields `UINT_MAX`.

Answer (score 1):

`i`'s value is `0xFFFFFFFF`, which is exactly the same as `-1`, at least when the later is converted to an unsigned integer. And this is exactly what is happening with the comparison operators:

> If both of the operands have arithmetic type, the usual arithmetic conversions are performed. [...]
>
> [N1570 $6.5.9/4]

`-1` in two's complement is "all bits set", which is also what `0xFFFFFFFF` for an `unsigned int` (of size 4) is.