# Why sizeof(int) is not greater than -1?

Tags: c++, c, sizeof

this is my C code :
why is the output   "False "  ?????

why 4 > -1???

code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    if (sizeof(int) > -1)
        printf("True");
    else
        printf("False");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because `sizeof(int)` yields `4` usually and `-1` is casted to `unsigned int` which yields `0x7FFFFFFF`

Comment: Enable compiler warnings, and the compiler will tell you.

Comment: -1 not the real code (`main` must have a function result type).

Comment: Usually I'm not countervoting, but I see no reason here to downvote. It's a dupe nothing more, nothing less (even it's a hard to find one for a new user).

Comment: [Why is −1 > sizeof(int)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3100365/995714)

Answer (score 11):

Because sizeof(int) is unsigned. So -1 is converted to a large unsigned value.

Answer (score 4):

Because `sizeof` yields a value of type `size_t` which is an unsigned type. In `>` expression usual arithmetic conversions will convert `-1` to an unsigned type which is the type of the `>` result. The resulting value will be a huge positive value.

To get the expected behavior use:

```
(int) sizeof (int) > -1
```