# Why #define is not working in for loop?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

In this program the `TOTAL_ELEMENTS` calculates properly when not used in for loop. And the first printf prints properly. But why the 2nd printf is not working even if the condition in the loop is true. `TOTAL_ELEMENTS` returns `7`. And `-1<7-2` i.e `-1<5`is true. So what is wrong here?

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define TOTAL_ELEMENTS (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))
int array[] = {23,34,12,17,204,99,16};

int main()
{
int d;
printf("Total= %d\n", TOTAL_ELEMENTS);
for(d=-1;d <= (TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2);d++)
printf("%d\n",array[d+1]);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466857/why-sizeofint-is-not-greater-than-1?lq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `sizeof` returns an `unsigned` value. Therefore, the entire expression

```
TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2
```

is considered `unsigned`. The next thing that happens is that the comparison `d <= (TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2)` is considered an unsigned comparison. However, `-1` in `unsigned` representation is the largest possible value, so `<=` is evaluated as `false` from the first iteration.

You can force a signed comparison by adding an explicit cast:

```
for(d=-1;d <= (int)((TOTAL_ELEMENTS)-2);d++)
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/cx5mdK)

Comment: I thought that sizeof is returning a signed integer.

Comment: the sizeof can be considered as an unsigned long !!@PankajMahato

Comment: @user12448 You can only say that for some platforms. `sizeof expr` and `sizeof(type)` results in a value of type `size_t`. `size_t` is actually a `typedef` for an unsigned type, and it is declared in a few header files. On my 64-bit Windows machine, `size_t` is 64-bit while `unsigned long` is 32-bit. Assuming they are the same can lead to problems.

Comment: For the `long int` it actually depends on the architecture ! in 64bit architecture it is 64 bit and in 32 bits architecture it is 32 bit !!

Answer (score 0):

your new code should be:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define TOTAL_ELEMENTS (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))
int array[] = {23,34,12,17,204,99,16};

int main()
{
 int d;
 printf("Total= %d\n", TOTAL_ELEMENTS);
 for(d=-1;d <= ((int)TOTAL_ELEMENTS-2);d++)
 {
   printf("%d\n",array[d+1]);
  }
 return 0;
  }
```

you need to cast the

`TOTAL_ELEMENT` to integer before doing a operation on that. it is not a variable.

Answer (score -3):

**TOTAL_ELEMENTS** is a constant, you can't use as a variable.

Comment: No one is using it as a variable.

Comment: the correct name for **TOTAL_ELEMENTS** is an object-like macro because it looks like a data object in code that uses it and constant is a symbolic name  !!