# if statement selects the wrong condition

Tags: c, if-statement, strlen

I have a problem with this code: I don't know why it prints B and not A, since the condition is true.
`strlen(x)` is clearly greater than `i`. Can you help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char x[]="Hello";
   int i = -3;
   
   if(strlen(x)>i)
   {
       printf("A");
   }
   else
   {
       printf("B");
   }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What type of value does [`strlen()`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.6.3) return?

Comment: The problem is you're using `-3` in an unsigned comparison.  Since `strlen` returns a `size_t`, which is an unsigned integer type, comparing the result with an `int` results in the `int` being converted to a `size_t` as well.

Comment: Your compiler should be giving you a warning. If not, you definitely should rise the warning level.

Comment: [Why sizeof(int) is not greater than -1?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24466857/995714)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard function `strlen` is declared like

```
size_t strlen(const char *s);
```

where the type `size_t` is an implementation defined unsigned integer type the rank of which is not less than the rank of the type `int`. Usually the type `size_t` is defined as an alias for the type `unsigned long`.

In the expression used as a condition of the if statement

```
if(strlen(x)>i)
```

the compiler determines the common type of operands using the usual arithmetic conversions. That is the operand `i` is converted to the type `size_t` by propagating the sign bit. And as a result the value of the converted operand is a very big unsigned integer of the type `size_t` that is greater than the returned value of the call of `strlen`. So the condition evaluates to the logical false.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int i = -3;
    
    printf( "( size_t )i = %zu\n", ( size_t )i );
    
    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
( size_t )i = 18446744073709551613
```

If you want to get the expected by you result in your program you should write

```
if( ( int )strlen(x)>i)
```

or for example

```
if( ( long int )strlen(x)>i)
```

That is you need to cast the value returned by the function `strlen` to some signed integer type.

Answer (score 1):

From [C17 document](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf), 6.3.1.8, page number 39

> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank
> greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then
> the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the
> operand with unsigned integer type

```
size_t strlen(const char *s);
```

Here, `strlen(x)` return value of type `size_t` (unsigned long int). But `i` is of type `int`. The rank of `size_t` is greather than the rank `int`. So, `i` will be promoted to `size_t`.

Unsigend value of -3 is 4294967293 (in my system). And `strlen(x) = 5` , so it will print the `else` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare signed int with unsigned int.
Try
`if(signed(strlen(x))>i){}`
Or else you may change the value of I to positive int.

Comment: But `-3` downcast to unsigned should still be smaller than strlen of hello, or am I misunderstanding what downcast does?

Comment: Try.`int I=-3;printf("%u",(unsigned int)I);`Then run your code you will get value something like 4294967293 which is bigger than 5.