# Why is sizeof(int) less than -1?

Tags: c, sizeof

In the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   if (sizeof(int) > -1)
       printf("True");
   else
       printf("False");
return 0;
}
```

I get the output as "False" rather than "True".My understanding is that sizeof operator just returns the size of int which will be 4 in this case.

Why is the condition evaluated as false?

Comment: [Why is −1 > sizeof(int)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3100365/995714)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`sizeof` generates a `size_t` which is always positive. You are comparing it with `-1` which is probably promoted in `size_t` which gave you a HUGE number, most likely greater than the size of an int.

To make sure of it, try this:

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(int));
printf("%zu\n", (size_t)(-1));
```

[EDIT]: Following comments (some have been removed), I precise indeed that `sizeof` is an operator, not a function.

Comment: @user3195614 no, it is not a function, it is an operator. And it does evaluate to a value.

Comment: It's not "cast", but "promoted" because the C integer promotion rules say so :-).

Answer (score 2):

From the standard, **C11, 6.5.3.4 The sizeof and _Alignof operators**:

> 5 The value of the result of both operators is implementation-defined, and its type (an
>   unsigned integer type) is size_t, defined in  (and other headers).

So, the `sizeof` operator yields an unsigned value. You then compare an unsigned value with a signed value. That is dealt with by [converting the signed value to be unsigned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084949/arithmetic-operations-on-unsigned-and-signed-integers), which explains the behaviour that you see.

Answer (score 0):

First, running your code:

```
cc1plus: warnings being treated as errors
In function 'int main()':
Line 3: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
```

Then fixing it:

```
int main()
{
   if ((int)sizeof(int) > -1) // cast value of sizeof(int) to int before compare to int
       printf("True");
   else
       printf("False");
   return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
True
```

Comment: This is the answer, you should cast from -unsigned int- to -int-.

Comment: pls try adding the comment so users who use this in future might get a good grasp of it