# How sizeof operator works in C?

Tags: c, sizeof

In this below code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("%d",sizeof(int));
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled on gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4 compiler it gives  warning:

> format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type
>   ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=] printf("%d",sizeof(int));

Why I am getting this warning? Is it that return type of sizeof is 'long unsigned int' ?

When I replaced '%d' with '%ld' the warning went.

Comment: `sizeof` is an operator, not a function.

Comment: This question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797843/why-is-sizeofint-less-than-1

Comment: To avoid the warning you have to cast the value to int.
It's like when you define your own sizeof() operator , you need a cast something like this,

#define my-sizeof(type)(int*)(&type+1)-(int*)(&type)

Comment: @lazyborg: your macro won't work for both `my_sizeof(int)` and `my_sizeof(v)` (with some `int v;`  variable) and `my_sizeof(2)`; in other words, the `sizeof` operator is genuinely needed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [`sizeof` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof) is processed at *compile* time (and can be applied on both types and expressions). It gives some constant<sup>*</sup> of type `size_t`. On your system (and mine Debian/Linux/x86-64 also) `sizeof(int)` is `(size_t)4`. That [`size_t` type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t) is often `typedef`-ed in some type like `unsigned long` (but what integral type it actually is depends upon the implementation). You could code

```
printf("%d", (int)sizeof(int));
```

or (since [printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) understands the `%zd` or `%zu` control format string for `size_t`)

```
printf("%zu", sizeof(int));
```

For maximum portability, use `%zu` (not `%ld`) for printing `size_t` (because you might find systems or configurations on which `size_t` is `unsigned int` etc...).

<sup>Note *: `sizeof` is always constant, except for [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)</sup>