# Need a union to make 5 ints from 20 chars

Tags: c

this is my first post here so I will apologize in advance if I mess anything up.

I am writing a program for my class in C and the assignment wants us to read in a string 20 characters long from a file, then use a union to take the string and make 5 ints out of it.

All of my int values are coming out the same, and I can not figure out what else to do. All the examples I can find only really care about taking in a string then making it into one int or an int and a float.

my union is set up as follows

```
union hashes
{
    char str[20];
    int one;
    int two;
    int three;
    int four;
    int five;
};

int main (void)
{
    union hashes hashes1;
}
```

A new attempt at showing more of the program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

union hashes
{
    char str[20];
    int one;
    int two;
    int three;
    int four;
    int five;
};

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //declare union
    union hashes hashes1;
    //declare struct from link.h
    struct node* current;
    struct node* new_node;
    //file pointer to open file
    FILE *fpointer;
    fpointer = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    //activate first node
    current = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

//read from file
    while (fread(current, 20, 1, fpointer))
    {
        //copy the string to the union
        strncpy(hashes1.str, current->name, 20);
        //add the variables
        printf("string: %s\nInts: %d %d %d %d %d\n", hashes1.str, hashes1.one, hashes1.two, hashes1.three, hashes1.four, hashes1.five);

        new_node = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        current = new_node;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your posted code makes no effort to read in a string of 20 characters or use a union to make 5 ints out of it. This is not a homework completion site. From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking for homework help **must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it**.* If you can't get started on your assignment, ask your instructor for help.

Comment: Sorry Ken, I read a lot of helpful posts on this site and I have seen many new posters get yelled at for posting too much. I knew the issue was with my union, and what n.m. said I understand and should fix it. I did not want to post the whole code and get yelled at, I was attempting to focus on the area where I knew the issue was.

Comment: I also assumed it was implied that i can read the strings from the file and attempt to use union being that I stated my union ints were all coming out with the same values.

Comment: You need to post a [mcve]. Don't expect us to *assume* anything, particularly when it comes to posting your homework assignments. Include the *minimal relevant code to demonstrate the problem*. What you included is not useful in any way.

Comment: If the contents of the file are `int` * 5 binary, you do not need to use `union`. You can read directly into arrays(`int[5]`) using `fread` directly.

Comment: Ken, if you stop back by let me know if this would be more acceptable in the future? I would prefer to not make this mistake moving forward. Thank you for informing me.

Comment: `printf("string: %s\n...", hashes1.str,` This is not suitable. I think that you are misunderstanding.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thank you very much! I understand what you mean, but I don't think the file is in binary. It appears to be strings and null characters. Plus the assignment directions specifically want it done this way. The end result (which I did not add in my post because I was attempting to be succinct) is to use this union as an algorithm for a hash table. So I have to add these 5 ints together, then use the modulus division on them to get a number that I will use to add it to a linked list for that number.

Comment: oh i see.......

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I dont understand what you mean about the printf not being suitable. I am only using it to check the values in the union variables because the hash values were acting wierd and that is when i learned they were all storing the exact same value.

Comment: Your code should not compile (since `struct node` is not defined).

Comment: @Basile sorry, I was trying to leave out anything not required to express my issue here, the program at the time i posted this was approx 100 lines, and as I said ive seen people get yelled at for posting too much. There is a header file that i didnt put in the include that has the node struct. Should have #include "link.h" at the top, but i felt that would only be more confusing so i commented that struct declaration hoping it would shed some light on it.

Answer (score 3):

If `sizeof(int)` is 4 on your platform, use:

```
union hashes
{
    char str[20];
    int numbers[5];
};
```

You can also use a fixed width integer.

```
union hashes
{
    char str[20];
    int32_t numbers[5];
};
```

Comment: I see, thank you very much!

Comment: Just consider that first sentence might be translated into `if(sizeof(int)==4)` in real code. This is a good place to suggest fixed-width integer types.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis, yes, of course.

Comment: This does seem like a natural place for `int32_t`, but if we are being picky, `char`s are not required to be 8 bits.

Answer (score 1):

All of your `int`s are the same. Another approach will be having another vector, but this time, of `int`s. Since the `sizeof(int)` between platforms can change, you can get the vector size relative to the `int` size:

```
union hashes
{
   char str[20];
   int numbers[20 / sizeof(int)];
};
```

A little test case can be used to prove that both fields have a same size:

```
int main(void)
{
   union hashes hashes1;

   printf("%lu %lu %lu", sizeof(hashes1), sizeof(hashes1.str),
                         sizeof(hashes1.numbers));
   return 0;
}
```

That prints `20 20 20`. A little [Coliru demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f707e147fcdc93ec).

To know or work with the resulting amount of `int`s you could do something like:

```
int main(void)
{
    union hashes hashes1;
    int i;

    if (sizeof(hashes1.numbers) / sizeof(int) != 5)
       printf("In this architecture we cannot extract 5 numbers "
              " from 20 characters\n");
    else {
       printf("The numbers are: ");

       for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
         printf("%d ", hashes1.numbers[i]);

       printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Although usually `sizeof(int) == 4`, so, you will nearly always get 5 integers, and the first `if` will be never executed in your tests.

Comment: Thank you so much, that is really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

With recent C (e.g. [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) or [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29) at least), a `union` can contain an [*anonymous* `struct`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8932707/what-are-anonymous-structs-and-unions-useful-for-in-c11). So you might code:

```
union hashes {
  char str[20];
  struct {
    int one;
    int two;
    int three;
    int four;
    int five;
  };
};
```

and later use `hashes1.str` and `hashes1.three` etc.

Be aware that you have no guarantee that an `int` takes four bytes (or that it is aligned to 4 bytes). You might use [`<stdint.h>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) and types like `int32_t` (a 32 bits signed integer) or `uint8_t` (an 8 bit unsigned integer, e.g. a *byte*). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40798649/841108) and read the standard reference, e.g. [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (a draft which is practically the same as the ISO C11 standard).

You should use the [`sizeof` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof) (and perhaps also [`alignof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Alignof), if [alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) is relevant). In particular your call to `fread` should have `sizeof(struct node)` or `sizeof(union hashes)` instead of `20`.

<sup>(BTW, your code is wrong, so won't compile, because `struct node` is not declared)</sup>

Don't forget to favor readability and [portability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_portability) when writing C code. Be sure to enable all warnings & debug info when compiling (e.g. use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...), then use the debugger (e.g. `gdb`).

Comment: Thank you very much. From my understanding we are using C89 (atleast according to the professor). I am still very much wet behind the ears on this stuff, but we use a shell program to log into a campus linux os machine to do all the code, so I dont know how to tell which type it is for sure. There was a comment earlier (which got removed for some reason) where someone suggested making 2 structs and doing a union of them, which is what I did and it worked. Pretty much what you suggested here, but yours is even better, less typing!

Comment: Recent (and even not so recent) Linux distributions hava a [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler so are usually accepting C99 (at least if compiling with `gcc -std=c99`)

Comment: BTW, I believe you should learn C99 at least. So ask your professor if you are allowed to code against that standard (or even better, C11), and if he forbids it, ask him why. C89 is really a thing of the past and I see no reason to code against it in 2016. Please look into the [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) draft. You won't understand all of it, but you really should take a hour to glance into it.

Comment: Will do, thank you sir!