# Output data type of sizeof() operator

Tags: c, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, sizeof, gcc5

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.5 and GCC version 5.4.0.

I was playing with `sizeof()` operator, wrote the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

        long int mylint = 31331313131.1313;

        printf("size of long int is %d\n", sizeof(mylint));
        printf("size of long int is %d\n", sizeof(long int));

        return 0;
}
```

I tried to compile using `gcc -o ... ...` command and was expecting:

```
size of long int is 8
size of long int is 8
```

But I got the following error:

```
fl_double_lint.c: In function ‘main’:
fl_double_lint.c:11:9: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]

  printf("size of long int is %d\n", sizeof(mylint));
         ^
fl_double_lint.c:12:9: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
  printf("size of long int is %d\n", sizeof(long int));
```

When I use `%ld` instead it works as expected. Why `sizeof()` is not working with `%d`? (Why '`long unsigned int`' but not '`int`'?)

**Edit:** I know that many questions were asked regarding output of sizeof() operator (as suggested in comments). However, they do not answer the question of why using `%d` does not work (i.e. does not give any result). I know it is not correct format, but whenever we have a `char` type variable using `%d` we can get equivalent `int` result, this is also the case for short, uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t (generally for types with equal or less than 32 bit). The following code works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

        char mychar = 'd';
        uint32_t myuint32 = 32;
        uint16_t myuint16 = 16;
        uint8_t myuint8 = 8;
        short myshort = 26945;
        int myint = 100;

        printf("integer equivalent of mychar is %d\n", mychar);
        printf("integer equivalent of myuint8 is %d\n", myuint8);
        printf("integer equivalent of myuint16 is %d\n", myuint16);
        printf("integer equivalent of myuint32 is %d\n", myuint32);
        printf("character equivalent of myint is %c\n", myint);
        printf("integer equivalent of myshort is %d\n", myshort);


        return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
integer equivalent of mychar is 100
integer equivalent of myuint8 is 8
integer equivalent of myuint16 is 16
integer equivalent of myuint32 is 32
character equivalent of myint is d
integer equivalent of myshort is 26945
```

And now I discovered that `%d` does not work for any variable that needs larger than 32 bit to be stored. After considering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732319/difference-between-size-t-and-unsigned-int) I have some idea about implementation dependence of `size_t`, maybe in my system it was `unsigned long` (`%ld` also giving the result proves it). So maybe if `size_t` was an `unsigned int` in my system I would get a result, is it true?

As it can be seen from the code above, `%c` decodes the last 8 bits of `int` as a character, why `%d` does not do the same (i.e. decode the last 32 bits of content of `size_t` variable as it was `int`? I believe if it would do so we could get the same result for small enough numbers, and this was what I meant when I initially asked the question).

Comment: "_Why '`long unsigned int`' but not '`int`'?_" What sense would negative value, returned from `sizeof` make?

Comment: Actually `"%ld"` is *also* wrong. The `sizeof` operator returns a value of type `size_t`, and to print it with [`printf` (and family)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) you should use `"%zu"`. Or since you also tagged this question with the very different C++ language, just use `std::cout << sizeof(something)`.

Comment: @AdhamzhonShukurov The return type of sizeof operator is **size_t** which is unsigned and **int** is **signed** by default.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How sizeof operator works in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40798554/how-sizeof-operator-works-in-c)

Comment: This has been asked a zillion times. C gold badges: why is it still open???

Comment: [What's the correct way to use printf to print a size_t?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/940087/995714), [Output data type of sizeof() operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54463692/995714)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the correct way to use printf to print a size\_t?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940087/whats-the-correct-way-to-use-printf-to-print-a-size-t)

Comment: `size_t` appears to be `long unsigned int` on your system, but it doesn't have to. Can be unsigned short or unsigned int or whatever, as long as it can represent the size of objects on that platform

Comment: @YSC is it still duplicate?

Comment: @phuclv can you consider my question again?

Comment: `myuint32` is an `uint32_t` which must be printed using `PRIu32`. Remember int is not always 32 bits, and printing an unsigned type with signed format specifier is still UB. [printf format specifiers for uint32_t and size_t](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3168275/995714)

Comment: @phuclv But up to 2147483647 uint32_t and 32 bit integer decoded the same way. + I am asking why it does not even give a result.

Comment: `why %d does not do the same (i.e. decode the last 32 bits of content of size_t variable as it was int?)` C doesn't work that way. Type sizes are not fixed and vararg functions doesn't know what size a parameter is. On platforms where those are on stack then if you specify a different type different from what you give it then you can mess up the stack when printf pops a different number of bytes for that argument. As said, use the correct specifier and don't wonder why it works here and not there

Comment: @phuclv Thanks for the answer, but my aim is to use C together with custom HDL designed hardware, that is why it is really important to me to wonder about these things.

Comment: @phuclv By the way duplicate linked question does not seem to be enough to completely answer my question, I would be glad if you remove it (of course if you agree with me).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `sizeof` operator evaluates to a value of type `size_t`.  This type is unsigned and typically larger than an `int`, which is why you get the warning.

Using the wrong format specifier to `printf` invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  You can get away with this however for types smaller than `int` due to the rules of *integer promotions* in section 6.3.1.1p2 of the C standard:

> The following may be used in an expression wherever an int or unsigned
>   int may be used:
>
> - An object  or  expression  with  an  integer  type  (other  than int or unsigned int ) whose  integer  conversion  rank  is  less  than
>     or  equal  to  the  rank  of int and unsigned int .
> - A bit-field of type
>     _Bool , int , signed int ,or unsigned int .
>
> If  an int can  represent  all  values  of  the  original  type  (as  restricted  by  the  width,
>   for  a bit-field),  the  value  is  converted  to  an int ; otherwise,
>   it  is  converted  to  an unsigned int . These  are  called  the
>   integer promotions . All  other  types  are  unchanged  by  the
>   integer promotions.

So as long this doesn't result in a change from unsigned to signed, types smaller than `int` can be printed with `%d`.

The proper type modifier for `size_t` is `%zu`, as per section 7.21.6.1p7 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding length modifiers for the `fprintf` function (and by extension, `printf`):

> z
>
> Specifies that a following d , i , o , u , x ,or X conversion
>   specifier applies to a `size_t` or  the  corresponding  signed  integer 
>   type  argument;  or  that  a following n conversion specifier applies
>   to a pointer to a signed integer type corresponding to `size_t`
>   argument.

So what you want is:

```
printf("size of long int is %zu\n", sizeof(mylint));
```

Comment: I downvoted since as a C gold badge I'd expect you to close this question as the duplicate it is rather than answering.

Comment: @YSC It's not always easy to find one unless you have a specific one in mind.  Given that this one has a title that better reflects the question, is more upvoted, and has an answer with a quote from the standard, I'm reversing the dup.

Comment: I found the duplicate by searching for "printf format sizeof". First answer. I disagree with you but not strongly enough to do anything.

Comment: "I'm going to close the other question as a dupe of this one because I wrote the answer here". If you think your answer adds something over the answer to the other question, move your answer there. This is not right.

Comment: Given that the questions (and their answers) are substantially identical, it might be best to ask a mod to merge them. (I also kind of agree with @CrisLuengo that you probably shouldn't have dupehammered that question yourself. Even if it _was_ objectively the right call -- which I'm not sure about -- it still _looks like_ an attempt to game the system for rep and visibility.)

Comment: @dbush Thanks for the good answer, it partially answered my question, but can you update it accordingly and give more information (I edited the question).

Comment: @AdhamzhonShukurov No, you added _another_ question to your original question. this is frowned upon on Stack Overflow. Prefer [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @AdhamzhonShukurov Since your edit was asking for clarification on the last part of your original question, I've updated to address.