# Why is (sizeof(int) > -1) false?

Tags: c, sizeof

Can You justify the below code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    if(sizeof(int) > -1)
    {
            printf("\nTrue\n");
    }
    else
    {
            printf("\nFALSE\n");
    }
}
```

The output is `FALSE` .....suggest me the reason

Comment: gcc even has a warning for this `foo.c:4:20: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare] if(sizeof(int) > -1)` - you can easily enable verbose warnings in gcc with `-Wall -Wextra` which is something everyone should be doing.

Comment: [Why is −1 > sizeof(int)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3100365/995714)

Answer (score 7):

`sizeof(int)` has type `size_t`, which is an unsigned integer type.

`-1` has type `int`, which is a signed integer type.

When comparing a signed integer with an unsigned integer, first the signed integer is converted to unsigned, then the comparison is performed with two unsigned integers.

`sizeof(int) > (unsigned int)-1` is false, because `(unsigned int)-1` is a very large number on most implementations (equal to UINT_MAX, or the largest number which fits in an `unsigned int`).

Comment: *When comparing a signed integer with an unsigned integer, first the signed integer is converted to unsigned* This is true only if the conversion rank of the unsigned integer type is greater or equal than the one of the signed integer type.

Answer (score 2):

```
sizeof
```

yields a value of an unsigned type (namely `size_t`).

In `sizeof(int) > -1` expression, the usual arithmetic conversion applies and `-1` is converted to the unsigned type of `sizeof` which results in a huge unsigned value greater than `-1`.

Comment: thanks for ur answer

Answer (score 2):

It's because the `sizeof` operator returns an unsigned integer type.  When compared with a signed integer type, the signed integer is converted to unsigned.  So in effect, you were comparing `sizeof(int)` against the largest possible unsigned integer.

You can force the size to signed by casting:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    if((int)sizeof(int) > -1)
    {
            printf("\nTrue\n");
    }
    else
    {
            printf("\nFALSE\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: To be picky, the signed integer is _converted_ to unsigned. It is done implicitly in this case, as opposed to casting which is always something done explicitly by the programmer.

Comment: @Lundin Ok, I changed it to use the term "converted".