# comparing a signed and unsigned integer in c language

Tags: c, sizeof

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    if (sizeof(int) > -10)
        printf("YES\n");
   else 
        printf("NO\n");
   return 0;
}
```

why it is printing NO instead of YES? Because the size of int is 4bytes as per the compiler.And it is greater than -10.

Comment: It's not less than -10.

Comment: `sizeof()` returns an **unsigned** value, so it can never be less than 0.

Comment: I would also like to suggest that `printf("%zu\n", (size_t)-10)` may be enlightening.

Comment: [Why is −1 > sizeof(int)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3100365/995714)

Comment: You have used < ( smaller than sign) which means it will print NO, as 4 is greater than -10.

  
    if (a < b)
    {
        prints yes if a is smaller.
    }
    else
    {
        prints no if b is smaller.
    }

you have a = 4 and b = -10, thus it prints no.

Comment: @RahulGurung Did you try it? The correct behavior is actually "YES".

Comment: @aschepler i am eager to see how.

Comment: @aschepler checked out that tagged ques , i got you.

Comment: @RahulGurung See the duplicate, and/or look at [the Usual Arithmetic Conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions)

Comment: @RahulGurung See [this](https://onlinegdb.com/ryo0w6EvQ).

Comment: yeah the sign should be > and the answer will be NO.

Comment: @Osiris blew my mind. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof` produces an unsigned value. When comparing a signed and unsigned integer, the signed value is converted to unsigned.  The two’s complement value for `-10` is much bigger than `4` when interpreted as unsigned.

Comment: Shouldn't `if (sizeof(int) < much_bigger_value)` be true?

Comment: @Barmar because of your comment I realized  that the OP was reporting an output of NO. I get an output of YES with his exact code.

Comment: The title says that `sizeof(int)` is less than `-10`. It is a bit unclear.