# How to display the maximum value of a unsigned long long in C?

Tags: c, types, long-integer

What am I doing wrong here?

```
$ cat size.c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main() {

printf ("sizeof unsigned int = %d bytes.\n", sizeof(unsigned int));
printf ("sizeof unsigned long long = %d bytes.\n", sizeof(unsigned long long));

printf ("max unsigned int = %d\n", (int)(pow(2, 32) - 1));
printf ("max unsigned long long = %lld\n", (unsigned long long)(pow(2, 64) - 1));

}
$ gcc size.c -o size
$ ./size
sizeof unsigned int = 4 bytes.
sizeof unsigned long long = 8 bytes.
max unsigned int = 2147483647
max unsigned long long = -1
$
```

I am expecting `18446744073709551615` as output instead of a `-1` at the last line.

---

Okay, I completely missed that I was getting the wrong value for 2<sup>32</sup> - 1, which should have been 4294967295, not 2147483647. Things make more sense now.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `%llu`, not `%lld`. `d` is for signed integers, so `printf` displays it as a signed long long.

Answer (score 29):

Just don't suppose that it has a certain value use `ULLONG_MAX`

Comment: `#include <limits.h>` to get this macro, along with others. like `LLONG_MAX` and `LLONG_MIN`.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit: changed ~0 to (type) -1 as per Christoph's suggestion. See the comments below.**

You can get the maximum value of an unsigned type doing the following:

```
unsigned long long x = (unsigned long long) -1;
```

Easier, right? =). Second, you are telling `printf()` to interpret the given variable as a long long decimal, which is signed. Try this instead:

```
unsigned long long x = (unsigned long long) -1;
printf("%llu", x);
```

`%llu` means "long long unsigned".

Comment: Actually that should be `~0LLu`

Comment: Actually gcc figures that out all by itself.

Comment: Though I'd expect it to give some sort of warning.

Comment: @Santiago: gcc doesn't figure anythng out here - without the `llu` suffix, it'll only work as intended if `~0 == -1`; casting `-1` actually is the preferred (and portable) method to get the maximum value of any unsigned type, ie `x = (unsigned long long)-1`; the explicit cast is unnecessary if your warning levels are low enough

Comment: Right you are. Edited! Thanks.

Comment: Casting is ugly. Simply write `-1ULL`.

Comment: The casting isn't necessary, using `-1` is completely valid. The standard states that the `int` will first be extended to `long long` then cast to `long long unsigned` (which isn't standardized, but always happily converts). This is the same as putting `(long long unsigned) -1` in the first place.

Comment: @Matt: that's why I said that the explicit cast is unnecessary; it may be needed to make your compiler happy, though (gcc may warn about implicit conversions from signed to unsigned)

Comment: @R..: what about `size_t` and the types from `stdint.h`, ie if you dont know to which standard integer type your unsigned type corresponds? plain `-1` works fine in all cases, so I prefer that...

Comment: @Matt: right, but the reason is even simpler than you state. Conversion from signed types to unsigned types is always just computation modulo: `Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
until the value is in the range of the new type.`

Answer (score 2):

```
unsigned long long ulTestMax = -1;
printf ("max unsigned long long = %llu\n", ulTestMax );
```

this works in C++, should work here, too.

Comment: Assuming that the underlying architecture uses two's complement

Comment: Also, long long is not a standard type (it's gnu extension, as i remember) and there's no guarantee that it's 64bit

Comment: @Nathan: casting `-1` to an unsigned integer type is guaranteed to yield the maximum value by the C standard (specifically, C99 6.3.1.3 §2)

Comment: @Nathan: you're wrong. This has nothing to do with twos complement, only the strictly-defined behavior of unsigned values.

Answer (score 1):

Whoever done -1 to Kiril Kirov post pls take a look here:

[Is it safe to use -1 to set all bits to true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809227/is-it-safe-to-use-1-to-set-all-bits-to-true/809341#809341)
Dingo post

In Kiril post only slight modification required regarding sign extension:

```
unsigned long long ulTestMax = -1LLu;
```

-1 is antipattern, it'll do the job if u dont want to go with the solution provided by lmits.h