# C question: off_t (and other signed integer types) minimum and maximum values

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I occasionally will come across an integer type (e.g. POSIX signed integer type `off_t`) where it would be helpful to have a macro for its minimum and maximum values, but I don't know how to make one that is truly portable.

For unsigned integer types I had always thought this was simple. `0` for the minimum and `~0` for the maximum. I have since read of several different SO threads which suggest using `-1` instead of `~0` for portability. An interesting thread with some contention is here:
[c++ - Is it safe to use -1 to set all bits to true? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809227/is-it-safe-to-use-1-to-set-all-bits-to-true)

However even after reading about this issue I'm still confused. Also, I'm looking for something both C89 and C99 compliant so I don't know if the same methods apply. Say I had a type of `uint_whatever_t`. Couldn't I just cast to 0 first and then bitwise complement? Would this be ok?:

```
#define UINT_WHATEVER_T_MAX ( ~ (uint_whatever_t) 0 )
```

Signed integer types look like they'll be a tougher nut to crack. I've seen several different possible solutions but only [one](http://old.nabble.com/off_t-madness-td8811802.html) appears to be portable. Either that or it's incorrect. I found it while googling for an OFF_T_MAX and OFF_T_MIN. Credit to Christian Biere:

```
#define MAX_INT_VAL_STEP(t) \
    ((t) 1 << (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(t) - 1 - ((t) -1 < 1))) 

#define MAX_INT_VAL(t) \
    ((MAX_INT_VAL_STEP(t) - 1) + MAX_INT_VAL_STEP(t))

#define MIN_INT_VAL(t) \
    ((t) -MAX_INT_VAL(t) - 1)

[...]
#define OFF_T_MAX MAX_INT_VAL(off_t)
```

I couldn't find anything regarding the different allowable types of signed integer representations in C89, but C99 has notes for integer portability issues in §J.3.5:

> Whether signed integer types are represented using sign and magnitude, two’s
>   complement, or ones’ complement, and whether the extraordinary value is a trap
>   representation or an ordinary value (6.2.6.2).

That would seem to imply that only those three listed signed number representations can be used. Is the implication correct, and are the macros above compatible with all three representations?

---

Other thoughts:
It seems that the function-like macro `MAX_INT_VAL_STEP()` would give an incorrect result if there were padding bits. I wonder if there is any way around this.

Reading through [signed number representations on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations) it occurs to me that for all three signed integer representations any signed integer type's MAX would be:
sign bit off, all value bits on (all three)
And its MIN would be either:
sign bit on, all value bits on (sign and magnitude)
sign bit on, all value bits off (ones/twos complement)

I think I could test for sign and magnitude by doing this:

```
#define OFF_T_MIN ( ( ( (off_t)1 | ( ~ (off_t) -1 ) ) != (off_t)1 ) ? /* sign and magnitude minimum value here */ : /* ones and twos complement minimum value here */ )
```

Then as sign and magnitude is sign bit on and all value bits on wouldn't the minimum for off_t in that case be `~ (off_t) 0` ? And for ones/twos complement minimum I would need some way to turn all the value bits off but leave the sign bit on. No idea how to do this without knowing the number of value bits. Also is the sign bit guaranteed to always be one more significant than the most significant value bit?

Thanks and please let me know if this is too long a post

---

**EDIT 12/29/2010 5PM EST**:
As answered below by ephemient to get the unsigned type max value, `(unsigned type)-1` is more correct than `~0` or even `~(unsigned type)0`. From what I can gather when you use -1 it is just the same as 0-1 which will always lead to the maximum value in an unsigned type.

Also, because the maximum value of an unsigned type can be determined it is possible to determine how many value bits are in an unsigned type. Credit to Hallvard B. Furuseth for his IMAX_BITS() function-like macro that he posted in reply to a [question on comp.lang.c](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c/tree/browse_frm/thread/35f79d1050452749)

```
/* Number of bits in inttype_MAX, or in any (1<<b)-1 where 0 <= b < 3E+10 */
#define IMAX_BITS(m) ((m) /((m)%0x3fffffffL+1) /0x3fffffffL %0x3fffffffL *30 \
                  + (m)%0x3fffffffL /((m)%31+1)/31%31*5 + 4-12/((m)%31+3))
```

> IMAX_BITS(INT_MAX) computes the number of bits in an int, and IMAX_BITS((unsigned_type)-1) computes the number of bits in an unsigned_type.  Until someone implements 4-gigabyte integers, anyway:-)

The heart of my question however remains unanswered: how to determine the minimum and maximum values of a *signed* type via macro. I'm still looking into this. Maybe the answer is there is no answer.

*If you are not viewing this question on StackOverflow in most cases you cannot see the proposed answers until they are accepted. It is suggested to [view this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514572).*

Comment: Indeed, `MAX_INT_VAL_STEP` breaks if there are any padding bits. I have a related question I never got a satisfactory answer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957252/is-there-any-way-to-compute-the-width-of-an-integer-type-at-compile-time

Comment: @R What platforms targeted by a C compiler have padding bits in the signed integral types? Maybe those can be handled with some `#ifdef` specific to those platforms, if necessary.

Comment: Since C11, you can use a `_Generic` macro for that.

Answer (score 7):

I believe I have *finally* solved this problem, but the solution is only available at `configure`-time, not compile-time or runtime, so it's still not idea. Here it is:

```
HEADERS="#include <sys/types.h>"
TYPE="off_t"
i=8
while : ; do
printf "%s\nstruct { %s x : %d; };\n" "$HEADERS" "$TYPE" $i > test.c
$CC $CFLAGS -o /dev/null -c test.c || break
i=$(($i+1))
done
rm test.c
echo $(($i-1))
```

The idea comes from 6.7.2.1 paragraph 3:

> The expression that specifies the width of a bit-field shall be an integer constant
>   expression with a nonnegative value that does not exceed the width of an object of the
>   type that would be specified were the colon and expression omitted. If the value is zero,
>   the declaration shall have no declarator.

I would be quite pleased if this leads to any ideas for solving the problem at compile-time.

Comment: R.. thanks for your post, that's a neat idea. If I ever figure compile-time out I'll post it as an answer and if you figure it out please do likewise. -AQG

Comment: Glad you came across this late answer. If I find a better solution I'll surely follow up.

Comment: @AnonymousQuestionGuy: I came up with another idea that may be relevant to your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5761398/379897

Comment: Hmm. This may be good enough for compile-time checking e.g. if `86400L` (17 bits precision) fits into an `int`: for this, `int` would need a width of at least 18 bits, so I could do `struct { signed int int_at_least_18_bits_wide:18; };` (the `signed` is necessary!) as compile-time assertion, right? C99 and n2731 (C2x draft) only require a diagnostic, the program may compile, but the usual `struct { char ensure_foo[foo ? 1 : -1]; };` is the same… and I _believe_ both use neither UB nor IB. Am I correct regarding that?

Comment: I don't think this script solves a useful problem; it amounts to figuring out how many bits there are in `off_t`, which is easily available as `CHAR_BIT * sizeof (off_t)`.  Now ISO C doesn't require it. An integer type could have padding bits in it so that its value bits are not a multiple of the byte, like say 36 bit word size, with a 34 bit integer.  **Will your POSIX shell script even run there? Will there be a POSIX API with an off_t to worry about**?

Comment: @Kaz: It's not equivalent. `sizeof` also includes padding bits.

Comment: You missed the "could have padding bits" remark in my comment. `sizeof` includes padding bits only if they exist. Otherwise it does not include padding bits. They exist in copious amounts in some structures: between members and at the end. According to the standard they may exist in the integer types themselves, but you have to be on some special machine.

Comment: This is a good trick if you genuinely need a compile time number of bits as a preprocessor constant. If you want to be able to do `#if SIZEOF_OFF_T > 32`  type stuff, then your configure script can prepare the right preprocessor constants in a configuration header.

Answer (score 5):

Surprisingly, C promotes types up to `int` before arithmetic operations, with results being at least `int` sized.  (Similarly oddities include `'a'` character literal having type `int`, not `char`.)

```
int a = (uint8_t)1 + (uint8_t)-1;
   /* = (uint8_t)1 + (uint8_t)255 = (int)256 */
int b = (uint8_t)1 + ~(uint8_t)0;
   /* = (uint8_t)1 + (int)-1 = (int)0 */
```

So `#define UINT_WHATEVER_T_MAX ( ~ (uint_whatever_t) 0 )` isn't necessarily okay.

Answer (score 2):

Signed max:

```
#define GENERIC_S_MAX(stype) ((stype) ((1ULL << ((sizeof(stype) * 8) - 1)) - 1ULL))
```

Assuming your system uses two's complement, the signed min should be:

```
#define GENERIC_S_MIN(stype) ((stype) -1 - GENERIC_S_MAX(stype))
```

These should be totally portable, except that long long is technically a compiler extension in C89. This also avoids the undefined behavior of over/underflowing a signed integer.

Comment: This assumes lack of padding bits.

Comment: This is true. I was not familiar with C integer types that use padding bits.

Comment: It also assumes `CHAR_BIT==8`, but that's easily fixed by subbing in `CHAR_BIT` for 8.

Comment: @R.. Are there any real world cases where `off_t` is used but `CHAR_BIT != 8` though...? The POSIX spec requires `CHAR_BIT == 8` and `off_t` is typically used on POSIX systems, so I'd say it's a pretty safe assumption.

Comment: @CraigBarnes: The question isn't just about off_t, and generalizes to non-POSIX.

Answer (score 1):

For sign-magnitude representations, it's fairly easy (for types at least as wide as `int`, anyway):

```
#define SM_TYPE_MAX(type) (~(type)-1 + 1)
#define SM_TYPE_MIN(type) (-TYPE_MAX(type))
```

Unfortunately, sign-magnitude representations are rather thin on the ground ;)

Answer (score 0):

Quick answers only:

`#define UINT_WHATEVER_T_MAX ( ~ (uint_whatever_t) 0 )` looks OK to me, the preference for -1 is that `uint_whatever_t = -1;` is more concise than `uint_whatever_t = ~(uint_whatever_t)0;`

`(CHAR_BIT * sizeof(t))` looks not strictly conforming to me. You're right about padding bits, so this value might be considerably *more* than the width of the type unless Posix says otherwise about `off_t`.

In contrast, the fixed-width integer types in C99 *must not* have padding bits, so for `intN_t` you're on firmer ground using the size to deduce the width. They're also guaranteed two's complement.

> That would seem to imply that only
>   those three listed signed number
>   representations can be used. Is the
>   implication correct

Yes. 6.2.6.2/2 lists the three permissible meanings of the sign bit, and hence the three permissible signed number representations.

> is the sign bit guaranteed to always
>   be one more significant than the most
>   significant value bit

It's indirectly required to be *more* significant than the value bits, by the fact (6.2.6.2/2 again) that "Each bit that is a value bit shall have the same value as
the same bit in the object representation of the corresponding unsigned type". So the value bits must be a contiguous range starting at the least significant.

However, you can't portably set just the sign bit. Read 6.2.6.2/3 and /4, about negative zeros, and note that even if the implementation uses a representation that has them in principle, it doesn't have to support them, and there's no guaranteed way of generating one. On a sign+magnitude implementation, the thing you want is a negative zero.

[Edit: oh, I misread, you only need to generate that value after you've ruled out sign+magnitude, so you could still be OK.

To be honest, it sounds a bit numpty to me if Posix has defined an integer type and not provided limits for it. Boo to them. I'd probably go with the old, "porting header" approach, where you put the thing that probably works everywhere in a header, and document that someone should probably check it before compiling the code on any freakish implementations. Compared with what they normally have to do to get anybody's code to work, they'll happily live with that.]

Answer (score 0):

It's technically not a macro, but in practice the following should always be folded into a constant minimum for `off_t`, or any signed type, regardless of sign representation.  Although I'm not sure what doesn't use two's compliment, if anything.

POSIX requires a signed integer type for `off_t`, so the C99 signed exact width values should be sufficient.  Some platforms actually define `OFF_T_MIN` (OSX), but POSIX unfortunately doesn't require it.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include <sys/types.h>

  assert(sizeof(off_t) >= sizeof(int8_t) && sizeof(off_t) <= sizeof(intmax_t));

  const off_t OFF_T_MIN = sizeof(off_t) == sizeof(int8_t)   ? INT8_MIN    :
                          sizeof(off_t) == sizeof(int16_t)  ? INT16_MIN   :
                          sizeof(off_t) == sizeof(int32_t)  ? INT32_MIN   :
                          sizeof(off_t) == sizeof(int64_t)  ? INT64_MIN   :
                          sizeof(off_t) == sizeof(intmax_t) ? INTMAX_MIN  : 0;
```

The same is usable to obtain the maximum value.

```
  assert(sizeof(off_t) >= sizeof(int8_t) && sizeof(off_t) <= sizeof(intmax_t));

  const off_t OFF_T_MAX = sizeof(off_t) == sizeof(int8_t)   ? INT8_MAX    :
                          sizeof(off_t) == sizeof(int16_t)  ? INT16_MAX   :
                          sizeof(off_t) == sizeof(int32_t)  ? INT32_MAX   :
                          sizeof(off_t) == sizeof(int64_t)  ? INT64_MAX   :
                          sizeof(off_t) == sizeof(intmax_t) ? INTMAX_MAX  : 0;
```

This could be turned into a macro using `autoconf` or `cmake` though.

Comment: This is a nice solution if the C compiler treats ternary expressions as constant expressions which ISO C, quite stupidly, does not require.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following pattern to solve the problem (assuming there are no padding bits):

```
((((type) 1 << (number_of_bits_in_type - 2)) - 1) << 1) + 1
```

The `number_of_bits_in_type` is derived as `CHAR_BIT * sizeof (type)` as in the other answers.

We basically "nudge" the 1 bits into place, while avoiding the sign bit.

You can see how this works. Suppose that the width is 16 bits. Then we take 1 and shift it left by 16 - 2 = 14, producing the bit pattern `0100000000000000`. We carefully avoided shifting a `1` into the sign bit. Next, we subtract 1 from this, obtaining `0011111111111111`.  See where this is going? We shift this left by 1 obtaining `0111111111111110`, again avoiding the sign bit. Finally we add 1, obtaining `0111111111111111`, which is the highest signed 16 bit value.

This should work fine on one's complement and sign-magnitude machines, if you work in a museum where they have such things. It doesn't work if you have padding bits. For that, probably all you can do is `#ifdef`, or switch to alternative configuration mechanisms outside of the compiler and preprocessor.

So, for `off_t`:

```
// probably bad idea to use these symbol names

#define OFF_T_BITS (sizeof (off_t) * CHAR_BIT)
#define OFF_T_MAX (((((off_t) 1 << (OFF_T_BITS - 2)) - 1) << 1) + 1)
```

Comment: `(unsigned short)1 << 15` promotes to `int` though, so you lose… you’ve got to ask tons more casts.

Comment: @mirabilos I have a typo in the expression: there is supposed to be a `- 2`. You can tell from the discussion which refers to a 14 bit shift in the 16 bit case.   Promotion isn't any problem; it's a red herring.  And we can't really do anything about it. If `(type)` is `(unsigned short)` and we add a `(type)` cast to the whole thing, it will still promote to `int` again. Also, this is clearly intended to get the max value for a signed type, not unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

Since C11 you can use _Generic to find the underlying type. Before then `__builtin_choose_expr` with `__typeof` and `__builtin_types_compatible_p` was fairly portable.

If you don't want to use any of those, you could guess the type based on its size and signedness.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#define TP_MAX(Tp) ((Tp)-1>0 ? ( \
                        1==sizeof(Tp) ? ((Tp)2==1?1:UCHAR_MAX) \
                        : sizeof(unsigned short)==sizeof(Tp) ? USHRT_MAX \
                        : sizeof(unsigned int)==sizeof(Tp) ? UINT_MAX \
                        : sizeof(unsigned long)==sizeof(Tp) ? ULONG_MAX \
                        : sizeof(unsigned long long)==sizeof(Tp) ? ULLONG_MAX : 0 \
                   ) :  ( 1==sizeof(Tp) ? SCHAR_MAX \
                        : sizeof(short)==sizeof(Tp) ? SHRT_MAX \
                        : sizeof(int)==sizeof(Tp) ? INT_MAX \
                        : sizeof(long)==sizeof(Tp) ? LONG_MAX \
                        : sizeof(long long)==sizeof(Tp) ? LLONG_MAX : 0)) \


#define STC_ASSERT(X) ((void)(sizeof(struct { int stc_assert:(X)?1:-1; })))

int main()
{
    STC_ASSERT(TP_MAX(signed char)==SCHAR_MAX);
    STC_ASSERT(TP_MAX(short)==SHRT_MAX);
    STC_ASSERT(TP_MAX(int)==INT_MAX);
    STC_ASSERT(TP_MAX(long)==LONG_MAX);
    STC_ASSERT(TP_MAX(long long)==LLONG_MAX);
    STC_ASSERT(TP_MAX(unsigned char)==UCHAR_MAX);
    STC_ASSERT(TP_MAX(unsigned short)==USHRT_MAX);
    STC_ASSERT(TP_MAX(unsigned int)==UINT_MAX);
    STC_ASSERT(TP_MAX(unsigned long)==ULONG_MAX);
    STC_ASSERT(TP_MAX(unsigned long long)==ULLONG_MAX);
}
```

(If you want to do it even without limits.h, please check out my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/53470064/1084774).

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Use the header file listed below and then use `TYPE_MAX(someType)` to get the maximum of the type used by someType.

You can use the `_Generic` expression, introduced with C11.
You need a list of every base integer type (like `char`, `long`, ...) your compiler supports, every typedefed integer (most likely things like `uint8_t`, `off_t`) will be treated like the underlying type.

Here is an example header file:

```
#include <float.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#if UINTMAX_MAX==ULLONG_MAX
  #define TYPE_UINTMAX_MAX
  #define TYPE_UINTMAX_MIN
#else  //UINTMAX_MAX!=ULLONG_MAX
  #define TYPE_UINTMAX_MAX                    \
      , uintmax_t           : UINTMAX_MAX     \
      , intmax_t            : INTMAX_MAX      \

  #define TYPE_UINTMAX_MIN                    \
      , uintmax_t           : UINTMAX_MIN     \
      , intmax_t            : INTMAX_MIN      \

#endif //UINTMAX_MAX==ULLONG_MAX


#define TYPE_MAX(variable) _Generic          \
  (                                          \
    (variable)                               \
    , bool                : 1                \
    , char                : CHAR_MAX         \
    , unsigned char       : UCHAR_MAX        \
    , signed   char       : SCHAR_MAX        \
    , unsigned short      : USHRT_MAX        \
    , signed   short      : SHRT_MAX         \
    , unsigned int        : UINT_MAX         \
    , signed   int        : INT_MAX          \
    , unsigned long       : ULONG_MAX        \
    , signed   long       : LONG_MAX         \
    , unsigned long long  : ULLONG_MAX       \
    , signed   long long  : LLONG_MAX        \
    TYPE_UINTMAX_MAX                         \
                                             \
    , float               : FLT_MAX          \
    , double              : DBL_MAX          \
    , long double         : LDBL_MAX         \
  )

#define TYPE_MIN(variable) _Generic          \
  (                                          \
    (variable)                               \
    , bool                : 0                \
    , char                : CHAR_MIN         \
    , unsigned char       : 0                \
    , signed   char       : SCHAR_MIN        \
    , unsigned short      : 0                \
    , signed   short      : SHRT_MIN         \
    , unsigned int        : 0                \
    , signed   int        : INT_MIN          \
    , unsigned long       : 0                \
    , signed   long       : LONG_MIN         \
    , unsigned long long  : 0                \
    , signed   long long  : LLONG_MIN        \
    TYPE_UINTMAX_MIN                         \
                                             \
    , float               : -FLT_MAX         \
    , double              : -DBL_MAX         \
    , long double         : -LDBL_MAX        \
  )
```

Let's say `off_t` is defined with `typedef int64_t off_t` and `int64_t` is defined with `typedef long long int64_t`, then the C compiler will treat `off_t foo; TYPE_MAX(foo)` the same as `long long foo; TYPE_MAX(foo)` and will chose the option with the value `LLONG_MAX`, giving you the maximum.

If a system has another native type not listed in this header file, make a preprocessor variable that is empty on other systems but contains the values for that native type when you compile on a system with that type. And then add this preprocessor variable to the list, similar to how it was done here with `uintmax_t`.

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to look at limits.h (added in C99) this header provides macros that should be set to match the compiler's ranges. (either it is provided along with the Standard library that came with the compiler, or a third party standard library replacement is responsible for getting it right)

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such constant for `off_t` ☹ and it seems that we _really_ need them for signed types… which `off_t` is one…