# What is the most portable way to read and write the highest bit of an integer in C?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

What is the most portable way to read and write the highest bit of an integer in C?

This is a Bloomberg interview question. I didn’t give best answer at that time. Can anyone please answer it?

Comment: GNU C is not very portable...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the type is unsigned, it's easy:

```
(type)-1-(type)-1/2
```

For signed values, I know no way. If you find a way, it would answer several unanswered questions on SO:

[C question: off_t (and other signed integer types) minimum and maximum values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514572/c-question-off-t-and-other-signed-integer-types-minimum-and-maximum-values)

[Is there any way to compute the width of an integer type at compile-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957252/is-there-any-way-to-compute-the-width-of-an-integer-type-at-compile-time)

Maybe others.

Comment: what do you mean  (type) -1 ?? can you give me the real C code? confused . maybe I didn't get it. sorry

Comment: `(type)` is a typecast to type `type`. For example, you could do `(unsigned int)-1 - (unsigned int) -1 / 2`.

Comment: i tried, but didn't get right result. what's wrong with me? can you give me a short program snippet? how can you prove this is right? confused still..

Comment: What result did you get and what did you expect? On a system with 32-bit int, `(unsigned)-1-(unsigned)-1/2` gives me `0x80000000` as expected.

Comment: another possibility would be `~((unsigned)-1 >> 1)`

Comment: @Christoph: Indeed. I'm just in a habit of avoiding the bitwise operators and always using arithmetic ones. (Note however that `<<` and `>>` are arithmetic and not bitwise, per C's specification of them.)

Comment: It's interesting how much more readable the answer is with spaces ala `(type)-1 - (type)-1 / 2`... :-/.

Answer (score 5):

First, note that there's no portable way to access the top bit if we're talking about signed integers; there's simply no single portable representation defined in the standard, so the meaning of 'top bit' can in principle vary. Additionally, C does not allow direct access to the bitwise representation; you can access the int as a `char` buffer, but you have no idea where the 'top bit' is located.

If we're only concerned with the non-negative range of a signed integer, and assuming said range has a size that is a power of two (if not, then we need to care about the signed representation again):

```
#define INT_MAX_BIT (INT_MAX - (INT_MAX >> 1))
#define SET_MAX_BIT(x) (x | INT_MAX_BIT)
#define CLEAR_MAX_BIT(x) (x & ~INT_MAX_BIT)
```

A similar approach can be used with unsigned ints, where it can be used to get the true top bit.

Comment: This only works for integer types that have limits specifies in `limits.h`. For instance, it does not work for `off_t`.

Comment: @R, true, but it's hard to see an efficient, portable method that doesn't use a `_MAX` macro and doesn't invoke undefined (or implementation-defined) behavior...

Comment: i'm sorry,can you explain it for me why "#define INT_MAX_BIT (INT_MAX - (INT_MAX >> 1))" works? I didn't get it

Comment: Typically `INT_MAX` has a value that has all 1s set (assuming INT_MAX is 2^n - 1 for some n). Shifting right one results in the top bit being cleared. Then subtracting from the original leaves only the top bit set.

Comment: The standard actually puts quite tight restrictions on the representation of integer types - for example, the maximum values of both signed and unsigned types must be `2**N - 1`.  See section 6.2.6.2.

Comment: Ah, I see; and it actually is restricted to one of three signed integer representations. Although there's nothing that says the sign bit must be the "top" bit :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a silly one, using:

```
Built-in Function: int __builtin_clz (unsigned int x)

Returns the number of leading 0-bits in x, starting at the most
significant bit position. If x is 0, the result is undefined.
```

First attempt:

```
int get_msb(int x) { return x ? __buildin_clz(x) == 0 : 0; }
```

Note: it's a quirk of C that functions specifying `int` or `unsigned int` parameters can be called with the other type without warning.  But, this probably involves a conversion - the C++ Standard 4.7.2 says:

> If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2n where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type). [Note: In a two's complement representation, this conversion is conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern (if there is no truncation). ]

Which implies that the bit pattern may be changed if it's not a two's complement representation, which would stop this "solution" working reliably too. :-(

Chris's comment below provides a solution (incorporated here as a function rather than preprocessor macro):

```
int get_msb(int x) { return x ? __buildin_clz(*(unsigned*)&x) == 0 : 0; }
```

Comment: The workaround would be `#define msb(x) __builtin_clz(*(unsigned)&x)` but then you can't use it on literal numbers. The GCC workaround would be `#define msb(x) ({ typeof(x) _x = x; __builtin_clz(*(unsigned)&_x); })`

Comment: @Chris: that's neat... in the function above the `int x` parameter would receive literals anyway, and you can then do the cast as you suggest.  I'll update the code above.  Thanks!

Comment: The cast is technically undefined behavior, which means it's not guaranteed to work. In practice, it will reinterpret the address of a signed value as an unsigned value (which is rightly undefined behavior since the standard doesn't specify a particular sign representation) much the same way as `union { int i; unsigned u; } u; u.i = x; return __builtin_clz(u.j);` would. I used a macro so that it would work on both signed and unsigned `int` types, invoking UB only for the signed version. But any way you do it will end up being necessarily platform dependent.

Comment: @Chris: yes, I knew that, but wouldn't be surprised if GCC itself doesn't work on any systems that quirky... :-).

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with this one?

```
int get_msb(int n){
    return ((unsigned)n) >> (sizeof(unsigned) * CHAR_BIT - 1);
    // or, optionally
    return n < 0;
};

int set_msb(int n, int msb){
    if (msb)
         return ((unsigned)n) |  (1ULL << (sizeof(unsigned) * CHAR_BIT - 1));
    else return ((unsigned)n) & ~(1ULL << (sizeof(unsigned) * CHAR_BIT - 1));
};
```

It takes care of endianness, number of bits in a byte, and works also on 1's complement.

Comment: This assumes twos-complement representation. The OP requested a portable way :)

Comment: The C standard does not limit the options to "twos or ones complement". Per 6.5.7.5, the result of a right-shift of a negative value is completely implementation defined; the result of a left-shift outside of the range of positive values is undefined and could, in principle, even crash.

Comment: Also not portable in that `sizeof(X)*CHAR_BIT` assumes no padding bits.

Comment: By using [modular] arithmetic instead of bit hacks.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define HIGH_BIT(inttype) (((inttype)1) << (CHAR_BIT * sizeof(inttype) - 1))
```

example usage:

```
ptrdiff_t i = 4711;
i |=  HIGH_BIT(ptrdiff_t);  /* set high bit */
i &= ~HIGH_BIT(ptrdiff_t);  /* clear high bit */
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.