# Completely removing most significant bit

Tags: c, binary

I don't know how to proceed with this...
I want to change a binary stored as an int `1111` to `111` being stored as an int also?

Comment: Please read up on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The number of bits in a number stored in a computer's memory (or a CPU's registers) is fixed, so you should set the bits you want to "remove" to 0: `0111` = `111`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you set only certain bits of a byte in C without affecting the rest?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439078/how-do-you-set-only-certain-bits-of-a-byte-in-c-without-affecting-the-rest)

Comment: @try-catch-finally: Not really a duplicate of that; this one needs to remove the most significant 1 bit, wherever that happens to be.

Comment: @TomZych: is the most significant bit not _a certain bit_ or what? As the question is at the moment, I can't see that OP wants his code to be flexible to unset the 6th bit in `111111` too, with the same algorithm. Further, four bits aren't an integer so _1_111 is not the most significant bit. If the OP wants his code to unset _1_11111 too, he should mention it. `.oO( luckily the comment says "possible dupicate" )` Maybe [this is a better duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233452/set-most-significant-bit-in-c) :)

Comment: @try-catch-finally: Well, yes, I assumed a generalization of what the OP asked, mostly based on what the title says. Not an unreasonable guess at what the OP would have asked if they'd managed to be more coherent, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't ordinarily answer "gimme teh codez" questions, but it was an
interesting problem so I did it for fun. As usual, most of the time went
into extraneous stuff like the output code.

If this is homework, **do** take the time to understand how the code
works, or you'll only be cheating yourself.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Define "number" as an unsigned number of desired size
typedef unsigned long number;

number drop_msb(number n);
char *ntob(char *dest, number n, int min_len);

int main()
{
    number i;
    number j;
    char ibuf[65];
    char jbuf[65];

    for (i = 0; i < 512; i++) {
        j = drop_msb(i);
        ntob(ibuf, i, 0);
        ntob(jbuf, j, strlen(ibuf) - 1);
        printf("%s --> %s\n", ibuf, jbuf);
    }

    return 0;
}

number drop_msb(number n)
{
    number bit;
    number a;

    // Handle special case
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;

    // Set highest bit
    bit = ((number) -1 >> 1) ^ (number) -1;

    // Guaranteed to terminate
    while (1) {
        a = n ^ bit;
        if (a < n)
            return a;
        bit >>= 1;
    }
}

char *ntob(char *dest, number n, int min_len)
{
    /* Convert n to shortest binary string, padding with zeroes on left
     * to make it at least min_len characters long. dest should be long
     * enough to hold the maximum number, plus terminating null. */

    char *left;
    char *right;

    /* min_len should be >= 1, to handle n == 0 correctly. Also needs to
     * be non-negative to avoid bad pointer during padding. */
    if (min_len < 1)
        min_len = 1;

    // Build with lsb on left
    for (right = dest; n; right++, n >>= 1)
        *right = '0' | (n & 1);

    // Pad if needed
    while (right < dest + min_len)
        *right++ = '0';

    *right = '\0';

    // Reverse it
    for (left = dest, right--; left < right; left++, right--) {
        *left ^= *right;
        *right ^= *left;
        *left ^= *right;
    }

    return dest;
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If there's a mistake in the code, you should let the poster know in a comment.

Comment: @szczurcio: Who cares? Someone being petty. *Non ragioniam di lor, ma guarda e passa.*

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned int test(unsigned int n)
{
unsigned int answer = 1;

while(n>>=1 && n)
{
    answer <<= 1;
} 
answer = (answer-1);
return answer;
}
```

This should solve your problem.