# Programmatically determining max value of a signed integer type

Tags: c, overflow, signed

This related question is about determining the max value of a signed type at compile-time:

[C question: off_t (and other signed integer types) minimum and maximum values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514572/c-question-off-t-and-other-signed-integer-types-minimum-and-maximum-values)

However, I've since realized that determining the max value of a signed type (e.g. `time_t` or `off_t`) at **runtime** seems to be a very difficult task.

The closest thing to a solution I can think of is:

```
uintmax_t x = (uintmax_t)1<<CHAR_BIT*sizeof(type)-2;
while ((type)x<=0) x>>=1;
```

This avoids any looping as long as `type` has no padding bits, but if `type` does have padding bits, the cast invokes implementation-defined behavior, which could be a signal or a nonsensical implementation-defined conversion (e.g. stripping the sign bit).

I'm beginning to think the problem is unsolvable, which is a bit unsettling and would be a defect in the C standard, in my opinion. Any ideas for proving me wrong?

Comment: I don't agree that it's a defect in the C standard - whoever defined the type also had the opportunity to define `_MIN` and `_MAX` macros corresponding to the type, which are far more convenient to use anyway.  In the `off_t` case, not defining such macros is really a defect in POSIX.  I suppose C could in theory include a pair of operators `_Minof` and `_Maxof` along the lines of `sizeof`, making such macros unnecessary.

Comment: Part of the `time_t` issue is that ISO C defines `time_t` but as an almost-opaque type that's nearly useless (with no need for min/max values), while POSIX further specifies it to be seconds since the epoch (and now knowing min/max becomes useful).

Comment: By the way, a `_Widthof` operator would probably be more useful.

Comment: Isn't `(type)x` UB if the value doesn't fit?

Comment: @Jens: not undefined, but implementation-defined - with the possibility of raising a signal...

Comment: @R. I think the defect is simply in the extreme cases for the relation `signed/unsigned` that are allowed by the standard. I think nowadays they make not much sense anymore. If we could simply have that the width of signed and unsigned types are the same, all the problem would disappear.

Comment: @Jens: Not really. There's no way to specify a type that's "the unsigned type corresponding to `foo_t`". If there were, the problem would be easy to solve.

Comment: @R:. I find that the most usual reason for needing the range of a type at runtime is to pre-check before calculations to ensure that the result won't overflow, for which use the maximum and minimum are generally the most convenient constants.  However, I can see the argument for a `_Widthof`, since `_Maxof` at least could be conveniently implemented in terms of it, but not the reverse.  Perhaps all three are useful.  I wonder how hard it would be to add such operators to gcc?

Comment: @caf: Actually `_Widthof` and `_Maxof` are interchangeable as an amazing result of another question I asked, but very few people know how. And of course `_Minof` is trivially equivalent to `_Maxof` since the relationship between min/max is immediately known once you know if signed values are twos complement or ones-complement or sign/magnitude, which is easily testable.

Comment: @R.: It's possible to write a convenient constant-expression for log base 2?

Comment: @caf: I thought it was impossible (and of course it is in general), but for values of the form 2^n or 2^n-1 (or 2^n plus any fixed k, of course) up to *insanely large* limits, there is a formula in terms of simple arithmetic operations. See AQG's answer to my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957252/is-there-any-way-to-compute-the-width-of-an-integer-type-at-compile-time

Comment: @R.: That is quite something.

Comment: Why are you trying to solve this problem? When you keep hitting a wall, the best solution is often to go around it.

Comment: I considered it an interesting open problem, and since nobody has found any answers and I have an abundance of spare rep to throw around, I thought I'd put a bounty on it and see if anyone can some up with a solution. I suspect, however, it may not be solvable...

Comment: I worked out a solution to the configure-time version of the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514572/c-question-off-t-and-other-signed-integer-types-minimum-and-maximum-values/5862036#5862036

Comment: Determining the max value of `time_t` is challenging as `time_t` may be a FP type.  (Commented by OP [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813055/programmatically-determining-max-value-of-a-signed-integer-type#comment6564024_5737382))

Comment: @chux: That's trivial to test: `(T)1/2`. For implementations conforming to Annex F, the max value is then `INFINITY`. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** Thankfully, my previous answer below was wrong, and there seems to be a solution to this question.

```
intmax_t x;
for (x=INTMAX_MAX; (T)x!=x; x/=2);
```

This program either yields `x` containing the max possible value of type `T`, or generates an implementation-defined signal.

Working around the signal case may be possible but difficult and computationally infeasible (as in having to install a signal handler for every possible signal number), so I don't think this answer is fully satisfactory. POSIX signal semantics may give enough additional properties to make it feasible; I'm not sure.

The interesting part, especially if you're comfortable assuming you're not on an implementation that will generate a signal, is what happens when `(T)x` results in an implementation-defined conversion. The trick of the above loop is that it does not rely at all on the implementation's choice of value for the conversion. All it relies upon is that `(T)x==x` is possible if and only if `x` fits in type `T`, since otherwise the value of `x` is outside the range of possible values of *any expression* of type `T`.

---

**Old idea, wrong because it does not account for the above `(T)x==x` property:**

I think I have a sketch of a proof that what I'm looking for is impossible:

1. Let X be a conforming C implementation and assume `INT_MAX>32767`.
2. Define a new C implementation Y identical to X, but where the values of `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN` are each divided by 2.
3. Prove that Y is a conforming C implementation.

The essential idea of this outline is that, due to the fact that everything related to out-of-bound values with signed types is implementation-defined or undefined behavior, an arbitrary number of the high *value bits* of a signed integer type can be considered as *padding bits* without actually making any changes to the implementation except the limit macros in `limits.h`.

Any thoughts on if this sounds correct or bogus? If it's correct, I'd be happy to award the bounty to whoever can do the best job of making it more rigorous.

Comment: Ref: "Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised." C11dr §6.3.1.3 3

Comment: I think you want `INT_MAX>=32767`  `>=` vs `>`?

Comment: If the implementation-defined value for an out-of-range `x` of `(T)x` is -1, then `(-1 != x` is false before the first iteration and `x` has the value of `UINTMAX_MAX`.  Do not think this method works in that case.

Comment: @chux: Thanks. I think it can be fixed by changing to `intmax_t` and `INTMAX_MAX` rather than `-1`, though, right?

Comment: @chux: No they're not. Reread what you wrote. `intmax_t` is a signed type.

Comment: Egg on face - yes I was thinking `uintmax_t`.  Deleting prior comment.

Comment: I think your re-work to `intmax_t` and `INTMAX_MAX` will work for _signed_ types (except for extended integer types) - will ponder it.

Comment: `intmax_t` is at least as large as extended integer types. Things like `__int128`, on systems where `intmax_t` is 64-bit, are simply nonstandard language extensions, not "extended integer types".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125055/discussion-between-chux-and-r).

Comment: If you don't get a signal, I don't think that `(T)x==x` would necessarily work as you want, because the standard does not say that the conversion or value is implementation-defined, but that the *result* is implementation-defined, and in the standard, *result* can mean pretty much anything; for instance, an implementation-defined result may be a trap representation, as explicitly said in 6.3.2.3#5, as opposed to implementation-defined values. But this goes even beyond that.

Comment: @vinc17 §6.3.2.3(5) applies to pointer-to-integer conversions only. (I also see it as a list that may happen in addition to IB result, not one that applies to the term IB result. “result” isn’t as well-defined as value, but from context also elsewhere in the document, “result” here means “the value the operation results in”.

Answer (score 4):

Let's first see how C defines "integer types". Taken from [ISO/IEC 9899](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf), §6.2.6.2:

> 6.2.6.2 Integer types
>   
> 1
>  For unsigned integer types other than unsigned char, the bits of the object
>   representation shall be divided into two groups: value bits and padding bits (there need
>   not be any of the latter). If there are N value bits, each bit shall represent a different
>   power of 2 between 1 and 2N−1, so that objects of that type shall be capable of
>   representing values from 0 to 2N − 1 using a pure binary representation; this shall be
>   known as the value representation. The values of any padding bits are unspecified.44)
>   
> 2 
> For signed integer types, the bits of the object representation shall be divided into three
>   groups: value bits, padding bits, and the sign bit. There need not be any padding bits;
>   there shall be exactly one sign bit. Each bit that is a value bit shall have the same value as the same bit in the object representation of the corresponding unsigned type (if there are M value bits in the signed type and N in the unsigned type, then M ≤ N). If the sign bit
>   is zero, it shall not affect the resulting value. If the sign bit is one, the value shall be
>   modified in one of the following ways:
>
> — the corresponding value with sign bit 0 is negated (sign and magnitude);
>   
> — the sign bit has the value −(2N) (two’s complement);
>   
> — the sign bit has the value −(2N − 1) (ones’ complement).
>   
> Which of these applies is implementation-defined, as is whether the value with sign bit 1
>   and all value bits zero (for the first two), or with sign bit and all value bits 1 (for ones’
>   complement), is a trap representation or a normal value. In the case of sign and
>   magnitude and ones’ complement, if this representation is a normal value it is called a
>   negative zero.

Hence we can conclude the following:

- `~(int)0` may be a trap representation, i.e. setting all bits to is a bad idea
- There might be padding bits in an `int` that have no effect on its value
- The order of the bits actually representing powers of two is undefined; so is the position of the sign bit, if it exists.

The good news is that:

- there's only a single sign bit
- there's only a single bit that represents the value 1

With that in mind, there's a simple technique to find the maximum value of an `int`. Find the sign bit, then set it to 0 and set all other bits to 1.

How do we find the sign bit? Consider `int n = 1;`, which is strictly positive and guaranteed to have only the one-bit and maybe some padding bits set to 1. Then for all other bits `i`, if `i==0` holds true, set it to 1 and see if the resulting value is negative. If it's not, revert it back to 0. Otherwise, we've found the sign bit.

Now that we know the position of the sign bit, we take our `int n`, set the sign bit to zero and all other bits to 1, and tadaa, we have the maximum possible `int` value.

Determining the `int` *minimum* is slightly more complicated and left as an exercise to the reader.

Note that the C standard humorously doesn't require two different `int`s to behave the same. If I'm not mistaken, there may be two distinct `int` objects that have e.g. their respective sign bits at different positions.

**EDIT:** while discussing this approach with R.. (see comments below), I have become convinced that it is flawed in several ways and, more generally, that there is no solution at all. I can't see a way to fix this posting (except deleting it), so I let it unchanged for the comments below to make sense.

Comment: How do you avoid generating trap representations? BTW your last paragraph is nonsense due to "Representation of Types" and the way `memcpy` (or the by-hand equivalent, casting to `unsigned char *`) is defined.

Comment: Note that the only way to "set a bit" like you describe is casting a pointer to `unsigned char *` and setting the bit through that.

Comment: @R..: are there any other potential trap representations besides `~0`? I think that I see your point from the second comment: it's not feasible to use `some_int |= (1<<i);` to set the (i+1)th bit, because initially we don't know the representation of `1`. Is that your concern?

Comment: No, the reason is that `1<<i` can overflow and invoke UB. `<<` is an arithmetic operator not a bitwise operator.

Comment: Also, there are potentially other trap representations, but they cannot be generated without accessing the representation (via `unsigned char *`).

Comment: `a<<i` can of course overflow, but this only results in UB if `a` has a signed type. For unsigned types, the value of `a<<i` is defined as `a*2^i % INT_MAX+1` (see §6.5.7, subclause 4). Hence, it should be no problem to use `1<<i` as a bitmask (by "1", I mean "an `int` with all bits set to zero except for the last one"). Furthermore, the *result* of the `<<`-operator is defined bitwise. Only the *value* of the result is defined in arithmetic terms. I'd say that `<<` is clearly a bitwise operator.

Comment: Regarding trap representations: `int`s are required to only have padding bits, value bits and a sign bit. We may toggle the padding bits in any way we please, because trap representations are caused by illegal *values*, not by illegal *representations*, and padding bits don't have any influence on the value. Furthermore, we know that setting all bits to 1 may be a trap representation (negative zero on One's Complement), but we clearly avoid it with my method. If I am not mistaken, any other trap representations are environment-specific and completely arbitrary. Am I missing something here?

Comment: `1<<i` definitely will not do what you want, because `1` has type `int`, which might be smaller than the type in question, in which case `1<<i` will overflow before filling the type in question. `(uintmax_t)1<<i` would avoid this problem and UB, but converting back to the type in question would then have implementation-defined behavior.

Comment: As for padding bits, there is **no way to access padding bits** except via the representation as `unsigned char [sizeof(type)]`. The `<<` operator operates on *values*, not *representations*, and **cannot access them**.

Comment: Ah, finally I think that I can follow your concerns. I'll update my posting to reflect my new opinion: I'm pretty much convinced now that there is no solution to your original problem. Sorry for being so slow, and let's see if somebody else comes up with an *actual* solution in spite of our shared pessimism. Speaking for me, I learned a lot during the course of this discussion. Thanks :)

Comment: In that case at least the 150 rep was good for something. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Mathematically, if you have a finite set (X, of size n (n a positive integer) and a comparison operator (x,y,z in X; x<=y and y<=z implies x<=z), it's a very simple problem to find the maximum value.  (Also, it exists.)

The easiest way to solve this problem, but the most computationally expensive, is to generate an array with all possible values from, then find the max.

Part 1.   For any type with a finite member set, there's a finite number of bits (m) which can be used to uniquely represent any given member of that type.  We just make an array which contains all possible bit patterns, where any given bit pattern is represented by a given value in the specific type.

Part 2.  Next we'd need to convert each binary number into the given type.  This task is where my programming inexperience makes me unable to speak to how this may be accomplished.  I've read some about casting, maybe that would do the trick?  Or some other conversion method?

Part 3.  Assuming that the previous step was finished, we now have a finite set of values in the desired type and a comparison operator on that set.  Find the max.

But what if...

...we don't know the exact number of members of the given type?  Than we over-estimate.  If we can't produce a reasonable over-estimate, than there should be physical bounds on the number.  Once we have an over-estimate, we check all of those possible bit patters to confirm which bit patters represent members of the type.  After discarding those which aren't used, we now have a set of all possible bit patterns which represent some member of the given type.  This most recently generated set is what we'd use now at part 1.

...we don't have a comparison operator in that type?  Than the specific problem is not only impossible, but logically irrelevant.  That is,  if our program doesn't have access to give a meaningful result to if we compare two values from our given type, than our given type has no ordering in the context of our program.  Without an ordering, there's no such thing as a maximum value.

...we can't convert a given binary number into a given type?  Then the method breaks.  But similar to the previous exception, if you can't convert types, than our tool-set  seems logically very limited.

Technically, you may not need to convert between binary representations and a given type.  The entire point of the conversion is to insure the generated list is exhaustive.

...we want to optimize the problem?  Than we need some information about how the given type maps from binary numbers.  For example, unsigned int, signed int (2's compliment), and signed int (1's compliment) each map from bits into numbers in a very documented and simple way.  Thus, if we wanted the highest possible value for unsigned int and we knew we were working with m bits, than we could simply fill each bit with a 1, convert the bit pattern to decimal, then output the number.

This relates to optimization because the most expensive part of this solution is the listing of all possible answers.  If we have some previous knowledge of how the given type maps from bit patterns, we can generate a subset of all possibilities by making instead all potential candidates.

Good luck.

Comment: +1 for great first answer effort. This would be a good answer to the general computational problem, but unfortunately it doesn't deal with the technicalities of the C language that make it impossible to generate "all possible values" for a signed type without knowing something more about the type.

Comment: Actually, since I don't want the +150 to go to waste and you said "what if...we can't convert a given binary number into a given type?" which is basically the problem and the dead end we run into, have it. And welcome to the SO community!

Comment: Here's a partial solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514572/c-question-off-t-and-other-signed-integer-types-minimum-and-maximum-values/5862036#5862036

Answer (score 1):

I might just be writing stupid things here, since I'm relatively new to C, but wouldn't this work for getting the max of a `signed`?

```
unsigned x = ~0;
signed y=x/2;
```

This might be a dumb way to do it, but as far as I've seen `unsigned max` values are `signed max`*2+1. Won't it work backwards?

Sorry for the time wasted if this proves to be completely inadequate and incorrect.

Comment: `unsigned` means `unsigned int` and `signed` means `int`. Here, the question was for *any* signed integer type. Otherwise, for `int`, the answer would simply be `INT_MAX`.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't something like the following pseudo code do the job?

```
signed_type_of_max_size test_values =
    [(1<<7)-1, (1<<15)-1, (1<<31)-1, (1<<63)-1];

for test_value in test_values:
    signed_foo_t a = test_value;
    signed_foo_t b = a + 1;
    if (b < a):
        print "Max positive value of signed_foo_t is ", a
```

Or much simpler, why shouldn't the following work?

```
signed_foo_t signed_foo_max = (1<<(sizeof(signed_foo_t)*8-1))-1;
```

For my own code, I would definitely go for a build-time check defining a preprocessor macro, though.

Comment: No, this code invokes undefined behavior. A much smaller (and fixable) problem is that it only tests a discrete set of possibilities.

Comment: Your simplified code has overflow issues and assumes no padding bits.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming modifying padding bits won't create trap representations, you could use an `unsigned char *` to loop over and flip individual bits until you hit the sign bit. If your initial value was `~(type)0`, this should get you the maximum:

```
type value = ~(type)0;
assert(value < 0);

unsigned char *bytes = (void *)&value;
size_t i = 0;
for(; i < sizeof value * CHAR_BIT; ++i)
{
    bytes[i / CHAR_BIT] ^= 1 << (i % CHAR_BIT);
    if(value > 0) break;
    bytes[i / CHAR_BIT] ^= 1 << (i % CHAR_BIT);
}

assert(value != ~(type)0);
// value == TYPE_MAX
```

Comment: as Jens mentioned, this might already fail during the first step as `~` can produce trap representations

Answer (score 0):

Since you allow this to be at runtime you could write a function that *de facto* does an iterative left shift of `(type)3`. If you stop once the value is fallen below `0`, this will never give you a trap representation. And the number of iterations - 1 will tell you the position of the sign bit.

Remains the problem of the left shift. Since just using the operator `<<` would lead to an overflow, this would be undefined behavior, so we can't use the operator directly.

The simplest solution to that is not to use a shifted `3` as above but to iterate over the bit positions and to add always the least significant bit also.

```
type x;
unsigned char*B = &x;
size_t signbit = 7;
for(;;++signbit) {
  size_t bpos = signbit / CHAR_BIT;
  size_t apos = signbit % CHAR_BIT;
  x = 1;
  B[bpos] |= (1 << apos);
  if (x < 0) break;
}
```

(The start value `7` is the minimum width that a signed type must have, I think).

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't that basically the same algorithm I suggested? if so, the caveat from my answer applies here as well: the conversion to `unsigned char *` will expose padding bits...

Comment: @Christophe, they are similar agreed. But assuming that we are able to process the bytes in the order of significance, no we are not modifying padding bits. We always start from a valid value namely `1` and modify exactly one bit. You may have UB right from the start, because `~0` may be a trap representation.

Comment: @Jens: `~(type)0` should never be a trap representation; I also don't think you are correct in stating that your algorithm is guaranteed to only operate on value bits as padding bits can legally occur in the middle of value bits; the C99 rationale even mentions that the existence of such an architecture was one of the reasons for the introduction of integer padding

Comment: @Christoph, yes, `~0` can be a trap representation for one's complement, this is explicitly mentioned. Hm, but for the consecutiveness of the value bits in the object, in effect, there seems no mentioning of that, either way. I didn't find the rational that you mention, though.

Comment: @Jens: the cited architecture constructed 32-bit signed integers from two 16-bit signed integers; one of the sign bits was used as sign bit for the resulting integer, the other one discarded, resulting in a padding bit in the middle of the value; see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf 6.2.6.2

Comment: @Jens, re `~0`: you're right - I did not remember that, but see C99 6.2.6.2 §4

Comment: @Christoph, wow, never imagined that such a thing would exist. (I mean to not interpret the lower word as unsigned.) Hopefully these extreme hacks will die out, eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Why would this present a problem? The size of the type is fixed at compile time, so the problem of determining the runtime size of the type reduces to the problem of determining the compile-time size of the type. For any given target platform, a declaration such as `off_t offset` will be compiled to use some fixed size, and that size will then always be used when running the resulting executable on the target platform.

***ETA:*** You can get the size of the type `type` via `sizeof(type)`. You could then compare against common integer sizes and use the corresponding `MAX`/`MIN` preprocessor define. You might find it simpler to just use:

```
uintmax_t bitWidth = sizeof(type) * CHAR_BIT;
intmax_t big2 = 2;  /* so we do math using this integer size */
intmax_t sizeMax = big2^bitWidth - 1;
intmax_t sizeMin = -(big2^bitWidth - 1);
```

Just because a value is representable by the underlying "physical" type does not mean that value is valid for a value of the "logical" type. I imagine the reason max and min constants are not provided is that these are "semi-opaque" types whose use is restricted to particular domains. Where less opacity is desirable, you will often find ways of getting the information you want, such as the constants you can use to figure out how big an `off_t` is that are mentioned by the SUSv2 in [its description of `<unistd.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/unistd.h.html).

Comment: And how do you determine that size, without relying on implementation-defined, unspecified, or undefined behavior? I allowed runtime determination because it makes more things possible, but if you have a way to do it at compiletime (i.e. with constant expressions) that's just as well. I believe it's impossible though, and it may even be impossible at runtime.

Comment: Your question ventures into unspecified details. All the C standard tells you about `time_t` is that it is an arithmetic type capable of representing a time. It does not specify that it is a *signed* arithmetic type.

Comment: Indeed, `time_t` is not the best example, but it's valid because you can determine if it's floating point via `(time_t)1/2!=0` and if it's signed via `(time_t)-1<0`. `off_t` was a better example.

Comment: C does not have a `^` exponentiation operator... And even if it did, this would overflow. Also this assumes no padding bits.

Comment: Agreed.  Did you mean to use `pow`?  `^` is the binary XOR operator, which doesn't seem to make sense for your code.

Answer (score 0):

For an opaque signed type for which you don't have a name of the associated unsigned type, this is unsolvable in a portable way, because any attempt to detect whether there is a padding bit will yield implementation-defined behavior or undefined behavior. The best thing you can deduce by testing (without additional knowledge) is that there are at least *K* padding bits.

BTW, this doesn't really answer the question, but can still be useful in practice: If one assumes that the signed integer type `T` has **no padding bits**, one can use the following macro:

```
#define MAXVAL(T) (((((T) 1 << (sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT - 2)) - 1) * 2) + 1)
```

This is probably the best that one can do. It is simple and does not need to assume anything else about the C implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not getting the question right, but since C gives you 3 possible representations for signed integers (http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.6.2):

- sign and magnitude
- ones' complement
- two's complement

and the max in any of these should be `2^(N-1)-1`, you should be able to get it by taking the max of the corresponding unsigned, `>>1`-shifting it and casting the result to the proper type (which it should fit).

I don't know how to get the corresponding minimum if trap representations get in the way, but if they don't the min should be either `(Tp)((Tp)-1|(Tp)TP_MAX(Tp))` (all bits set) `(Tp)~TP_MAX(Tp)` and which it is should be simple to find out.

Example:

```
#include <limits.h>
#define UNSIGNED(Tp,Val) \
    _Generic((Tp)0, \
            _Bool: (_Bool)(Val), \
            char: (unsigned char)(Val), \
            signed char: (unsigned char)(Val), \
            unsigned char: (unsigned char)(Val), \
            short: (unsigned short)(Val), \
            unsigned short: (unsigned short)(Val), \
            int: (unsigned int)(Val), \
            unsigned int: (unsigned int)(Val), \
            long: (unsigned long)(Val), \
            unsigned long: (unsigned long)(Val), \
            long long: (unsigned long long)(Val), \
            unsigned long long: (unsigned long long)(Val) \
            )
#define MIN2__(X,Y) ((X)<(Y)?(X):(Y))
#define UMAX__(Tp) ((Tp)(~((Tp)0)))
#define SMAX__(Tp) ((Tp)( UNSIGNED(Tp,~UNSIGNED(Tp,0))>>1 ))
#define SMIN__(Tp) ((Tp)MIN2__( \
                    (Tp)(((Tp)-1)|SMAX__(Tp)), \
                    (Tp)(~SMAX__(Tp)) ))
#define TP_MAX(Tp) ((((Tp)-1)>0)?UMAX__(Tp):SMAX__(Tp))
#define TP_MIN(Tp) ((((Tp)-1)>0)?((Tp)0): SMIN__(Tp))
int main()
{
#define STC_ASSERT(X) _Static_assert(X,"")
    STC_ASSERT(TP_MAX(int)==INT_MAX);
    STC_ASSERT(TP_MAX(unsigned int)==UINT_MAX);
    STC_ASSERT(TP_MAX(long)==LONG_MAX);
    STC_ASSERT(TP_MAX(unsigned long)==ULONG_MAX);
    STC_ASSERT(TP_MAX(long long)==LLONG_MAX);
    STC_ASSERT(TP_MAX(unsigned long long)==ULLONG_MAX);

    /*STC_ASSERT(TP_MIN(unsigned short)==USHRT_MIN);*/
    STC_ASSERT(TP_MIN(int)==INT_MIN);
    /*STC_ASSERT(TP_MIN(unsigned int)==UINT_MIN);*/
    STC_ASSERT(TP_MIN(long)==LONG_MIN);
    /*STC_ASSERT(TP_MIN(unsigned long)==ULONG_MIN);*/
    STC_ASSERT(TP_MIN(long long)==LLONG_MIN);
    /*STC_ASSERT(TP_MIN(unsigned long long)==ULLONG_MIN);*/

    STC_ASSERT(TP_MAX(char)==CHAR_MAX);
    STC_ASSERT(TP_MAX(signed char)==SCHAR_MAX);
    STC_ASSERT(TP_MAX(short)==SHRT_MAX);
    STC_ASSERT(TP_MAX(unsigned short)==USHRT_MAX);

    STC_ASSERT(TP_MIN(char)==CHAR_MIN);
    STC_ASSERT(TP_MIN(signed char)==SCHAR_MIN);
    STC_ASSERT(TP_MIN(short)==SHRT_MIN);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For all real machines, (two's complement and no padding):

```
type tmp = ((type)1)<< (CHAR_BIT*sizeof(type)-2);
max = tmp + (tmp-1);
```

With C++, you can calculate it at compile time.

```
template <class T>
struct signed_max
{
      static const T max_tmp =  T(T(1) << sizeof(T)*CO_CHAR_BIT-2u);    
      static const T value = max_tmp + T(max_tmp -1u);
};
```