# Get INT_MAX with bit operations

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

How can I obtain the value of `INT_MAX` using only the bitwise operators, in C? I expected `~0` to be `1111111111` (complement of `1`, so decimal `-1`) and `~0 >> 1` to be `0111111111`, which would be max, but it's still `-1`.

Why is that and how can I obtain the value of `INT_MAX` by using bit operations?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `~0UL >> 1`. The issue is that C will do a sign-extended right shift if it's dealing with a signed type. This is why you're still getting negative one -- because it's shifting in another 1 bit to match the 1 bit that was there. (That way `-8` >> 1 gives `-4` as you'd like for fast divisions by two.)

Comment: `~0UL >> 1` is LONG_MAX. You need `~0U >> 1`. Maybe also cast it to `int`, so it would have the right type.

Comment: Subtle but good point -- uhg, compiler differences always get the best of me. Question is, is any of this ANSI or is there no real standard?

Comment: I think the standard says to use INT_MAX. Your solution works for 2's complement, i.e. any real cpu. As an alternative, I think `for(x=0;x+1>x;x++);` is quite robust, though slow.

Comment: Thinking again, I think it is guaranteed to work. Unsigned numbers are well defined. Signed positive numbers must have the same encoding. The high bit must be the sign (1=negative). So this pattern necessarily gives the largest positive number.

Comment: @ugoren That loop would work for unsigned numbers, but signed overflow is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @DanielFischer, The loop indeed has UB. In practice, it won't crash, so it will stop on INT_MAX (because x+1 surely isn't larger). But it's worthless in practice, and not robust in theory, which doesn't leave much.

Comment: @DanielFischer, There's no right-shifting of negative signed values here. `~0U` is unsigned.

Comment: @ugoren, no the high bit must not necessarily the sign, unfortunately the standard allows scenarios that are more complicated. So this solution doesn't work. There is no completely portable way to find that value but to use `INT_MAX`. That is why this kind of macros exist for all integer types.

Comment: @ugoren a compiler can assume `x + 1 > x` is always `1` if `x` is an `int` because of the overflow. Actually I remember `gcc` would do this optimization when all optimizations are enabled.

Comment: @ugoren My first comment referred to "The issue is that C will do a sign-extended right shift if it's dealing with a signed type." in the answer. Practically, I know of no implementation behaving differently, but the standard leaves it up to the implementation. As for the loop, what ouah said.

Comment: @DanielFischer implementations on small microcontrollers with logical right shift instructions but not arithmetic right shift usually don't propagate the sign.

Comment: @JensGustedt, I actually based my comment on the c99 standard, which clearly defines the meaning of the sign bit. Regarding ANSI C, I'm really not sure - I find it harder to read.

Comment: @ouah, I guess you're right here. I almost said that the compiler won't be stupid enough to reduce it to `while(1);`, but I've seen worse. You could prevent it by calling a function that returns `x+1`, and is defined in another file. But it's really going too far.

Comment: @ugoren, no, even C99 only defines the meaning of the sign bit, but not the relative position in the corresponding unsigned type. Please have a look at http://gustedt.wordpress.com/2010/09/21/anatomy-of-integer-types-in-c/

Comment: @ouah Ah, thanks. I guess those would be freestanding implementations? I'd be somewhat surprised to learn of a hosted implementation not using sign-extension.

Answer (score 2):

If you shift a negative number to the right, the new bits of the number may be 1 (to keep it negative). That why you get -1.

Edit: You can do something like:

```
int i=1;
while (i<<1) i<<=1;
i=~i;
```

Comment: "May be"? As in, not in all implementations?

Comment: I think that the standard says that it depends on the implementation.

Comment: @PaulManta Right-shifting negative numbers is implementation-defined indeed (6.5.7(5)). asaelr, but for `E1 > 0` a value of a signed type, `E1 << E2` is undefined behaviour if `E1 * 2^E2` is not representable in that type, so your alternative relies on a specific interpretation of this undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

If you treat `0` as an unsigned integer, the compiler will not perform a signed shift:

```
int i = ~0U >> 1;
```

This will give you `INT_MAX`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no portable solution except to use the `INT_MAX` macro. See my longstanding question:

[Programmatically determining max value of a signed integer type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813055/programmatically-determining-max-value-of-a-signed-integer-type)

and the question it's based on:

[C question: off_t (and other signed integer types) minimum and maximum values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514572/c-question-off-t-and-other-signed-integer-types-minimum-and-maximum-values)

Answer (score 1):

(1<<31)-1)

as well. This is an old thread but i'll post it anyway for anyone googling it. But it's not entirely bitwise, and it's assuming an "int" on your machine is 32bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int max = ~0U >> 1;
    int min = ~max;

    printf("Max = 0x%X, min = 0x%X", max, min);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Max = 0x7FFFFFFF, min = 0x80000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can find MIN/MAX of any signed integer type. However, I assume left shift does arithmetic shift and fills blanks with zeros, which is true for majority of compilers.

```
#define MIN_OF_SIGNED_TYPE(type) ((type)1 << (sizeof(type) * 8 - 1))
#define MAX_OF_SIGNED_TYPE(type) (~MIN_OF_SIGNED_TYPE(type))

#define MY_INT_MIN MIN_OF_SIGNED_TYPE(int)
#define MY_INT_MAX MAX_OF_SIGNED_TYPE(int)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int int_max = (unsigned int)-1 >> 1;
```