# maximum (and minimum) off_t

Tags: c, limits

I could not find something like `OFF_MAX` that would tell me the maximum allowed value for `off_t` so I wonder if I could perhaps use that:

```
#define OFF_MAX ~((off_t)1 << (sizeof(off_t) * 8 - 1))
#define OFF_MIN  ((off_t)1 << (sizeof(off_t) * 8 - 1))
```

I know bit operations on signed values is generally undefined, but is it ok for x86 and ARM, Windows (mingw), Linux and Mac OS X?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514572/c-question-off-t-and-other-signed-integer-types-minimum-and-maximum-values ?

Comment: Which has no accepted answer.

Comment: a `char` has not necessarily 8 bits.

Comment: I don't find `off_t` in the standard. You you mean `ptrdiff_t`?

Comment: IIRC, `off_t` is part of POSIX.

Comment: I mean `off_t` as used by `fseeko` and `struct stat`. And indeed it's POSIX. `off_t` can be 64bit on 32bit platforms, that's why I need a `OFF_MAX` when I parse use input as `off_t`.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite POSIX is the relevant standard for dealing with `off_t` and POSIX has mandated `CHAR_BIT == 8` since 2001.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ (not C), you could just say

```
static constexpr off_t OFF_MIN = std::numeric_limits<off_t>::min();
static constexpr off_t OFF_MAX = std::numeric_limits<off_t>::max();
```

In C, you don't have that generic API, so your macros are pretty close to the best you can do. One thing to watch out for is bit-twiddling involving the sign bit: `(1 << 31) - 1` triggers undefined behavior, so the result isn't necessarily `0x7fffffff` even on real-world systems. ([Godbolt.](https://godbolt.org/z/czPd69GG4)) So you should at least change your bit-twiddling to something like this:

```
#define OFF_MAX ((((off_t)1 << (sizeof(off_t)*8 - 2)) - 1) * 2 + 1)
#define OFF_MIN (-OFF_MAX - 1)
```

Next, for portability to DSPs with 24- or 32-bit `char`, or simply to get rid of that magic number `8`, we could do this:

```
#define OFF_MAX ((((off_t)1 << (sizeof(off_t)*CHAR_BIT - 2)) - 1) * 2 + 1)
#define OFF_MIN (-OFF_MAX - 1)
```

Portability to sign-magnitude or ones'-complement platforms (which essentially do not exist in practice) is left as an exercise for the reader. :) Also these macros are not portable to an actively malicious DeathStation 9000 implementation — like, if `sizeof(off_t) == 128` but 124 of those bytes are just padding.

But instead of doing all this bit-twiddling, **in practice you should just do this:**

```
#define OFF_MAX (sizeof(off_t) == sizeof(long long) ? LLONG_MAX : sizeof(off_t) == sizeof(int) ? INT_MAX : -999999)
#define OFF_MIN (sizeof(off_t) == sizeof(long long) ? LLONG_MIN : sizeof(off_t) == sizeof(int) ? INT_MIN : -999999)
```

Systems where `off_t` is neither 32-bit nor 64-bit are, IMHO, neither common nor valuable.

---

Finally... I have basically no experience here, but *it seems to me* that usually when you want to know the effective "max" of `off_t`, it's because you're about to do something like [`ftruncate(fd, x)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/ftruncate) and you want to know whether `x` is going to throw you an `EFBIG` error instead of succeeding. In that case, you really need something *operation-specific*, something that is to `OFF_MAX` as `RSIZE_MAX` is to `SIZE_MAX` (see [Why is rsize_t defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33604857/why-is-rsize-t-defined) ), or analogous to `MAX_PATH` or `PIPE_BUF` from [`<linux/limits.h>`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man0/limits.h.0p.html) or [`RAND_MAX`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/RAND_MAX) from `<stdlib.h>`.

On some systems, the point-at-which-`EFBIG`-starts-happening might be accessible (at runtime) via something like this:

```
// #include <sys/resource.h>
rlimit lim;
getrlimit(RLIMIT_FSIZE, &lim);
printf("%zu %zu\n", (size_t)lim.rlim_cur), (size_t)lim.rlim_max));
```

On my MacBook, that just prints `SIZE_MAX`, so it's not very useful.