# Why is rsize_t defined?

Tags: c++, size-t, tr24731

I found that `strncpy_s()` is defined under *VS2013* as

```
errno_t __cdecl strncpy_s
(
  _Out_writes_z_(_SizeInBytes) char * _Dst, 
  _In_ rsize_t _SizeInBytes, 
  _In_reads_or_z_(_MaxCount) const char * _Src, 
  _In_ rsize_t _MaxCount
);
```

`rsize_t` is:

```
typedef size_t rsize_t;
```

I think it's a trick done by **Visual Studio**. However, I found this function  defined as follows on this [page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy)

```
errno_t strncpy_s
(
  char *restrict dest,
  rsize_t destsz,
  const char *restrict src, 
  rsize_t count
);
```

Why is `rsize_t` defined here?

What if `size_t` was used here?

Any special cases to use this `rsize_t`?

Comment: Isn't this a visual studio specific `typedef`? It doesn't seem to appear in my header files, nor does it seem to appear in my standard draft.

Comment: You might (or might not) find some useful information in [Do you use the TR-24731 "safe" functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372980/do-you-use-the-tr-24731-safe-functions)  At least, there are some issues highlighted there that you should be aware of if you are concerned about portability.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You've encountered it in Microsoft's C++ standard library, but it actually comes from C. C 11, to be precise, which means it's not technically a part of C++.

*C 11 standard, Annex K* introduced all the `_s` functions and the corresponding typedefs, including `rsize_t`. There is also a "maximum value" macro `RSIZE_MAX` which is large enough for typical applications, but smaller than the real maximum value of the type. The secure functions do nothing and report an error when a value of type `rsize_t` exceeds `RSIZE_MAX`.

The idea is to avoid crashes on buffer overruns and similar errors caused by invalid sizes, usually resulting from using a negative value for size. In 2's complement signed value representation (the most common one), a negative number corresponds to a *very* large number when treated as unsigned. `RSIZE_MAX` should catch such incorrect use.

Quoting the "rationale" part of C11 (N1570), K.3.2:

> 3 Extremely large object sizes are frequently a sign that an object’s size was calculated
>   incorrectly. For example, negative numbers appear as very large positive numbers when
>   converted to an unsigned type like `size_t`. Also, some implementations do not support
>   objects as large as the maximum value that can be represented by type `size_t`.
>
> 4 For those reasons, it is sometimes beneficial to restrict the range of object sizes to detect
>   programming errors. For implementations targeting machines with large address spaces,
>   it is recommended that `RSIZE_MAX` be defined as the smaller of the size of the largest
>   object supported or `(SIZE_MAX >> 1)`, even if this limit is smaller than the size of
>   some legitimate, but very large, objects. Implementations targeting machines with small
>   address spaces may wish to define `RSIZE_MAX` as `SIZE_MAX`, which means that there is no object size that is considered a runtime-constraint violation.

---

It is worth noting that Annex K has very few implementations and there is a proposal ([N1967](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm)) to deprecate and/or remove it from the standard.

Comment: @zwol I'll incorporate that (no time now); but I believe Wikipedia mentions Open Watcom has a conforming implementation too.

Comment: @zwol: And the MS implementation is non-conforming, or did that change?

Comment: @Deduplicator Annex K was definitely MS's idea, but I don't know if their implementation is fully conforming.  It would not surprise me if (for instance) they implemented an early draft and then couldn't pick up revisions because that would break binary compatibility.

Comment: @zwol: There's a request to abandon it as a badly flawed and even worse executed bad idea: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm

Answer (score 17):

These typedefs have semantic meaning. Obviously you can use `size_t` here (since it's the same), but `rsize_t` is more verbose:

> The type size_t generally covers the entire address space. ISO/IEC TR 24731-1-2007 introduces a new type rsize_t, defined to be size_t but explicitly used to hold the size of a single object. [[1]](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/INT01-CPP.+Use+rsize_t+or+size_t+for+all+integer+values+representing+the+size+of+an+object)

It's the similar situation as when using `size_t` instead of `unsigned int`. It's basically the same, but named differently so it's easy for you to understand what you're working with (`size_t` = "size of something", which  implies an unsigned whole number).

It is worth noting (as suggested by the comments) that `rsize_t` is defined in the C specification, but not in the C++ specification.

Comment: It might be a good idea to include the fact that `rsize_t` is defined in the C specification, but not in the C++ specification.

Comment: Nice answer, but where is the quote taken from?

Comment: size_t, I suppose it comes from type size, but rsize_t? What does the r means?

Comment: @sop "Restricted," I would say. C11 K.3.2/4 says "For those reasons, it is sometimes beneficial to restrict the range of object sizes to detect
programming errors. For implementations targeting machines with large address spaces,
it is recommended that `RSIZE_MAX` be defined as ..."