# Is it defined behavior when we fseeko() to the maximum offset on /dev/zero and then continue reading?

Tags: c, linux, file-io

While using DD to overwrite my hard drive with zeros, I wondered about the limits of reading from `/dev/zero` in a program. Specifically, what happens if we attempt to 'max out' the read position?

Is it defined behavior when we use `fseeko()` to set the file pointer to the maximum possible offset on `/dev/zero` and then continue reading bytes? Also, is the behavior OS and compiler specific?

I already ran a little test on OnlineGDB and I found that while `fseeko()` won't return an error when using the maximum of a long int (64-bit), `ftell()` will return 4095 as the highest file offset that I can reach using `fseeko()`. It simply wraps around to zero without error. But when we read a nonzero amount of Bytes from start_offset=4095, `ftell()` returns higher numbers. Is this normal behavior on such special files?

Here's the code to try it out for yourself (I had ChatGPT make me a scaffold and I tweaked it for the question here):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

// Defines the highest number that off_t can be on your platform, usually 9223372036854775807 on 64-bit systems
// Definition taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/72019392/2721597
#define OFF_MAX ((((off_t)1 << (sizeof(off_t)*8 - 2)) - 1) * 2 + 1)

int main()
{
    FILE* fp;
    const int num_bytes = 1; // Number of bytes to read, try also 0
    char buffer[num_bytes];

    fp = fopen("/dev/zero", "rb");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening /dev/zero");
        return 1;
    }

    off_t start_offset = OFF_MAX; // Try also 4095, 4096
    if (fseeko(fp, start_offset, SEEK_SET) != 0) {
        perror("Error on fseeko()");
        fclose(fp);
        return 1;
    }

    size_t bytes_read = fread(buffer, 1, num_bytes, fp);
    if (bytes_read < num_bytes) {
        if (feof(fp)) {
            printf("End of file reached.\n");
        }
        if (ferror(fp)) {
            perror("Error reading from /dev/zero");
        }
        fclose(fp);
        return 1;
    }


    printf("start_offset = %ld\n", start_offset);
    printf("num_bytes (bytes_read): %d (%ld)\n", num_bytes, bytes_read);
    printf("ftell: %ld\n", ftell(fp));

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While a particular `/dev/zero` impl _may_ keep a current position, to provide _some_ sanity for seeking, it's really irrelevant because it's really more of a sequential byte stream that always returns zeros regardless of the file position (and has _no_ EOF or limit). The 4096 is a page size. So, it may present that way. But, it ignores the file position when returning bytes. Only the read length matters. And, I'd use the lower level functions (e.g. `open`, `lseek`, `read`) rather than the stdio versions as they may be obscuring things. 4096 is the default stdio stream buffer length, so ...

Comment: ***U***ndefined ***B***ehaviour is C language thing and C language does not know anything about `/dev/zero` then your question cannot be answered. As Linux does nor specify many things precisely it is 100% how it is implemented in particular distribution and kernel. This question has no answer.

Comment: `/dev/zero` and `/dev/null` won't return an error on `lseek` regardless of what position you specify. For _both_ devices, `lseek` will always return 0. And, `read` on `/dev/null` will always return 0 (immediate EOF). `/dev/zero` will fill the buffer and always fill the buffer with `count` bytes. Of course, `read` will return errors for bad buffer addresses, etc. That's because the `read` top layer will check buffer addresses/size limits _before_ calling the `/dev/null` or `/dev/zero` device specific `.read` function.

Comment: @0___________: Re “***U***ndefined ***B***ehaviour is C language thing…”: No, it is not; what specifications or definitions there are for behaviors is an engineering thing generally. The C standard uses “undefined behavior” with a particular meaning inside the standard, but this question does not use that term at all.

Comment: @CraigEstey: Re “`/dev/zero` and `/dev/null` won't return an error on `lseek`…”: The question shows code using `/dev/zero` through standard C library streams, and so it is conceivable a stream implementation may interact poorly with the “infinite stream” of `/dev/zero` or `/dev/null`. So it is a reasonable question to ask whether implementations of the C library used on Linux will encounter some problem when the stream functions reach their maximum offset but the associated device still provides or accepts data.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I think I covered that with: _And, I'd use the lower level functions (e.g. open, lseek, read) rather than the stdio versions as they may be obscuring things. 4096 is the default stdio stream buffer length_ And, I specifically mentioned the `lseek` results to show that `fseeko/ftello` weren't adhering to the underlying layer.

Comment: @Stefan Rickli, Why `"%ld"`with `off_t`?