# Is using 0xFFFFFFFF a reliable way to set all bits in a 32-bit type?

Tags: c++, types, binary, portability, bit-fields

There's this code that compiles with Windows SDK:

```
UINT cFiles = DragQueryFileW(hDrop, 0xFFFFFFFF, NULL, 0);
```

where `DragQueryFileW()` has this signature:

```
UINT DragQueryFileW(HDROP, UINT, LPWSTR, UINT );
```

and `UINT` is defined somewhere in SDK headers like this:

```
typedef unsigned int UINT;
```

for the platform where `int` is surely 32-bits. As usual, types like `UINT` are meant to have fixed width independent on the system bitness, so if the same code has to be recompiled on some other platform, where `DragQueryFileW()` is reimplemented somehow there will also be a corresponding `typedef` that will make `UINT` map onto a suitable 32-bit unsigned type.

Now there's a static analysis tool that looks at `0xFFFFFFFF` constant and complains that it is an unportable magic number and [one should use `-1` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/809227/57428). While of course `-1` is good and portable I can't see how using the `0xFFFFFFFF` constant could be a problem here since even when porting the type will still be 32-bit and the constant will be fine.

Is using `0xFFFFFFFF` instead of `-1` to set all bits safe and portable in this scenario?

Comment: May be static analyzer complains, because it may not worry about 32-bit or 64-bit.

Comment: Sounds like a false positive in the static analysis tool. It may not be able to see that you're always using that constant in a 32-bit context.

Comment: @Jeremy Friesner: APIs are full of legacy names that have a fixed meaning. Take Microsofts `DWORD` as example, which means double word. AFAIK it stems from times where they were coding almost exclusively in 16-bit mode where a word is 16-bits, so a double-word is 32-bit. It still means 32-bits, although in 32-bit mode it's a word and in 64-bits is a half-word.

Comment: @ybungalobill: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809227/is-it-safe-to-use-1-to-set-all-bits-to-true/809341#809341) to the question sharptooth has linked, it explains why using negation is not a good idea (although it seems like a natural solution).

Answer (score 12):

The portable way to fill all bits (regardless of type size) is really:

```
type variable = (type)-1;
```

as in:

```
UINT foo = (UINT)-1;
```

or more portable using C99 type names:

```
uint32_t foo = (uint32_t)-1;
```

The C standard guarantees that assigning -1 sets all bits.

Now, if you can guarantee that your variable is *unsigned* 32 bits then using `0xFFFFFFFF` is alright as well, of course. But I'd still go for the `-1` variant.

Comment: No, this works because the Standard makes it so. Even on a platform that doesn't use two's complement the implementation has to guarantee it works.

Comment: @Luc Danton: You're right. Read that in the meantime as well and have now corrected it.

Answer (score 4):

you could use:

```
type var =  0;
var = ~var;
```

Comment: @FredOverflow, would that do? What if type is wider than int?

Comment: type var = ~type(0)  ?

Answer (score 3):

One potential problem I see with 0xFFFFFFFF is that you can easily miss one F and initialize in a complete dummy value.

I believe that it is better to define a constant:

```
#define  ALL_ONES_32BIT ((UINT) -1)
```

and use that everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

0xffffffff is for sure a reliable way to set all bits to one in 32 bits. but I wouldn't depend on a UINT always being 32 bits.

to make it less "magic" you could also write it: (1 << 32) - 1

Comment: I'm not sure whether the shifting is a good idea. Using -1 works everywhere, as in theory, it is a endless stream of 1s in 2's complement.