# What's the difference between (size_t)-1 and ~0?

Tags: c, unsigned, ones-complement

I've seen both `(size_t)-1` and `~0` used to represent large numbers, or numbers with all their bits flipped.

Is there any difference between the two? If so, what is it?

I found this question: [What is the difference between -1 and ~0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734275/what-is-the-difference-between-1-and-0), however it did not answer my question because I'm dealing with unsigned integers (such as `size_t`), as opposed to signed integers (such as `int`).

Comment: Note that `~0` is a signed quantity — you'd need `~0U` to make it unsigned.

Comment: Should I edit that?

Comment: Since you've got some answers which addresses `~0` rather than `~0U`, best to leave it unchanged, I think, but note for the future that it is a good idea to be careful.  You can change a question up until making the change would invalidate answers.

Comment: related: [Is static_cast<T>(-1) the right way to generate all-one-bits data without numeric_limits?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36675858/995714), [What is the purpose of "int mask = ~0;"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46376693/995714)

Comment: Differences: First is C++. Second is not unsigned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What's the difference between (size_t)-1 and ~0?

Type and value differ.

`(size_t)-1` is the same value as `SIZE_MAX` and has a type of `size_t`.

`~0` is often -1 and has the type of `int`.

---

Assigning both of those to a `size_t`  will result in `SIZE_MAX`.

```
size_t a = (size_t)-1; 
size_t b = ~0;
```

In the 2nd case, `-1` is assigned to a `b` and undergoes a conversion first, wrapping around the -1 to the maximum `size_t` value.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191818/discussion-on-answer-by-chux-whats-the-difference-between-size-t-1-and-0).

Answer (score 4):

`(size_t)-1` is of type `size_t`. It typically has a value of 2<sup>32</sup>-1 or 2<sup>64</sup>-1 (`4294967295` or `18446744073709551615`).

`~0` is of type `int`, and has the value `-1` on a 2's-complement system (i.e., just about everywhere).

Both are likely to have the same bit pattern -- *if* `int` and `size_t` are the same size, which they very commonly are not.

If you want the maximum value of type `size_t`, you can use the `SIZE_MAX` macro, defined in `<stdint.h>`. If you're using an older implementation (pre-C99) that doesn't provide `SIZE_MAX`, `(size_t)-1` will work. I'm not sure why you'd want to write `~0` rather than `-1` -- unless perhaps you're considering non-two's-complement systems.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I'll remember to define `SIZE_MAX` in my `stdint.h` implementation.

Comment: Re; `~0` versus `-1` - some compilers warn on implicit wrapping in constant expressions.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the previous answers assume a 2's complement machine (very likely to be the case these days, but not guaranteed).

If you had a sign-magnitude machine then `-1` would have a sign bit and least significant bit set with all others clear, if you had a 1's complement machine then `-1` would have all bits but the LSB set.

In all of these cases (including the common 2's complement machine), `~0` has all bits set.

Comment: Note that in the question I'm asking about *unsigned* integers, so there's no such thing as a "sign bit".

Comment: @JL2210 - note that the intermediate values of both `~0` and `-1` are signed, not unsigned.

Comment: Ah. I understand now. I'll upvote as soon as this is edited.

Comment: Concerning non-2s-complement: The most recent non-2's complement machine I have heard of was from somewhere in 2000-2008 and I have not used one since pre-1990. Do you know of any in use in the last 10 years?