# Is -1u valid c++?

Tags: c++, platform-independent

Is for example

```
size_t x = -1u;

if (x == -1u)
    ...
```

valid?

If this is valid it would prevent a warning.
of course on a 32 bit system x should be 0xffffffff and on a 64 bit
system it should be 0xffffffffffffffff.

-Jochen

Comment: Literals are always non-negative. This is parsed as `-(1u)`.

Comment: @KerrekSB does that make a difference here?

Comment: Well, it makes the result signed, so it kind of defeats the purpose of the U.

Comment: `-1u` probably *won't* be `2^64 - 1` on a 64 bit system. `-1UL` *might* be - but not on Windows. `-1ULL` almost certainly will be.

Comment: "If this is valid it would prevent a warning." It would help to get to the bottom of your question if you said what other form you tried to use and what the warning was. For instance, if your compiler warns on `size_t x = -1;`, which is defined although it may indicate a programmer mistake, I do not see why it wouldn't warn on `size_t x = -1u;` which is defined although it may indicate a programmer mistake.

Comment: If your goal is to get `0xFFFFFFFF` on a 32-bit system and `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` on a 64-bit system, wouldn't it be clearer to write `size_t x = ~0U`?

Comment: ~0U is all bits on, -1U is highest number possible.

Comment: @ruakh ... although that does not solve the issue where `size_t` is wider than `unsigned int`, which may be what the OP had in mind. The expression `~0U` evaluates to the same value as `UINT_MAX`.

Comment: @Complicatedseebio: Good point; I suppose it would have to be `~((size_t)0U)`. Or just `SIZE_MAX`, assuming C99.

Comment: Are you merely trying to set all bits, or get the largest number a platform specific `size_t` will hold?  Is there a reason you're not using the built-in compiler constants (ie, you need portable code)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`1u` has the type `unsigned int`.  This is then negated using the unary `-` operator.  The behavior is as follows:

> The negative of an unsigned quantity is computed by subtracting its value from 2<sup>n</sup>, where n is the number of bits in the promoted operand (C++11 5.3.1/8).

`-1u` is thus guaranteed to give you the largest value representable by `unsigned int`.

To get the largest value representable by an arbitrary unsigned type, you can cast `-1` to that type.  For example, for `std::size_t`, consider
 `static_cast<std::size_t>(-1)`.

Answer (score 5):

I've always used ~0U for the purpose of "unsigned, all bits on".

Comment: SIZE_MAX is probably better in that case, or ~0ULL as a fallback.

Comment: However take care not to write `~0`. The `U` in here is very important. For further discussion, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809227/is-it-safe-to-use-1-to-set-all-bits-to-true

Comment: What, because we're worried about one's-complement hardware coming back? I think that ship has sailed :) I mean, sure, the U is more correct, but I expect you'd see a LOT more problems than that if you tried to port a typical app to a one's-complement architecture.

Comment: @StilesCrisis: One's complement is not coming back but systems that assert on overflow are still with us.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler implementation dependant behavior is annoying. You should be able to do this, though:

```
size_t x = 0;
x--;

if ((x+1) == 0)
```

Comment: @Pubby:  What in this answer do you think exhibits undefined behavior?

Comment: Pubby where do you see UB?  Unsigned types (and size_t is an unsigned types) have well defined behavior on overflow, they wrap around. (Signed overflow is UB).

Comment: @AProgrammer Is that so? I'll gladly remove the downvote if point me to a reference.

Comment: @Pubby, "Unsigned integers, declared unsigned, shall obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2<sup>n</sup> where n is the number of bits in the value representation of that particular size of integer." 3.9.1/4 in C++-03

Answer (score 0):

While this is *technically* valid code, you are depending on implementation dependent behavior: overflow handling of converting a negative number to unsigned. However, if you need to meaningful compare a size_t with -1 because the API calls you are using require it, the system is already screwed up but your code is likely to work because they would have had to do the same thing on the other side of the API.

Comment: I am not a C++ expert but I doubt converting from signed integer type to unsigned integer type is implementation-defined in C++, because it's defined in C99.

Comment: It's well defined. I think it's something like `x % 2^32` for 32 bits.

Comment: No negative number is converted to unsigned.  `1u` is a positive number of type `unsigned int`, and that positive number is negated using the unary `-` operator.

Comment: size_t is almost always unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely what you want:

```
size_t x = -1ull;

if (x == -((size_t)-1ull))
    ...
```

`x` will be set to the largest integer possible, which may not be all bits set. Use ~0 for that.

Comment: Many years from now when `size_t` is wider than `unsigned long long`, `size_t x = -1ull;` (perhaps `size_t` as a typedef to a wide `uintmax_t`) will fail to be initialed `x` with the max value.  `size_t x = SIZE_MAX;` will still work.