# Purpose of casting -1 to uint32?

Tags: c#, c++, casting

This is probably a really silly question to experienced C++ developers, but what is the purpose of casting a -1 to uint32? I am translating a program from C++ to C# and there are many occasions when I see something like this:

```
static const uint32 AllTypes = static_cast<uint32>(-1);
```

What exactly does this do? How can the same be accomplished in C#?

Comment: I agree with Magnus, make `static_cast` vs. `dynamic_cast` a separate question.

Comment: Both questions are duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809227/is-it-safe-to-use-1-to-set-all-bits-to-true

Comment: you may find `std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max()` more self-documenting.

Comment: Thanks all for such quick replies. I will keep all that in mind next time--the static versus dynamic question is not too important to me, but rather just a curiousity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On systems using two's complement, casting `-1` to unsigned gives the highest value an unsigned number can represent.

In C# you can use `unchecked((UInt32)-1)` or better: `UInt32.MaxValue`. This is well defined behavior, and works on all CPU architectures.

According to [the thread rve linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809227/is-it-safe-to-use-1-to-set-all-bits-to-true), casting `-1` to unsigned results in all bits being set on all architectures in C++.

Comment: It sets all bits to 1 (= highest number) and it works on all machines, not only 2s complement. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809227/is-it-safe-to-use-1-to-set-all-bits-to-true

Comment: Ah, thank you for the quick reply. That answers my question perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

> How can the same be accomplished in C#

```
uint AllTypes = uint.MaxValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's used to have all bits to 1. Useful when we use tagged data. Probably each elementary type it's given a bit, and 'complex' types (arrays, for instance) get their own.