# boost thread code ~uintmax_t(0)

Tags: c++, boost

```
bool is_sentinel() const
{
    return milliseconds==~uintmax_t(0);
}
```

I have found this line of code in thread_data.hpp, I am wondering why is it `~uintmax_t(0)` instead of `-1` ?

**EDIT:**

if reason is to avoid compiler warnings, why don't use  :

`std::numeric_limits(decltype(milliseconds)>::max()`

?

Comment: [Related, but not an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809227/is-it-safe-to-use-1-to-set-all-bits-to-true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason for using uintmax_t in the first place is that we don't know what the largest type is. Is it `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long`?

My guess is that using `~uintmax_t(0)` to produce a large unsigned value simply produces the least number of warnings on the largest number of compilers.

It is common for compilers to warn if you mix signed and unsigned values, or that using a minus on an unsigned value (`-1ull`) surprisingly(?) gives an unsigned result.

Comment: Why not using std::numeric_limits(decltype(milliseconds)>::max() instead of ~uintmax_t(0) ?

Comment: @guillaume - Probably because that is a function and not a compile time constant (improved to `constexpr` in C++11).

Answer (score 1):

`~uintmax_t(0)` is the simplest way to produce an all-ones value of type `uintmax_t` that does not produce compiler warnings.

Comment: I'm surprised (and mildly disappointed) that there are compilers that warn about an explicit `uintmax_t(-1)`.

Comment: @Charles what compilers are those? MSVC?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I don't know of any current ones myself.

Answer (score 0):

Since `milliseconds` is unsigned, comparing it to `-1` wouldn't make any sense.