# proper form with size_t (passing -1 as a default value to get max size)

Tags: c++, c, unsigned

I'm attempting to parse a text file backwards. I have the parsing done, now I'm trying to give my function a limit so that it doesn't read my entire 5Mb-2Gb log file. I'm passing this limit as a size_t and I was trying to think of a way to default the limit to read everything in the file.

since passing -1 to an unsigned type will set the highest bit, I'm assuming this will mean I get the max size of size_t. I was wondering, is this bad form? Also, is there a better way to accomplish my goal.

Comment: Why not have 0 as your no limit special case value?

Comment: If you want the maximum value of something, the general, more obvious C++ way of doing it would be `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()`.

Comment: size_t is for memory arrays, not files. Take a look at fpos_t, fgetpos, and fsetpos.

Comment: @PeteFordham I don't know why I didn't think of 0.

Comment: @JimBalter I used a memory map instead of a stream (probably for the terrible reason of learning about memory maps).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809227/is-it-safe-to-use-1-to-set-all-bits-to-true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In regards to the question on whether it is "okay" to use `-1` to get the max size of a unsigned integral type, I will refer you to [this question/answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809227/is-it-safe-to-use-1-to-set-all-bits-to-true).

Given that answer, an additional option you have available that follow a better C++ methodology would be to use `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()`.

Finally, in C you could use one of the various `_MAX` definitions in `limits.h` that describe the maximum integral value for the data-type you're reading.  For example, with a `size_t` type, you would use `SIZE_MAX`, etc.

Comment: `-1` will always give the largest value for any unsigned type. The arithmetic for unsigned types is made like this. Also, there is a macro for `size_t`: `SIZE_MAX`

Comment: My understanding is that for one's compliment, the negative of 0x0001 would only be 0xFFFE, which is not the largest unsigned value.

Comment: @jason - a negative value cannot be represented by any unsigned type, so the conversion requirement will kick in.  That requirement kicks in based on the value, not based on the bits representing the value.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Okay, I see what's going on from the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605/signed-to-unsigned-conversion-in-c-is-it-always-safe ... Thanks for not punishing me too hard :-)

Comment: I wouldn't call the referenced question "excellent".  The long list of answers, many of which are contradictory, suggests that it's a controversial practice.  Besides, that question was about setting all bits in a bitfield, which is different in _intent_ than this question, making it not a great reference.

Answer (score 5):

In order to get the maximum possible value a `size_t` can hold, use [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits). This would be the most portable way to do it:

```
#include <limits>

size_t max_value = std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max();
```

Comment: +1.  This has the added bonus that it's obvious to everyone, as opposed to the `-1` trick.  Although `-1` will do what you want, it requires casting or disabling useful compiler warnings, and will not be obvious to many programmers.