# Setting all bits in int64_t

Tags: c++, int64

From following code I expect to set all bits in x to 1, but somehow only first 32 bits are set:

```
int64_t x = 0xFFFFFFFF;
x<<32;
x|=0xFFFFFFFF;
```

Note: printing x after each line results in 4294967295 (32 lower bits set to 1).
Also, tried using `numeric_limits<int64_t>::min()` with no success.
My question is how to set all bits in x?
Using RHEL5.5.

Thx

Comment: How are you printing it?

Comment: If all else fails, and I really mean all because it's not pretty, `memset(&x, 0xFF, 8)`.

Comment: building a streamstring and printing it, no precision. Assume prints are ok, I "see" it wrong in calculations later in code

Comment: @peachykeen : trying to avoid memset, but still I will try, thanks

Comment: If you care about the bits, why are you using `int64_t` rather than `uint64_t`? (And `x<<32` doesn't work because you're discarding the result; you wanted `x <<= 32`.) But shifting a `1` into the sign bit position has undefined behavior -- thus my question about `uint64_t`.

Comment: Not a dupe, but see this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809227/is-it-safe-to-use-1-to-set-all-bits-to-true

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`x<<32` calculates the result of shifting `x` left by 32 bits *and does nothing with the value*.  You want to use `x <<= 32` instead.

Comment: jwodder has what you want OP. You forgot to assign your result:

x = x << 32;

as opposed to what you had.

Comment: As an aside, it's technically undefined behavior because of overflow

Answer (score 10):

Why not `int64_t x = -1`?  or `uint64_t x = ~0`?

Answer (score 4):

This will work:

```
int64_t x = ~0LL;   (iner
```

or

```
int64_t x = -1LL;
```

You may get away with not having the `LL`, but not guaranteed - depends on the compiler.

Comment: And also, you may get away with having the LL :) ("depends on the compiler", though 128-bit long long isn't coming for a while)