# Dynamically setting multiple bits in uint

Tags: c, bit-shift

I have an `unsigned int` that holds a series of bits, and a certain bit location.

Now I want to set all bits to 1 from that bit location 'downwards'. How can this be achieved simply without a loop?

Example:

```
unsigned int bitloc=2;
unsigned int bits=??;           //must become 0000 0111

unsigned int bitloc=4;
unsigned int bits=??;           //must become 0001 1111
```

Equivalent function that creates the result:

```
bits=0;
for (unsigned int i=0; i<=bitloc; i++)
    bits|=1<<i;
```

Comment: [Bit twiddling hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about?

```
unsigned int  Mask =   0xffffffff;
  bits = Mask >> (31 - bitloc);
```

as in your example bitloc is 2:
Mask is a binary number of ones then we shift right it 29 time effectively adding 29 zeros from the left leaving only bit zero bit one and bit two as ones.

> 0xffffffff >> 29 = 0x00000007=000...0111

Comment: That's a different approach than the other answers, and it actually works for all `bitloc` including `bitloc==31`. And the same works when you want to use `bitloc` to let `bits` become `1110 0000` by simply using `~(Mask>>(32-bitloc))`. Clever!

Comment: For 64-bit, use `~0ULL` instead of `0xFFFFFFFF` (the `~0` also works for `int` too).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, simply using `-1` would work, wouldn't it: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809227/is-it-safe-to-use-1-to-set-all-bits-to-true)?

Comment: @DoubleYou: In practice, yes, appropriately qualified. In theory, no; if the machine uses 1's complement or sign-magnitude binary numbers, `-1` won't work correctly (but `~0` will work even with those).

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
bits |= (2 << bitloc) - 1;
```

Of course, this only works if `bitloc <= 30`.

Comment: I think it should be `..(2ul << bitloc)..`

Comment: So for `bitloc==31` create an if-statement containing `bits=-1`?

Comment: @DoubleYou Yes, although `bits = ~0` might be preferred from a pedantic point of view.

Comment: @user3386109 I've taken `-1` from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809227/is-it-safe-to-use-1-to-set-all-bits-to-true) as `~0` can behave differently on different systems.

Comment: @DoubleYou interesting, in that case you shouldn't need an `if` statement at all, since the expression will evaluate to -1 on a 32-bit machine when `bitloc` is 31.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this should work,

```
bits |= ~((~0)<<(bitloc + 1))
```

Comment: If `bitloc == 31` and `sizeof(unsigned int) == 4`, you have undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

### Here is the more generic solution for your question

Lets say you want to set "N" bits from a specific position "P" from M.S.B. towards LSB in a given value "X". Then the solution will be

---

X = X | ((~(~0 << N)) << ((P + 1) - N));