# Bit- manipulation

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, jpeg

I'm implementing a JPEG-Decoder and in one step I need to determine the sign of a value from a given number of bits `(positive if 1th bit = 1)`.
When the 1th bit is `0` then I have to get the two's complement from this value and additionaly add 1 to result.

I've have the following function to do this job:

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <string.h>     /* strcat */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* strtol */

typedef int bool;
#define true 1
#define false 0

int DetermineSign(int val, int nBits)
{
    bool negative = val < (1<<(nBits-1));

    if (negative)
    {
        // (-1 << (s)), makes the last bit a 1, so we have 1000,0000 for example for 8 bits

        val = val + (-1 << (nBits)) + 1;
    }

    // Else its unsigned, just return
    return val;
}
```

Could anyone explain please what does this expression `(-1 << (nBits))` do and how it works?
I know there is a comment from author to explain it, but I also tested it with the following function and it returns another result.

```
const char *byte_to_binary(int x)
{
    static char b[9];
    b[0] = '\0';

    int z;
    for (z = 128; z > 0; z >>= 1)
    {
        strcat(b, ((x & z) == z) ? "1" : "0");
    }

    return b;
}

int main(void)
{
    char testValue = 0;

    testValue = (-1 <<(testValue));

    printf("%s\n", byte_to_binary(testValue)); // output 1111 1111 doesn't it has to be 1000 000?

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: It adds trailing zeros.

Comment: You may want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809227/is-it-safe-to-use-1-to-set-all-bits-to-true

Comment: it adds zeros in the less significative bits to a mask made all of ones (in two's complement, -1 is the pattern `1111111...111`. So `-1 << 3` is `11111...111000`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It replaces the right-most (least significant) ones with zeros:

- `-1 << 0 == 0xFFFFFFFF`
- `-1 << 1 == 0xFFFFFFFE`
- `-1 << 2 == 0xFFFFFFFC`
- `-1 << 3 == 0xFFFFFFF8`
- `-1 << 4 == 0xFFFFFFF0`
- ...

Comment: The amount of `F`s depends on the value of `sizeof int` on your platform of course...

Comment: Exactly!  My problem was, that I didn't interpret `-1` as `0xFFFFFFFF`. Thanks!

Comment: @Samashki95: You're welcome. Please keep in mind my comment above (although in most cases `-1` is indeed "made of" 8 `F`s).

Comment: @Samashki95: BTW, I tend to use `~0` instead of `-1`.

Comment: What's the reason of using -0?

Comment: @LPs: No special reason, I just like it better for bit-manipulation code. BTW, it's `~0`, not `-0`.

Answer (score 1):

What `(-1 << (nBits))`  does is that the left operands value(-1) is moved left by the number of bits specified by the right operand (nBits). In decimal representation the  expression `x<<y`  equals to multiplying x by 2 y times,for example:

x=2,y=3 ,after `x<<y` x equals to 16.