# Is it more portable to use ~0 or -1 to represent a type with all bits flipped to 1?

Tags: c++, comparison, bit-manipulation

I saw an code example today which used the following form to check against -1 for an unsigned 64-bit integer:

```
if (a == (uint64_t)~0)
```

Is there any use case where you would WANT to compare against `~0` instead of something like `std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max()` or straight up `-1`? The original intent was unclear to me as I'd not seen a comparison like this before.

To clarify, the comparison is checking for an error condition where the unsigned integer type will have all of its bits set to `1`.

**UPDATE**

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/809341/1762276, `-1` does not always represent all bits flipped to `1` but `~0` does. Is this correct?

> I recommend you to do it exactly as you have shown, since it is the
>   most straight forward one. Initialize to -1 which will work always,
>   independent of the actual sign representation, while ~ will sometimes
>   have surprising behavior because you will have to have the right
>   operand type. Only then you will get the most high value of an
>   unsigned type.

I believe this error case is handled so long as `~0` is always case to the correct type (as indicated). So this would suggest that `(uint64_t)~0` is indeed a more accurate and portal representation of an unsigned type with all bits flipped?

All of the following seem to be true (GCC x86_x64):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    uint64_t a = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;

    cout << (int)(a == -1) << endl;
    cout << (int)(a == ~0) << endl;
    cout << (int)(a == (uint64_t)-1) << endl;
    cout << (int)(a == (uint64_t)~0) << endl;
    cout << (int)(a == static_cast<uint64_t>(-1)) << endl;
    cout << (int)(a == static_cast<uint64_t>(~0)) << endl;
    cout << (int)(a == std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max()) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

Comment: It's just easier to type `~0` instead of std:...

Comment: Use `~0` when you want an `int` with all bits flipped opposite of its zero representation. That's it. Comparing to the max value of an unsigned integer type is not one of those cases, this code is bad (and probably does the wrong thing!). See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809227/is-it-safe-to-use-1-to-set-all-bits-to-true

Comment: You are correct. But I think `-1` is a clearer representation of `::max()` when comparing to an unsigned type. Is there ever any ambiguity between `-1` and `~0` or are they always equivalent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general you should be casting before applying the operator, because casting to a wider unsigned type may or may not cause sign extension depending on whether the source type is signed.

If you want a value of primitive type `T` with all bits set, the most portable approach is `~T(0)`.  It should work on any number-like classes as well.

As Mr. Bingley said, the types from `stdint.h` are guaranteed to be two's-complement, so that `-T(1)` will also give a value with all bits set.

The source you reference has the right thought but misses some of the details, for example neither of `(T)~0u` nor `(T)-1u` will be the same as `~T(0u)` and `-T(1u)`.  (To be fair, litb wasn't talking about widening in that answer you linked)

Note that if there are no variables, just an unsuffixed literal `0` or `-1`, then the source type is guaranteed to be signed and none of the above concerns apply.  But why write different code when dealing with literals, when the universally correct code is no more complex?

Comment: Ahh, perfect! The `~T(n)` syntax was exactly what I was looking for. Inverting the value *before* the cast just felt wrong. I rarely cast in the form `T()`, as it's a C-style cast, and I'd forgotten it as an option. I suppose you could still `~static_cast<uint64_t>(0)` if you wanted to be pedantic about it!

Comment: @Zhro: Exactly so.  If you prefer C-style casts over function-style cast, then certainly `~(T)0` works as well.  The important thing is the sequence of operation and conversion.

Comment: Wouldn't a function-style cast still be considered C-style? I believe it's an inherited trait.

Comment: @Zhro: The behavior (set of allowed conversions) is the same as the C-style, but the syntax isn't permitted in C.

Answer (score 1):

`std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max()` is same as `(uint64_t)~0` witch is same as `(uint64_t)-1`

look to this example of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool x = false;
    cout << x << endl;
    x = std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max() == (uint64_t)~0;
    cout << x << endl;
    x = false;
    cout << x << endl;
    x = std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max() == (uint64_t)-1;
    cout << x;
}
```

**Result:**

```
0
1
0
1
```

> so it's more simple to write `(uint64_t)~0` or `(uint64_t)-1` than `std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max()` in the code.

Comment: According to my test, the cast might not even be necessary. But I still don't know if that's true. Testing some code run only on a single architecture does not prove portability.

Answer (score 1):

The fixed-width integer types like `uint64_t` are [guaranteed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) to be represented in two's complement, so for those `-1` and `~0` are equivalent. For the normal integer types (like `int` or `long`) this is not necessarily the case, since the C++ standard does not specify their bit representations.