# I am using klib library Can i use (khash) KHASH_SET_INIT_INT64() negative values for key. Because i saw in header file its using unsigned long int

Tags: c, hashset

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "klib/khash.h"

KHASH_SET_INIT_INT64(bin_value);

int counter = 1;

int main() {
  khash_t(bin_value) *bin_value_pointer = kh_init(bin_value);

  FILE *file = fopen("read.txt", "r");
  char line[20];
  while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
    int64_t value;
    int ret;
    if (sscanf(line, "%ld", &value) == 1) {
      kh_put(bin_value, bin_value_pointer, value, &ret);
    }
  }
  fclose(file);

  FILE *file1 = fopen("check.txt", "r");
  while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file1)) {
    int64_t input;
    int ret;
    if (sscanf(line, "%ld", &input) == 1) {
      if (kh_get(bin_value, bin_value_pointer, input) != kh_end(bin_value_pointer)) {
        printf("matched counter= %d\n", counter++);
      }
    }
  }

  kh_destroy(bin_value, bin_value_pointer);
  fclose(file1);
  return 0;
}
```

> I am trying to implement hashSet using khash can i use negative value for key because i saw in header file it using unsigned long int (uint64_t).. and also if i use negative value for key it will cause any problem..
> sorry for asking these type question but i am new to C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i saw in header file it using unsigned long int

You are probably using an old version:

```
#if ULONG_MAX == ULLONG_MAX
typedef unsigned long khint64_t;
#else
typedef unsigned long long khint64_t;
#endif
```

On modern versions `khint64_t` is defined as:

```
typedef uint64_t khint64_t;
```

> if i use negative value for key it will cause any problem

Your code is safe because conversions from `signed` to `unsigned` types has well defined behaviour, but that's not true for the opposite, from the standard:

> C11 6.3.1.3
>
> 6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers
>
> When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type
> other than _Bool, if the value can be represented by the new type, it
> is unchanged.
>
> Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by
> repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that
> can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of
> the new type.
>
> Otherwise, the new type **is signed and the value cannot be
> represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined** or an
> implementation-defined signal is raised.

In consequence

```
int64_t value;
int ret;
if (sscanf(line, "%ld", &value) == 1) {
  kh_put(bin_value, bin_value_pointer, value, &ret);
}
```

and

```
int64_t input;
...
   if (kh_get(bin_value, bin_value_pointer, input) !=  != kh_end(bin_value_pointer)) {
```

are both correct (except that `int64_t` wants `"%" SCNd64` instead of `"%ld"`), what would not be correct is:

```
int64_t value = kh_key(bin_value, bin_value_pointer);
```

In this case there is an `unsigned` to `signed` conversion.

Comment: thanks now i understand!!! as long as i am using for checking if the key is present in hashset or not it would fine right ? and actually my useCase is also that i have to check the key is present or not in the hashsest that's it.. it will be good right ??

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: @ David Ranieri i passed negative value as key and  i am trying to print the negative value keys.... i can't understand how its able to print the negative key i mean its printing  (correctly) ??

 for(khiter_t it = kh_begin(bin_value_pointer); it != kh_end(bin_value_pointer); ++it) {
    if(kh_exist(bin_value_pointer, it)) {
      printf("The keys aree: %lld\n", kh_key(bin_value_pointer, it));
    }
  }

Comment: Now i understand!  is there any good library for the hashSet which can work on negative and positive value (int64_t) my requirnment is only to check the value is present in hashSet or not after inserting a large no of elements with  auto resizing  ??

can you suggest any  ! thank you

Comment: You don't need any external library, there are several ways to convert `unsigned` to `signed`, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64842306/1606345

Comment: Okay but  is there any other library for hashset implementation which both signed and unsigned with auto resizing and which low memory because I tried uthash but it takes lot of memory any recommendations?

Comment: Nops ... sorry :(