# How to initialize a variable

Tags: variables, memory, bit

I want to store in n a 32-bit integer number. How should I initialize the variable n?

With unsigned int n or with int n?

Can someone tell me the difference between these two ?

The sign of the number stored in n does not matter. It is only important to store a 32 bit number.

Answer (score 0):

I probably don't understand your question, but I will try an answer.
You talk about `int` and `unsigned int`, thus I assume you use C as programming language. The data types of C are described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types).
I assume you talk about a 32 bit architecture that stores `int` and `unsigned int` with 32 bits.
To initialize such a variable means to allocate memory for it, in this case a 32 bit word.
Now, C can be considered as a statically typed language, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/430414/1987726).
This means that the compiler checks if a value of the correct type (`int` or `unsigned int`) is to be assigned to a variable.
So the first question is how your 32 bit number is to be stored in the allocated memory of your var.
If this is done in your code (and not, e.g. by direct memory access), your 32 bit number has to have the right type (`int` or `unsigned int`).
It is however possible to change the type, e.g. from `unsigned int` to `int`, by type casting, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5129528/1987726).
The real question is, how your code interprets the 32 bit number. If it is `int` or `unsigned int`, you should initialize it as such. If something else, e.g. bit-packed values, I would use `unsigned int`.
Note that bit-packed values are different from C bit fields, as explained [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_bit_fields.htm).

Comment: @Didi Did this answer your question? If not, what is missing? If yes, I suggest to accept the answer so that it is marked as answered.