# What happens when I subtract an unsigned integer from a signed integer in C++?

Tags: c++, math

What happens if I do something like this:

```
unsigned int u;
int s;

...
s -= u;
```

What's the expected behavior of this:

1) Assuming that the unsigned integer isn't too big to fit in the signed integer?

2) Assuming that the unsigned integer would overflow the signed integer?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [signed to unsigned conversion in C - is it always safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605/signed-to-unsigned-conversion-in-c-is-it-always-safe)

Comment: Not a complete duplicate.  That question had the last assignment into an `unsigned` variable, so the arithmetic is the same but the last assignment is different.

Comment: Also worth to have a look at: [*Is unsigned integer subtraction defined behavior?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7221409/1168156) :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In general, consult 5/9 in the standard.

In your example, the *signed* value is converted to *unsigned* (by taking it mod UINT_MAX+1), then the subtraction is done modulo UINT_MAX+1 to give an unsigned result.

Storing this result back as a signed value to `s` involves a standard integral conversion - this is in 4.7/3. If the value is in the range of `signed int` then it is preserved, otherwise the value is implementation-defined. All the implementations I've ever looked at have used modulo arithmetic to push it into the range `INT_MIN` to `INT_MAX`, although as Krit says you might get a warning for doing this implicitly.

"Stunt" implementations that you'll probably never deal with might have different rules for unsigned->signed conversion. For example if the implementation has sign-magnitude representation of signed integers, then it's not possible to always convert by taking modulus, since there's no way to represent `+/- (UNIT_MAX+1)/2` as an int.

Also relevant is 5.17/7, "The behavior of an expression of the form `E1 op=  E2` is equivalent to `E1  =  E1 op E2` except that `E1` is evaluated only once". This means that in order to say that the subtraction is done in the `unsigned int` type, all we need to know is that `s - u` is done in `unsigned int`: there's no special rule for `-=` that arithmetic should be done in the type of the LHS.

Comment: Just a reminder that the "implementation defined result" could
be an "implementation defined signal".  (The C standard is much
clearer in this regard.)

In practice, you'll get the correct results on a two's
complement machine, wrong results elsewhere.

Comment: @James: I think that's a deliberate difference between C++ and C, then. The C++ wording is quite clear, "the value is implementation-defined". It doesn't say, "the behavior is implementation-defined", which would permit a signal.

Comment: This answer is correct, but it has very surprising consequences. One is: **Even if the value of `u` is easily representable as `int`, it is implementation defined whether `s-=u` has the same effect as `s-=int(u)`.** This is because while converting signed to unsigned is precisely defined (by modular arithmetic), it is implementation defined whether the conversion back to signed will then reproduce the original value. So maybe even more surprising: **Even if `u==0`, it is implementation defined whether `s-=u` leaves `s` unchanged** in case `s` was negative.

Answer (score -2):

u is recast as a signed integer and subtracted from s. Ultimately the casting doesn't make any difference. One set of bits is subtracted from the other and the result goes into s.

Comment: This answer disagrees with the accepted answer, which cites the standard.