# unary - operator: implementation defined or undefined

Tags: c, expression, standards

```
unsigned u = 1;
int i = -u;
```

Does the 2nd assignment come under 6.5.5: If an exceptional condition occurs during the evaluation of an expression (that is, if the result is not mathematically defined or **not in the range of representable values for its type**), the behavior is **undefined**.

Or does it come under 6.3.1.3: 
1 When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, ...
...
3 Otherwise, the new type is signed and **the value cannot be represented in it**; either the
result is **implementation-defined** or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

---

I wrote this question because the following (thanks to R.. for clarifications) generates **undefined** behaviour under 6.5.5 :

```
int i = INT_MIN;
i = -i;
```

The problem with the above is that the expression `-i` is of type `int` and `-INT_MIN` for 2's complement platform may be larger than INT_MAX. Under that context, it generates undefined behaviour.

On the other hand, for:

```
unsigned u = 1;
int i = -u;
```

`-u` is of type unsigned. As explained in [Is unsigned integer subtraction defined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7221409/1016492) although the range of unsigned is nominally from 0 to `UINT_MAX`, there is really no such thing as an out of range unsigned value. So 6.5.5 does not apply for `-u`. But we still have the assignment expression `i=-u` in which case 6.3.1.3 applies.

Or to put it another way, if I can reword 6.5.5, it would be:
If an exceptional condition occurs during the evaluation of an expression (that is, if the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type), **if the expression type is not one of the standard or extended unsigned type**, the behavior is undefined. **If the expression type is one of the standard or extended unsigned type, and the result is less than 0 or greater than the maximum representable value, the result shall adjusted as per 6.3.1.3/2.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It comes under 6.3.1.3. There's nothing exceptional about the expression `-u`. It's equal to `UINT_MAX`. Assigning the result into a signed type in which the value `UINT_MAX` cannot be represented then results in an implementation-defined conversion or signal.

Comment: but 6.3.1.3 only applies if there is a conversion to another integer type. I take this to mean that the type before and after conversion must differ. So in the evaluation of `-u`, only 6.5.5 applies?

Comment: The conversion takes place as part of the assignment. 6.5.5 does not apply at all because `-u` is in the range of representable values for its type (`unsigned int`).