# Adding signed and unsigned int

Tags: c, implicit-conversion, unsigned-integer

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int a = 6;
    int b = -20;

    a + b > 6 ? puts("> 6") : puts("<= 6");
}
```

It is clear to me how the *ternary operator* work in this code.
I am not able to understand the addition of the `signed` and `unsigned` integer here.

When running this code, the output is `> 6`; why?

Comment: learn about ternary operator : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#C

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/9205

Comment: @georgesl I think the whole "challenge" is about knowing of what type is the addition `a + b` between `unsigned int a` and `int b`. (Which frankly, I couldn't care less about, because my coding standards forbid performing arithmetic operations without previously converting everything to an explicit same type.)

Comment: @DanielDaranas: Quite possibly.  But the OP would do well to make this clear in the question ;)

Comment: It's hard to give a concise answer to the question without knowing exactly what part of the program you don't understand.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597405/what-happens-to-a-declared-uninitialized-variable-in-c-does-it-have-a-value

Comment: I am  not confused about the ternary operator but about the addition of a signed and unsigned integer

Comment: @DanielDaranas : oh I missed that ! that's really evil ...

Comment: [MISRA C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MISRA_C) probably shouts at you in reversed Latin if you throw this kind of expression to it (arithmetic involving implicit conversions between signed and unsigned types).

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15030332/1168156

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think the OP is not confused about the ternary operator its a different problem.

From the C99 standard, section 6.3.1.8 ("Usual arithmetic conversions"):

> if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or
>   equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand
>   with signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with
>   unsigned integer type.

`unsigned int` and `int` has the same rank, so it's equivalent to:

```
(a + (unsigned int)b > 6)
```

To fix it, you need to explicitly cast in the other direction, i.e.:

```
((int)a + b > 6)
```

So this is the reason the output **will be** `>6` and **NOT** `<=6`

Answer (score 9):

The other two answer accurately describe Ternary operator, but I think this is more relevant to the question

The output is `>6` because `(a + b)` **casts `b` to unsigned int as well**.

EDIT:

See Acme's suggestion for fixing this problem. Essentially **casting `a` as an `int`** will fix this

Answer (score 5):

the simple form of you code is as follow:

```
if(a + (unsigned int)b > 6)
{
    puts(">6")
}
else
{
    puts("<=6");
}
```

Output will be :

```
>6 as (a + (unsigned int)b > 6)
```

Answer (score 5):

Because `4294967282>6` is true you will get `>6` as output. `4294967282` is coming from assigning `-14` to a `unsigned int`. `(a+b)` will be converted as `2^32 - 14`.
`