# What should be memory filled with if my malbolge program contains only 1 instruction?

Tags: virtual-machine, esoteric-languages, malbolge

According to the original specification ['98, Ben Olmstead](http://www.lscheffer.com/malbolge_spec.html) Malbolge VM fill empty memory cells using crazy op on two previous cells. "Cells which are not initialized are set by performing op on the previous two cells repetitively." I.e.

```
[m] = crz [m-2], [m-1]
```

For the sake of sanity what should I do if the program contains only 1 instruction?

Or should I assume the last character always to be `EOF`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the implementation and language-lawyering, there are two options -

- If we consider the definition of "two previous cells" as, literally, the two previous cells, then a single-char or empty malbolge program is **illegal in the language**, because it can not be executed according to the specs.
- If we consider the definition of `[m] = crz [m-2], [m-1]`, it gets interesting. The main implementation (alongside probably most of the rest) uses `unsigned short` (or `int`) for the memory pointer. When you try subtracting `2` from `1` (`m-2`) it results in `0xffff`, decimal `65535` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7221449/6575931) answer for details), which is just a bit over malbolge's `59049` memory limit. That glitch **runs *(almost)* perfectly on a normal machine**, using the `0xffff` cell for crazy-op computing (without even harming the out-of-environment memory!), but will **fail on a limited-memory** or virtual machine.

  - You might end up with `0xffffffff` instead of `0xffff`, depending on the way you use the pointer.

**In short**,

- If you run it by hand, **assume it fails**.
- If you run it on a virtual machine, **it fails**.
- If you run it on a simulator, it will **probably work**, but will fail the point of running itself, since `0xffff` is a random-valued memory cell, leading to random values along the environment memory. On the other hand, what can you expect from a single-byte malbolge program?