# C - check matrix[x][y] positions around

Tags: c, matrix

I've a matrix with size 7x7 that represents a game board. When a player makes a move, the program has to check the positions around the coordinates where the piece is, in order to detect another piece aside.

I use this function:

```
int check_position(COORDINATES coordinates, char board[7][7]) {
  int result = -1;

  if (board[coordinates.x][coordinates.y] != 'O' && board[coordinates.x-1][coordinates.y] != 'O' && board[coordinates.x][coordinates.y-1] != 'O' && board[coordinates.x+1][coordinates.y] != 'O' && board[coordinates.x][coordinates.y+1] != 'O' && board[coordinates.x-1][coordinates.y-1] != 'O' && board[coordinates.x+1][coordinates.y+1] != 'O' && board[coordinates.x-1][coordinates.y+1] != 'O' && board[coordinates.x+1][coordinates.y-1] != 'O') {
    result = 1;
  }

  return result;
}
```

The first parameter are the coordinates of the player's piece as a struct, with members x and y. The second parameter is the board array.

The `if` statement doesn't work to well, and I don't know which alternative can I take.

Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: You probably need more `if` statements (or rather `else if`) and in them check that you're not indexing out of range. For example, think about what would happen if e.g. `coordinates.x` is `0` or `6`. You *can* to it as a single expression, but it will be very hard to read and maintain.

Comment: Is that for C or C++. They are different languages, pick one. There might be different answers for C++.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot about your coordinates overflowing at the borders. You can either test for this, or:

Hint: Make the array two rows and columns larger than the board and fill the border with "empty" marker. The active board will the have coordinates `1...7` This way your coordinates cannot wrap (`1 - 1` and `7 + 1` are still within the array) and you do not have to care about the borders.

Note: If you just want to return a boolean value, it would be better to use `stdbool.h` and return a `bool` result. That way, the caller can directly use that function as a condition:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

...

bool check_position(COORDINATES coordinates, const char board[9][9]) {
    int x = coordinates.x - 1 
    for ( int xc = 0 ; xc < 3 ; xc++ ) {
        int y = coodinates.y - 1;
        for ( int yc = 0 ; yc < 3 ; yc++ ) {
            if ( board[x][y] != '0' )
                return true;
            y++;
        }
        x++;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note: as you only need one one non-empty field, you can terminate instantly if you found one. That is identical to the multiple conditions. Of course, that also works for your original `int` result.

Note2: I modified the type of `board` to being `const`, as it is not changed inside the function.

Answer (score -1):

You could also solve the edge overflow like this. **Edit** improved after discussion with @Olaf

```
#define BOARD 7

int check_position(COORDINATES coordinates, char board[BOARD][BOARD]) {
    int result = -1;
    int left   = coordinates.x == 0 ? 0 : coordinates.x - 1;
    int top    = coordinates.y == 0 ? 0 : coordinates.y - 1;
    int right  = coordinates.x == BOARD-1 ? coordinates.x : coordinates.x + 1;
    int bottom = coordinates.y == BOARD-1 ? coordinates.y : coordinates.y + 1;

    if (board[left]         [top] != 'O' && 
        board[coordinates.x][top] != 'O' &&
        board[right]        [top] != 'O' &&
        board[left]         [coordinates.y] != 'O' &&
        board[coordinates.x][coordinates.y] != 'O' && 
        board[right]        [coordinates.y] != 'O' &&
        board[left]         [bottom] != 'O' &&
        board[coordinates.x][bottom] != 'O' &&
        board[right]        [bottom] != 'O' && )
    {
        result = 1;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: That will not work with unsigned coordinates. We do not know their scalar types.

Comment: @Olaf it does work. When `unsigned x = 0` and `int left = x - 1` the value of `left` is `-1`.

Comment: Just take the first condition: (assume `x == 0`) => `(int)left = UINT_MAX` is UB, as the `int` cannot hold that value (same rank).

Comment: @Olaf, the value of `x` is converted to `int` before the `1` is subtracted. But it's hypothetical since you are only guessing about something OP didn't post.

Comment: @Olaf yes I now read that the `unsigned` type has precedence in the subtraction, but there can only be confusion in comparisons. `unsigned 0 - 1` => `0xFFFFFFFF` which is then assignd to `int` which is `-1`. This is well defined, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221409/is-unsigned-integer-subtraction-defined-behavior

Comment: `unsigned int` is _not_ converted to int, as both have the same rank. If that were, any arithmetics on unsigned relying on wrap would become UB, but wrapping is actually well defined. We both are speculating. That's why I prefer to play safe and do not assume it is `int` as you do. (Neither do I assume it is _not_ - heck, it could be `char` or `unsigned long long`).

Comment: @Olaf I commented just ahead of you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81127/discussion-between-olaf-and-weather-vane).