# Is there a difference between unary - and n -

Tags: c++, gcc, unsigned-integer, compiler-bug

I am fairly certain that subtracting one `uint8_t` from another should result in another unsigned number, but some of my results are confusing me.

```
  uint8_t a = 2;
  uint8_t b = 1;
  uint8_t c = -a;
  long d = b - a;
  long e = b + c;
```

When I obtain the value of `d` it produces `-1`, while `e` is as I would expect `255`.  This is a bug with the version of `gcc` I am using.....right?

For reference I am using the `arm-none-eabi-g++` compiler for my `MSP-432`.

Looking at [this](https://godbolt.org/g/3eDW6u) seems to indicate that `gcc` just seems to make the same mistake here.

Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221409/is-unsigned-integer-subtraction-defined-behavior) SO question it seems that godbolt and the arm gcc is wrong.

What is going on here?

Comment: used conversion specifier, please?

Comment: In C you cannot operate on types smaller than `int`. Search for implicit conversions.

Comment: Integer promotions as part of arithmetic conversions. The upshot is that you cannot use the sized type aliases for the purpose of modular arithmetic! The type aliases do not encode conversion rank.

Comment: @KerrekSB That explains a lot.......

Comment: What you are experiencing is called integer promotion.

Comment: Always enable recommended warnings. One of them is `-Wconversion`.

Comment: If you change from `uint8_t` to `unsigned int`, you'll get the behavior you expect.

Comment: @Barmar: That would be implementation defined.

Comment: @DarthRubik: "I am fairly certain that subtracting one `uint8_t` from another should result in another unsigned number". Nope. It evaluates to a `signed int` result.

Comment: Gosh, so many compilers, all wrong the same way with such a simple piece of code. Perhaps we should educate those compiler writers better!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This is a bug with the version of gcc I am using.....right?

No, it's not. Something that simple being buggy in a big compiler like gcc is highly unlikely.

What happens is due to the "usual arithmetic conversions", specifically "integer promotion":

The unary `-` promotes `a` to `int`, then the `(int)-2` gets converted back to `uint8_t` in the assignment, yielding `c == 254` (which is the representative of the equivalence class of -2 in Z mod 2^8 that lies in [0, 2^8)).

Likewise, the binary `+` and `-` in the lines below that promote to `int`, so we end up with

```
d == (int)b - (int)a == (int)1 - (int)2 == -1
```

and

```
e == (int)b + (int)c == (int)1 + (int)254 == 255
```

So everything is working fine as mandated by the standard.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that binary operators undergo integral promotion before doing the work, and since `int` can hold all possible values from `uint8_t`, that choice is used (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion). Thus the subtraction is done as a signed operation.

When calculating `e` the act of storing a value in `c` already resulted in your expected modulo math, storing 254 which is then added to `b`'s value of 1.