# is an argument of type long OK for %x printf specifier?

Tags: c++, printf, variadic-functions

I found this on [Win32 docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winscard/nf-winscard-scardisvalidcontext#examples):

> ```
> // Check the smart card context handle.
> // hContext was set previously by SCardEstablishContext.
>
> LONG    lReturn;
> lReturn = SCardIsValidContext(hContext);
> if ( SCARD_S_SUCCESS != lReturn )
> {
>    // Function failed; check return value.
>    if ( ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE == lReturn )
>        printf("Handle is invalid\n");
>    else
>    {
>        // Some unexpected error occurred; report and bail out.
>        printf("Failed SCardIsValidContext - %x\n", lReturn);
>        exit(1);  // Or other appropriate error action.
>    }
> }
> else
> {
>    // Handle is valid; proceed as needed.
>    // ...
> }
> ```

The `printf("Failed SCardIsValidContext - %x\n", lReturn);` line is passing an argument of type `LONG` (typedef for `long`) to `printf` where `printf` expects `unsigned int` according to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf). Is this well defined behavior? If so, is it the same as an explicit `static_cast` to `unsigned int`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is an argument of type long OK for %x printf specifier?

No, it is not OK in C++. `%x` is for unsigned int, not for long.

> Is this well defined behavior?

No, this is undefined behaviour. Quote from C standard draft (which is where the format specifiers are defined):

> x,X The **unsigned int argument** is converted to ... unsigned hexadecimal notation ...
>
> If  any argument  is not  the  correct  type  for  the  corresponding  conversion  specification,  the  behavior  is undefined.

---

It may be "OK" in windows if the system documents so, but relying on such guarantee will not be portable to other systems. I suspect that the example is not intended as documentation of validity of such misuse of format specifier, but that it is accidental.

Comment: This is the correct answer by the letter of the standard (+1), though that's essentially saying that `int n; unsigned k = *(unsigned *)&n;` is UB, which I find a bit surprising.

Comment: @dxiv It says nothing about reinterpreting signed integer as its unsigned counterpart, which is well defined.

Comment: Right, but `printf` presumably does something like `unsigned k = va_arg(args, unsigned)` when it hits `%x`, and all implementations that I know of translate that to `k = *(unsigned *)(void *)args`. So in the end, the UB is reading an `unsigned` from the address where an `int` was written.

Answer (score 1):

`printf("%x", (LONG)101);` is valid and well defined *in Windows* where `LONG` is [defined](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types) to be '*a 32-bit signed integer*", same as `int` and same size as `unsigned int`.

The portable equivalent using C++ types would be `printf("%lx", (unsigned long)101l);`

Comment: Is `%x` valid, or `%lx` or both?

Comment: @Ayxan Both, given how Windows defines the type, which is not expected to change anytime soon since it would break the entire Win32 API.

Comment: Interesting. I was asking this because cppreference says *"If any argument after [default conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments#Default_conversions) is not the type expected by the corresponding conversion specifier, or if there are fewer arguments than required by format, the behavior is undefined."* While the size matches, the type still doesn't. So, I am not sure. Perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: @Ayxan Using `"%x"` with a `signed int` in `printf` is indeed UB, as elaborated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32352833) (for C, which the Win32 API is using). I am not aware of any Windows compilers which do *not* do the expected with such construct, but technically it's still a language violation. I guess something like `printf("%x", lReturn + 0ul);` would work around that.