# Why do we use suffix in c variables?

Tags: c

**What is the difference between these two declarations?**

```
    long int n=12;
    long int n=12l;
    int n=12l;
```

and
**How does an unsigned variable store signed values?**

```
    unsigned int number=-13;
```

Comment: 12 is an int constant, 12l is a long int constant.  The conversion from the right-hand value to the left-hand type is specified by the standard.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is the reason for explicitly declaring L or UL for long values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134956/what-is-the-reason-for-explicitly-declaring-l-or-ul-for-long-values)

Answer (score 1):

**What is the difference between these declarations?**

```
long int n=12;
```

An `int` value `12` is assigned to the `long` variable `n`.

```
long int n=12l;
```

A `long` value `12l` is assigned to the `long` variable `n`.

```
int n=12l;
```

A `long` value `12l` is assigned to the `int` variable `n`.

[**How can an unsigned variable allow signed values?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32344810/unsigned-values-in-c)

```
unsigned int number=-13;
```

Why do you think so?
This question is a duplicate.

Comment: is it normal to assign a long value to the int variable?and the variable type still int?

Comment: unsigned int number=-13;   when i run this code ,there are no errors .so it accept it.im really confused

Comment: @chihebnouri Refer to the link in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do we use suffix in c variables?

These suffixes are not in the variables. They are in constants. We use suffixes, sometimes, to control the types of the constants.

> `long int n = 12;`

In this, `12` is a constant of type `int`. Small decimal numerals with no suffix are `int` by default. A numeral for an integer too big to represent in `int` will be `long int` or `long long int`, or possibly a compiler-specific wider type.

Since `n` is declared to be `long int`, the `int` 12 will be converted to a `long int` for the initialization. This conversion will not change the value.

> `long int n = 12l;`

Here, `12l` is a constant of type `long int`. Since it is used to initialize a `long int`, no conversion is necessary.

> `int n = 12l;`

Again, `12l` is a `long int`. However, since it is used to initialize an `int`, it will be converted to `int`. Since `int` can represent the value 12, this conversion will not change the value. If the constant were too large to represent in an `int`, then the conversion would change the value, in some implementation-defined way.

As to why we use suffixes sometimes, consider `1 << 31`. The `1` is an `int`, and we shift it left 31 bits. In C implementations common today, an `int` has 32 bits, and it can represent numbers from −2<sup>31</sup> to +2<sup>31</sup>−1. However, `1 << 31` would produce 2<sup>31</sup>, which overflows this `int` range. The C standard does not define the behavior when that overflow occurs.

To avoid this, we might write `1u << 31`. Then `1u` is an `unsigned int`, which can represent numbers from 0 to +2<sup>32</sup>−1. Then 2<sup>31</sup> fits in this, and there is no overflow. Alternately, if we know `long int` is 64 bits in the C implementation we are using, we might use `1l << 31`, depending on our needs. `1 << 31` would overflow, but `1l << 31` would not.

The `u` suffix makes a decimal constant `unsigned int`, `unsigned long int`, or `unsigned long long int`, as necessary to holds its value (or possibly a wider type supported by the compiler).

The `l` suffix makes a decimal constant at least `long int` (skipping `int`), but the constant will still be `long long int` if its value is too large for `long int`.

If an integer constant is written using octal (starts with `0`) or hexadecimal (starts with `0x`), then both signed and unsigned types are considered until one is found that can represent its value: `int`, `unsigned int`, `long int`, `unsigned long int`, `long long int`, `unsigned long long int`, and then compiler-specific types.

> `unsigned int number = -13;`

Here `13` is an `int` constant, and the `-` is the negation operator, so the result is an `int` with value −13. (Note there are no negative integer constants in C; you make a negative integer by negating an integer constant.)

Since it is used to initialize an `unsigned int`, it is converted to `unsigned int`. When C converts an integer to an unsigned integer type of width *M* (meaning the type uses *M* bits to represent values), it is “wrapped” modulo 2<sup>*M*</sup>. This means 2<sup>*M*</sup> is added to or subtracted from the value until the result is representable in the destination type. For −13 and a 32-bit `unsigned int`, wrapping −13 modulo 2<sup>32</sup> produces −13 + 4,294,967,296 = 4,294,967,283.

Wrapping modulo 2<sup>*M*</sup> produces the same result as if you wrote the starting number in binary (using two’s complement with more than *M* bits, if the number is negative) and removed all but the last *M* bits. For example, −13 in 64-bit two’s complement is 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110011<sub>2</sub> = FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF3<sub>16</sub>. The last 32 bits are 11111111111111111111111111110011<sub>2</sub> = FFFFFFF3<sub>16</sub>. In plain binary (not two’s complement), that is 4,294,967,283.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the noise. What you had written was clear to me in principle, but I have misread a sentence in your examples. I'll delete my first comment because it is misleading.