# How does in assembly does assigning negative number to an unsigned int work?

Tags: c, assembly, unsigned, unsigned-integer, conceptual

I Learned About `2's Complement` and unsigned and signed int. So I Decided to test my knowledge , as far as i know that a negative number is stored in `2's complement` way so that addition and subtraction would not have different algorithm and circuitry would be simple.

Now If I Write

```
int main()
{
  int a = -1 ;
  unsigned int b = - 1 ;

  printf("%d %u \n %d %u" , a ,a , b, b);
}
```

Output Comes To Be `-1 4294967295  -1 4294967295` . Now , i looked at the bit pattern and various things and then i realized that `-1` in 2's complement is `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111` , so when i interpret it using %d , it gives `-1` , but when i interpret using `%u` , it treat it as a positive number and so it gives `4294967295`. I Checked the Assembly Of the code is

```
.LC0:
    .string "%d %u \n %d %u"
main:
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    sub     rsp, 16
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], -1
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], -1
    mov     esi, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
    mov     ecx, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
    mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
    mov     r8d, esi
    mov     esi, eax
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    mov     eax, 0
    call    printf
    mov     eax, 0
    leave
    ret
```

Now here `-1` is moved to the register both the times in unsigned and signed . What i want to know if reinterpretation is only that matters , then why do we have two types `unsigned` and `signed` , it is `printf` format string `%d` and `%u` that matters ?

Further what really happens when i assign negative number to a unsigned integer (I learned That The initializer converts this value from `int` to `unsigned int`. ) but in the assembly code I did not saw such a thing. So what really happens ??

And How does Machine knows when it has to do `2's complement` and when not , does it see the negative sign and performs `2's complement`?

I have read almost every question and answer you could think this question be duplicate of , but I could not find a satisfactory solution.

Comment: *"How does Machine knows when it has to do 2's complement and when not"* - I don't understand this - everything comes down to being binary in programming. Machine instructions do not care about `signed` or `unsigned` those are higher level constructs.

Comment: @UnholySheep What i mean is when i write signed int a = -1 , it is stored as 2's complement so does every negative number no matter where it is stored in this way or not?

Comment: For C language, negative number could be one of the three representations, so not necessarily  2's complement. Also printf format must match the input, or your program is ill formed. Current C standard favors 2's complement in such a way that, converting signed types to and from unsigned types does not change the bit representation on a native 2's complement computer. Machines really doesn't know about the sign-ness of a variable when it's in the register. Compiler know, so the program knows, and that's enough.

Comment: @EOF I framed this question well still people come and downvote without even telling OP Once what is wrong with their question ,

Comment: Same thing that happens in C for 2's complement: [What happens if I assign a negative value to an unsigned variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2711522) - see my edit to the top answer for why the 2's complement bit-pattern is used unchanged.

Answer (score 3):

Both signed and unsigned are pieces of memory and according to operations it matters how they behave.

It doesn't make any difference when adding or subtracting because due to 2-complement the operations are exactly the same.

It matters when we compare two numbers: -1 is lower than 0 while 4294967295 obviously isn't.

About conversion - for the same size it simply takes variable content and moves it to another - so 4294967295 becomes -1. For bigger size it's first signed extended and then content is moves.

How does machine now - according the instruction we use. Machines have either different instructions for comparing signed and unsigned or they provide different flags for it (x86 has Carry for unsigned overflow and Overflow for signed overflow).

Additionally, note that C is relaxed how the signed numbers are stored, they don't have to be 2-complements. But nowadays, all common architectures store the signed like this.

Comment: when i assign -1 to unsigned int , what happens , in assembly it shows same for signed and unsigned int.

Comment: @SurajJain this is because, in 2's complement representation, the values *are* the same. They are the same binary bit pattern. It is how they are *used* that makes them different.

Comment: @WeatherVane What i am asking is every negative number , is represented as 2's complement and also if i store a negative number in unsigned int http://stackoverflow.com/a/7152835/5473170 it is written initializer converts this value from int to unsigned int. Where does it happen ?

Comment: @WeatherVane More precisely, current C standard require the conversion of negative number to unsigned number to follow the "2's complement rule" and that means nothing needs to be done if the computer natively use "2's complement".

Comment: The bit pattern is written. It is then interpreted as a differnet type. But it is the same bit pattern. Printed as `int` that is `-1`. Printed as `unsigned` that is `4294967295`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Here it is written something different http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152759/what-happens-when-i-assign-a-negative-value-to-an-unsigned-int/7152835#7152835

Comment: @SurajJain doesn't that answer say the same as I just did? If you provide the `unsigned int` value `4294967295` as the argument for the `%d` format specifier, you will not get what you expected. But if you used the value `1`, it would work because `1` is correctly represented the same by either type, with the same value. `1` is within the range of both `int` and `unsigned int`.

Comment: @WeatherVane It says "The initializer converts this value from int to unsigned int. The rules for signed-to-unsigned conversion say that the value is reduced modulo UINT_MAX + 1, so -1 will convert to UINT_MAX (which is probably 0xffffffff or 4294967295 if unsigned int is 32 bits)." what does it mean ?

Comment: @WeatherVane Can you tell me  , when does 2's complment happen , tell in beginner manner , does it happen whenever any negative integer has to be represented ?

Comment: @WeatherVane UNIT_MAX is 4294967295 , but it is not converted. ,??

Comment: @SurajJain Yeah, that's exactly what I've said (twice), C standard (ISO9899-2011) describes the negative number to/from unsigned number in a very strict and formal way, but what that rule does is to make sure bit-pattern is preserved during the conversion if the negative number uses 2's complement.

Comment: @user3528438 But it should have been converted first ??

Comment: @SurajJain You mean from decimal numbers to bit representation? Your example uses a constant number so may be in the pre-processor, maybe compiler, maybe in the assembler, but definitely done at "compile time".

Comment: @user3528438 No , signed int to unsigned int , when does that will happen ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few differences between signed and unsigned types:

1. The behaviors of the operators `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, `/`, `%`, and `>>` are all different when dealing with signed and unsigned numbers.
2. Compilers are not required to behave predictably if any computation on a signed value exceeds the range of its type.  Even when using operators which would behave identically with signed and unsigned values in all defined cases, some compilers will behave in "interesting" fashion.  For example, a compiler given `x+1 > y` could replace it with `x>=y` if `x` is signed, but not if `x` is unsigned.

As a more interesting example, on a system where "short" is 16 bits and "int" is 32 bits, a compiler given the function:

```
unsigned mul(unsigned short x, unsigned short y) { return x*y; }
```

might assume that no situation could ever arise where the product would exceed 2147483647.  For example, if it saw the function invoked as `unsigned x = mul(y,65535);` and `y` was an `unsigned short`, it may omit code elsewhere that would only be relevant if `y` were greater than 37268.

Comment: Can we chat sir ?

Comment: @SurajJain: Sure.  Let me know where.

Answer (score 0):

Choice of signed integer representation is left to the platform.  The representation applies to both negative and non-negative values - for example, if `11012` (-5) is the two's complement of `01012` (5), then `01012` (5) is *also* the two's complement of `11012` (-5).

The platform may or may not provide separate instructions for operations on signed and unsigned integers.  For example, x86 provides different multiplication and division instructions for signed (`idiv` and `imul`) and unsigned (`div` and `mul`) integers, but uses the same addition (`add`) and subtraction (`sub`) instructions for both.

Similarly, x86 provides a single comparison (`cmp`) instruction for both signed and unsigned integers.

Arithmetic and comparison operations will set one or more status register flags (carry, overflow, zero, etc.).  These can be used differently when dealing with words that are supposed to represent signed vs. unsigned values.

As far as `printf` is concerned, you're absolutely correct that the conversion specifier determines whether the bit pattern `0xFFFF` is *displayed* as `-1` or `4294967295`, although remember that if the type of the argument does not match up with what the conversion specifier expects, then the behavior is undefined.  Using `%u` to display a negative `signed int` may or may not give you the expected equivalent unsigned value.

Comment: What is meant by initializer changes the int type to unsigned type , when does that happen?

Comment: And was this question bad enough to generate -2 , and further block me to post any question for next 6 month.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you seem to have missed the facts that firstly, 0101 = 5 in both signed and unsigned integer values and that secondly, you assigned a negative number to an unsigned int - something your compiler may be smart enough to realise and, therfore, correct to a signed int.

Setting an unsigned int to -5 should technically cause an error because unsigned ints can't store values under 0.

Answer (score 0):

You could understand it better when you try to assign a negative value to a larger sized unsigned integer. Compiler generates the assembly code to do sign extension when transferring small size negative value to larger sized unsigned integer.

[see this blog post for assembly level explanation.](http://www.idryman.org/blog/2012/11/21/integer-promotion/)