# why the output of following c program is -10

Tags: c, printf, unsigned-integer, format-specifiers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned int a = -10;
    printf("a=%d\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

The above code is printing `-10` for signed `int`. If the both signed and unsigned are printing the `-10` then what is difference between them?

Comment: `%d` treats your integer as signed, use `%u` instead.

Comment: The behaviuour of this program is *undefined*. It can print -10, or blow up your computer.

Comment: You are storing a certain bit pattern in `a` (which is a really big number if interpreted as an unsigned int).  But then you tell printf to display the value as if it were signed (that's what %d does).  Since the bit pattern is -10 when interpreted as a signed number that's what printf displays.  You need a different format string for unsigned - try `printf("a=%u\n",a);`

Answer (score 6):

`printf` doesn't know about the type of the argument that you're giving it. With `%d` you're telling it that it's a *signed* `int`, which is wrong. That's undefined behavior - anything could happen. What will likely happen is that it's just interpreting that memory as signed `int` anyway, and with the `unsigned int a=-10;` you set the unsigned int to what will be interpreted as `-10` when read as signed `int`. For further info on what happens with that assignment of a negative number to an unsigned type, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7152835/10411602).

Answer (score 6):

You actually have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in that code.

The `"%d"` format is for plain *signed* `int`, and mismatching format specifier and argument leads to UB.

Since `printf` doesn't have any idea of the *real* types being passed, it has to rely only on the format specifiers. So what probably happens is that the `printf` function simply treats the value as a plain signed `int` and print it as such.

Answer (score -1):

You should use

printf("a=**%u**\n",a);

to print "a" as an unsigned integer

Comment: While this is correct, it doesn't answer the question.