# Why does having unsigned int crash for loop on last iteration?

Tags: c++, for-loop

The following program produces unexpected results

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    for(unsigned int i = 10; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but changing `unsigned int` to just `int` gives the output 10,9,8...,0

What is the correct way to have have an `unsigned int` and use it to iterate over the values [n, 0] (inclusive)? I iterate each element of an array but don't want to use the foreach syntax because I need a variable to hold the position of the element.

Comment: To clarify, **the code does not crash**. It just doesn’t do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your program crashes it means that the compiler is defective.

Decreasing an `unsigned` once it's zero produces the largest number of that type.

The idiom

```
for (unsigned i = 11; i--> 0; )
```

(which when used with the loop body you present will output the integers `10, 9, ..., 0`)

is often used when working with `unsigned` types, although it is falling out of fashion. `-->` is not really an operator in its own right as it's parsed to two separate tokens `--` and `>`, but it's occasionally called the *slide operator*, particularly by older folk such as me.

Comment: It's because `i` is used to access an array

Comment: Ah, classic operator goes to

Comment: @northerner: Yes, that could be undefined behaviour.

Comment: The idiomatic code you’ve posted is different from the code OP is using. In particular, you’re using exclusive `>` rather than inclusive `>=`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: My code prints 10 through to and including 0. Rather hard to compare what the OP wants given their loop is infinite?

Answer (score 5):

*unsigned goes negative*, not correct. Unsigned arithmetic wraps around, so in unsigned arithemetic if you subtract one from zero you get the largest possible unsigned value. What this is depends on your compiler, but if you have 32 bit integers then it would be 4294967295.

I don't think your program should crash, I think it should loop for ever because in unsigned arithmetic `i >= 0` is always true.

Incidentally the way I would write that loop so that it uses unsigned arithmetic correctly is

```
for (unsigned int i = 11; i-- > 0; )
{
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

Comment: Right that makes sense. Then what's the correct way to iterate [n, 0] where the iterator is of type `unsigned int`?

Comment: I just added a paragraph to the answer to show one way.

Comment: @john good fix. But I guess you could also put the `i--` in the place for `iteration_expression` if you want to be more explicit. Also, if you use pre-increment operator, this would fail but, `for (unsigned int i = 11; i > 0; --i)` would not. Is that right?

Comment: @VictorHMartin That version would give you different output, 11 down to 1, instead of 10 down to 0, because you are decrementing after the loop, not before.

Comment: Ah, I see it now. Thanks for the answer @john!

Answer (score 1):

I think your confusion has to do with how for loops operate. Here you can find a [description](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for). The important detail is to understand the every time the loop

```
for (init_statement; condition; iteration_expression){ statement;}
```

is run, the order of the operations are equivalent to the following:

> ```
> {
>  init_statement 
>  while ( condition ) { 
>   statement 
>   iteration_expression ; 
>  }
> }
> ```

It means that `i` is decreased **after** the block of the for loop is executed.

In the case of `int`, when `i = 0`, it runs the code inside it and then, it decreases the value. That way, the next iteration of the loop fails the condition, so it does not print `i = -1`.

Regarding `unsigned int` it never goes negative. If you debug it you will see how, once it reaches 0, instead of having the value -1 that value is converted to unsigned and the result is a big positive value. In particular, 4294967295, if `unsigned int` is 32 bits. You can see the details [in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152759/what-happens-when-i-assign-a-negative-value-to-an-unsigned-int).

And that's why you have "unexpected behaviour" (not for the compiler), because suddenly you have a really big positive number, so you probably have an infinite loop in your hands.