# C - Wrong read after lseek with define expression

Tags: c, lseek

I have a binary file from which I need to read timestamps. In particular, I'm trying to read the last record. Every record is 24 bytes long, the timestamp is in the first 8 bytes. Here's the code I wrote:

```
#define IDX_RS_LEN (unsigned int)(sizeof(unsigned long) * 3)

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   int fd;
   unsigned long rGmte;
   char filename[256];
   int offset;

   fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
   if (fd != -1) {
      offset = lseek(fd, -IDX_RS_LEN, SEEK_END);
      read(fd, &rGmte, sizeof(unsigned long));
      printf("offset:%d\trGmte: %lu\n", offset, rGmte);
   } else {
      printf("Error opening file\n");
   }
   close(fd);

   return 0;
}
```

But this gives me the following output:

> offset:117384 rGmte: 0

Which is wrong. If I replace the expression in the define with the fixed value 24 I get the right output:

> offset:117384 rGmte: 1606314900

Please also note that offset is the same in both cases, but the value read is different.
Any idea?

Comment: you can check return value of `read` in both cases, looks strange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a wrong type to set the position / offset in `lseek`, you should use an `off_t`(`signed long`) not an `unsigned int`.

Take a look to [What happens when I assign a negative value to an unsigned int?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7152759/1606345)

The offset set to `lseek` should be `-24`:

```
printf("Output: %ld\n", -(signed long)(sizeof(unsigned long) * 3));
Output: -24
```

but you are setting

```
printf("Output: %ld\n", -(unsigned int)(sizeof(unsigned long) * 3));
Output: 4294967272
```

Switch from

```
#define IDX_RS_LEN (unsigned int)(sizeof(unsigned long) * 3)

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   int fd;
   unsigned long rGmte;
   char filename[256];
   int offset;

   fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
   if (fd != -1) {
      offset = lseek(fd, -IDX_RS_LEN, SEEK_END);
```

to

```
#define IDX_RS_LEN (sizeof(unsigned long) * 3)

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   int fd;
   unsigned long rGmte;
   char filename[256];
   off_t offset = IDX_RS_LEN;

   fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
   if (fd != -1) {
      offset = lseek(fd, -offset, SEEK_END);
```

and it should work: https://godbolt.org/z/hEG4xx