# bit rotate on unsigned int in c

Tags: c, rotation, bit, bitwise-operators

im trying to write a code to rotate a unsigend int by number of bit (without knowing how many bits is unsigend int)
i write this code -

```
unsigned int left_rottate(unsigned int a, int b){
    int temp;
    int bits_size = size_in_bits()-1;
    b %= bits_size;

    while(b > 0){
        temp = (a>> bits_size)&1;
        a = (a <<1) | temp;
        b--;
    }
    return a;
}
 int size_in_bits()
{
    unsigned int x,
     i = 0;

  x = ~0u;
  while ((x & 1) != 0)
    (i+= 1, x /= 2);
  return (int) i; 
}
```

but i dont get the rigth results.

Comment: "how many bits is unsigned int": `sizeof(unsigned int) * CHAR_BIT`.

Comment: And you get `CHAR_BIT` using `#include <limits.h>`.

Comment: Why use a signed int for temp?

Comment: cant use limits.h because its not standard library

Comment: Whoever told you `limits.h` is not standard is [utterly **WRONG**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.10).  `CHAR_BIT` is [**required** to be defined by any conforming C implementation](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.1).

Comment: If you really can't use `<limits.h>` and `CHAR_BIT`, then you can calculate the size of the type by initializing a variable of the type to 1 and a counter to 1, and then run a loop that shifts left by 1 until the value is zero, incrementing the count each time.  Do it just once and cache the result.  You can probably optimize by shifting by 8 bits per loop, and initializing the count to 8 and incrementing by 8.

Comment: Do note, @JonathanLeffler, that that approach to computing the number of bits in an `unsigned int` is analogous to (albeit different from) the one taken by the `size_in_bits()` function that the OP presents.

Answer (score 0):

by using 2's complement systems you can do this.
so -1 is 0xffffffff (32bit 4byte) 0xffffffffffffffff (64bit 8byte) and so on.
so,

```
unsigned int t = -1; // 0xffff  1111_1111_1111_1111 using forced conversion in 2's complement.
t = t >> 1; // 0x7fff  0111_1111_1111_1111
t = t+1; // 0x8000     1000_0000_0000_0000
```

by doing this you have the leftmost mask with you.

```
11111111111111111011111111110111
^                              ^
left                           right
```

Algorithm:

1. left the leftmost bit using this mask.
2. left shift your number
3. set the bit at 0'th place.

Comment: They could perform that mask computation with an `unsigned int`, but the `t+1` step is not safe (in the sense that it has implementation-defined behavior) when `t` is a (signed) `int`.  However, your algorithm performs only a one-bit rotation, whereas the OP is trying to support multi-bit rotations.  In conjunction with doing that as a sequence of one-bit rotations, they are trying to use the size of `unsigned int` *also* to minimize the number of such rotations that are required.

Comment: @JohnBollinger you miss understood my points. I am only taking left most bit, adding it to right. It is one iteration, user can do multiple of those in a loop. 
The thing i did with t is only to get the mask with given condition of not knowing now many bits the 'int' is made of. Something which looks unsafe is not always unsafe. If you think it is unsafe plz come up with proofs.

Comment: I understand exactly what you said. It is, again, (i) *wrong*, in the minor detail that the computation has implementation-defined behavior for some inputs when performed using a signed integer data type; (ii) not otherwise an improvement over what the OP already has, because they already implement a single-bit rotation as part of their code; and (iii) not useful as an alternative to finding the `unsigned int` size explicitly, because they have a useful computational purpose for that size that requires them to compute it anyway.

Comment: @JohnBollinger have a look [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152759/what-happens-when-i-assign-a-negative-value-to-an-unsigned-int/7152835#7152835) . -1 will always be converted to appropriate type regardless of the type. (only for int , long type)

Comment: Not relevant, unless indirectly in *support* of my point.  Again, the issue around signedness is with your `t+1` when `t` has type `int`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger why bother about sign if you only want to rotate some bits.

Comment: Because you want to get the right answer?  And that the program not crash? You seem not to be grasping that C permits that the original version of your code *not* behave as you describe, regardless of the numeric representation in use.

Comment: @JohnBollinger better come with valid test cases rather than burning newbies who are tyring to contribute to community.

Comment: Better get off your high horse.  Nobody "burned" anybody.  I presume that you originally wrote the code as you did because you didn't know the relevant details of C.  Now you do. And with the revision, you are *also* now giving the OP better advice.  Wins all around.  It's still not the advice they are looking for, but better is better.

Answer (score 0):

> im trying to write a code to rotate a unsigend int by number of bit (without knowing how many bits is unsigend int)

Ok.  Your `size_in_bits()` function is one viable way to determine the number of *value* bits in an `unsigned int`, which is what you need.  In principle (but not in practice) it is in fact more reliable than the `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(unsigned int)` approach suggested to you in comments, because C allows that the representation of `unsigned int` might include one or more padding bits.  In an implementation where `unsigned int` had padding bits, the total number of bits in the representation of `unsigned int`, given by `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(unsigned int)`, would be strictly greater than the number of value bits.

More briefly, `size_in_bits()` is not wrong, though it's *enormously* more expensive than `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(unsigned int)`, which is completely standard and gives the right answer for any implementation you're likely to be using.

So why are you getting incorrect answers?  Presumably, because **this doesn't make any sense**:

> ```
>     int bits_size = size_in_bits()-1;
>     b %= bits_size;
> ```

It would make sense to reduce `b` modulo the size of `unsigned int`, but that's not what you are doing.  You're reducing modulo the size - 1, which is not useful when `b` is initially equal to or greater than the `size_in_bits()`.  As a concrete example, if the unsigned int size were 32 bits, and a 32-bit rotation were requested, then that would reduce `b` to 1, whereas if you want to perform such a reduction then the correct reduced rotation would be `0`.

Additionally, **when `b` is negative, `b %= bits_size` will be <= 0**.  This follows from the definition of the modulus operation:

> When integers are divided, the result of the `/` operator is the
> algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded. If the quotient
> `a/b` is representable, the expression `(a/b)*b + a%b` shall equal `a`

(C17 6.5.5/6)

Because of that and the `while(b > 0)` loop condition, your function will handle all negative `b` arguments as if they were 0.

Here is a variation on your `left_rottate()` [sic] function that should do better:

```
unsigned int left_rottate(unsigned int a, int b){
    static unsigned int bits_size = 0;

    if (bits_size == 0) {
        // compute this once for all
        bits_size = size_in_bits();
    }

    b %= bits_size;

    if (b < 0) {
        // Be sure to choose the non-negative modulus
        b += bits_size;
    }

    while (b > 0) {
        a = (a >> (bits_size - 1)) | (a << 1);
        b--;
    }
    return a;
}
```

But I note that once you reduce `b` to the range [0, `bits_size`), it is wasteful to perform the rotation one bit at a time.  You could easily do it all at once, instead:

```
    // ...

    if (b != 0) {
        a = (a >> (bits_size - b)) | (a << b);
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: hi thank you for your answer, its still dont work for me.. i try the number 174 (10101110) when b is 3 and get the number 1392(10101110000) and not the rigth number that is -117  (01110101 )

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* need to account for `(b < 0)` in this case:

```
#include <limits.h>

unsigned int rol (unsigned int a, int b)
{
    int k = sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT;

    if (b < 0)
        a = a << ((- b) % k) | a >> ((+ b) % k);
    else
        a = a << ((+ b) % k) | a >> ((- b) % k);

    return a;
}
```

With optimizations on, `(k)` will be evaluated at compile time, and as a power of (2) on any modern platform. The compiler might also recognise these operations as rotate instructions if available. gcc-12 (x86-64) gives me:

```
    movl    %esi, %ecx
    movl    %edi, %eax
    rorl    %cl, %eax
    roll    %cl, %edi
    testl   %esi, %esi
    cmovns  %edi, %eax
    ret
```

clang-15 doesn't recognise the pattern. However, if we make the 'power of (2)' assumption, and replace: `% k` with: `& (k - 1)`, clang makes the deduction, generating more-or-less identical code.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the number of bits in an `unsigned int`, you can use the following algorithm (simple and capable to get the number of 1s in an `unsignded` of unknown size --- upto a limit that can be large, as the number of operations is low)

```
unsigned long count_ones(unsigned long n)
{
    /* assume numbers will not be larger than 128bits */
    n = (n & 0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaUL) >>  1) + (n & 0x5555555555555555UL);
    n = (n & 0xccccccccccccccccUL) >>  2) + (n & 0x3333333333333333UL);
    n = (n & 0xf0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0UL) >>  4) + (n & 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0fUL);
    n = (n & 0xff00ff00ff00ff00UL) >>  8) + (n & 0x00ff00ff00ff00ffUL);
    n = (n & 0xffff0000ffff0000UL) >> 16) + (n & 0x0000ffff0000ffffUL);
    n = (n & 0xffffffff00000000UL) >> 32) + (n & 0x00000000ffffffffUL);
    return n;
}
```

you can get the number of bits of any `unsigned` integer by calling the above function as:

```
     unsigned nbits = count_ones((the_unsigned_type_you_want_to_measure) ~0UL);
```

I suggest you to cache the value as suggested in John Bollinger's answer, as the statements above don't need to be called twice, but it is very efficient code (it translates into a small list of machine instructions with no loops, very efficient)

Once you have the number of bits to rotate (and the number of bits to complete a full rotation) I recommend you to this code:

```
unsigned long rotate_bits(unsigned long n, unsigned bits_to_rotate)
{
    static int nbits = 0;
    if (nbits == 0) {
        /* the static nature of nbits makes to call only once to the function below */
        nbits = count_ones((unsigned long) ~0UL);
    }
    bits_to_rotate %= totalbits;  /* so we don't overflow */
    return (n << bits_to_rotate) | (n >> (nbits - bits_to_rotate));
}
```