# reinterpret_cast rvalue and optimization

Tags: c++, casting

I am converting a bunch of code over to use C++-style casts (with the help of `-Wold-style-cast`).  I'm not entirely sold on its use for primitive variables, but I'm new to C++-style casts in general.

One issue occurs in some endian converting code.  The current code looks like this:

```
#define REINTERPRET_VARIABLE(VAR,TYPE) (*((TYPE*)(&VAR)))

//...

uint16_t reverse(uint16_t val) { /*stuff to reverse uint16_t*/ }
 int16_t reverse( int16_t val) {
    uint16_t temp = reverse(REINTERPRET_VARIABLE(val,uint16_t));
    return REINTERPRET_VARIABLE(temp,int16_t);
}
```

Now, endianness doesn't care about signedness.  Therefore, to reverse an `int16_t`, we can treat it exactly like a `uint16_t` for the purposes of the reversal.  This suggests code like this:

```
 int16_t reverse( int16_t val) {
    return reinterpret_cast<int16_t>(reverse(reinterpret_cast<uint16_t>(val)));
}
```

However, as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464347/interpreting-a-uint16-t-as-a-int16-t) and in particular [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14623266/why-cant-i-reinterpret-cast-uint-to-int) question, `reinterpret_cast` requires a reference or a pointer (unless it's casting to itself).   This suggests:

```
 int16_t reverse( int16_t val) {
    return reinterpret_cast<int16_t&>(reverse(reinterpret_cast<uint16_t&>(val)));
}
```

This doesn't work because, as my compiler tells me, the outside cast wants an lvalue.  To fix this, you'd need to do something like:

```
 int16_t reverse( int16_t val) {
    uint16_t temp = reverse(reinterpret_cast<uint16_t&>(val));
    return reinterpret_cast<int16_t&>(temp);
}
```

This is not much different from the original code, and indeed the temporary variable exists for the same reason, but four questions were raised for me:

1. Why is a temporary even necessary for a `reinterpret_cast`?  I can understand a dumb compiler's needing to have a temporary to support the pointer nastiness of `REINTERPRET_VARIABLE`, but `reinterpret_cast` is supposed to just reinterpret bits.  Is this clashing with RVO or something?
2. Will requiring that temporary incur a performance penalty, or is it likely that the compiler can figure out that the temporary really should just be the return value?
3. The second `reinterpret_cast` looks like it's returning a reference.  Since the function return value isn't a reference, I'm pretty sure this is okay; the return value will be a copy, not a reference.  However, I would still like to know what casting to a reference really even means?  It *is* appropriate in this case, right?
4. Are there any other performance implications I should be aware of?  I'd guess that `reinterpret_cast` would be, if anything, faster since the compiler doesn't need to figure out that the bits should be reinterpreted--I just *tell* it that they should?

Comment: I'd be surprised if your compiler suite doesn't already provide some byte-swap functions/macros for you... GCC provides a header named `byteswap.h` that contains 16/32/64-bit byte swap implementations. Other compilers may put them in a different header...

Comment: Indeed, I encounter the same issue. I wonder do you have any idea now?

Comment: @astroboylrx See newly malloced answer.

Comment: It would be better if you can attempt to avoid casts entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no one has answered this with language-lawyery facts in two years, I'll answer it instead with my educated guesses.

1. Who knows.  But it's apparently necessary, as you've surmised.  To avoid [issues with strict aliasing](http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/StrictAliasing.html), it would be safest to use `memcpy`, which will be optimized correctly by any compiler.
2. The answer to any such question is always to profile it and to check the disassembly.  In the example you gave, e.g. GCC [will optimize it to](https://godbolt.org/g/FHJeGk):

   ```
   reverse(short):
       mov     eax, edi
       rol     ax, 8
       ret
   ```

   Which looks pretty optimal (the `mov` is for copying from the input register; if you inline your function and use it, you'll see it is absent entirely).
3. This is a language lawyer question.  Probably has some useful semantic meaning.  Don't worry about it.  You haven't written code like this since.
4. Again, profile.  Maybe reinterpret casting gets in the way of certain optimizations.  You should follow the same guidelines as you would for strict aliasing, mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you for adding this answer  :-)   
For sure, if possible, memcpy would be the first option.

Answer (score 3):

1. `temp` is required because the `&` (address-of) operator is applied to it on the next line. This operator requires an lvalue (the object to take the address of).
2. I'd expect the compiler to optimize it out.
3. `reinterpret_cast<T&>(x)` is the same as `* reinterpret_cast<T *>(&x)`, it is an lvalue designating the same memory location as `x` occupies.  Note that the type of an expression is never a reference; but the result of casting to `T&`, or of using the `*` operator is an lvalue.
4. I wouldn't expect any performance issues.

There are no strict aliasing problems with this particular piece of code, because it is allowed to alias an integer type as the signed or unsigned variation of the same type.  But you suggest the codebase is full of reinterpret casts, so you should keep your eye out for strict aliasing violations elsewhere, perhaps compile with `-fno-strict-aliasing` until it is sorted out.

Comment: If you can explain _why_ 1 is that way, and add the bit about profiling from my answer to 2, I'll accept this answer. Re: strict aliasing, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14623406/688624). It's only okay if cstdint typedefs std types (which is _probably_ true, but maybe not).