# Convert unsigned int to signed int C

Tags: c, int, unsigned-integer

I am trying to convert `65529` from an `unsigned int` to a signed `int`. I tried doing a cast like this:

```
unsigned int x = 65529;
int y = (int) x;
```

But `y` is still returning 65529 when it should return -7. Why is that?

Comment: You could try this: `y=(int)x<<(sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT-16)>>(sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT-16);`. Should work on most platforms.

Comment: 32-bit era has come decades ago. If you're still using ancient compiler for DOS or embedded systems where int has 16 bits then the result may be as you expected

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605/signed-to-unsigned-conversion-in-c-is-it-always-safe

Comment: Why would it be `-7`? `int` is typically 32-bits wide so 65539 is nowhere even close to overflowing it.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It seems like you are expecting `int` and `unsigned int` to be a 16-bit integer. That's apparently not the case. Most likely, it's a 32-bit integer - which is large enough to avoid the wrap-around that you're expecting.

Note that there is no fully C-compliant way to do this because casting between signed/unsigned for values out of range is implementation-defined. But this will still work in most cases:

```
unsigned int x = 65529;
int y = (short) x;      //  If short is a 16-bit integer.
```

or alternatively:

```
unsigned int x = 65529;
int y = (int16_t) x;    //  This is defined in <stdint.h>
```

Comment: If you can guarantee that `short` is a 16-bit integer, then yes, int `y = (short)x;` will work. Or you can use `int16_t` if your compiler has the `<stdint.h>` header.

Comment: @Nayefc As I said, you can check the size of your types by printing the value of `sizeof(int)` `sizeof(short)` or whichever you need

Comment: There is a mostly C-compliant way to do it: `y = x < 32767 ? (int)x : (x > 32768 ? -(int)-x : -32768);` (the only wrinkle is that `-32768` is not necessarily representable as a signed int, so you have to decide how to treat that).

Comment: Yeah, that works too - albeit a dirtier approach. I didn't think about going all the way to branching to do it...

Comment: @Mysticial: It won't branch on a decent compiler.

Comment: Erk can't edit comment now but that first `32767` should be a `32768`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I just tried it in VS2010 with full optimizations on x64. You're right, it doesn't branch. As I was half-expecting, it compiled to a bunch of `cmp` and `cmov` instructions. So it's smart enough to get rid of the branches, but not smart enough to turn it into a single `movsx` sign-extension. EDIT: Even with the first `32767` changed to `32768`.

Answer (score 6):

I know it's an old question, but it's a good one, so how about this?

```
unsigned short int x = 65529U;
short int y = *(short int*)&x;

printf("%d\n", y);
```

This works because we are casting the address of `x` to the signed version of it's type, that's permitted by the C standard. Not all type punning like this (most in fact) is legal. The standard says this.

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue that has one of the following types:
>
> - the declared type of the object,
> - a qualified version of the declared type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the declared type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the declared type of the object,
> - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union),
> - a character type.

So, alas, since we are accessing the bits of `x` as if they were a signed (via the pointer), the actual conversion operation is replaced by reading what appears to be just a negative signed short, and conversion takes place without issue. However, it's possible for this to screw up on a one's complement machine, but those are so, so rare, and so, so obsolete, I wouldn't even bother with looking out for them.

Comment: @pm89 I don't know about your definition of "works", but at least a compiler implementation could target a system with 1-s complement instead of 2-complement integers. For such a system, the solution would **work**, but it would result in **different values**. On the other hand, a compiler could define `short` to be 32bit size. In this case, the value would stay positive after the cast. Of course none of this is relevant if you take one of todays matured compilers and a standard x86/x64 hardware. Just don't be ignorant to the standard when talking about *regardless of compiler implementation*

Comment: @pm89 the accepted answer is explicit about the implementation defined behavior, so it has the same theoretical problems but it doesn't claim to produce the same results for any implementation oft the standard.

Answer (score 5):

@Mysticial got it. A short is usually 16-bit and will illustrate the answer:

```
int main()  
{
    unsigned int x = 65529;
    int y = (int) x;
    printf("%d\n", y);

    unsigned short z = 65529;
    short zz = (short)z;
    printf("%d\n", zz);
}

65529
-7
Press any key to continue . . .
```

---

A little more detail. It's all about how signed numbers are stored in memory. Do a search for twos-complement notation for more detail, but here are the basics.

So let's look at 65529 decimal. It can be represented as `FFF9h` in hexadecimal. We can also represent that in binary as:

`11111111 11111001`

When we declare `short zz = 65529;`, the compiler interprets 65529 as a signed value. In twos-complement notation, the top bit signifies whether a signed value is positive or negative. In this case, you can see the top bit is a `1`, so it is treated as a negative number. That's why it prints out `-7`.

For an `unsigned short`, we don't care about sign since it's `unsigned`. So when we print it out using `%d`, we use all 16 bits, so it's interpreted as `65529`.

Answer (score 2):

To understand why, you need to know that the CPU represents signed numbers using the two's complement (maybe not all, but many).

```
    byte n = 1; //0000 0001 =  1
    n = ~n + 1; //1111 1110 + 0000 0001 = 1111 1111 = -1
```

And also, that the type int and unsigned int can be of different sized depending on your CPU. When doing specific stuff like this:

```
   #include <stdint.h>
   int8_t ibyte;
   uint8_t ubyte;
   int16_t iword;
   //......
```

Answer (score 1):

The representation of the values 65529u and -7 are identical for 16-bit ints. Only the interpretation of the bits is different.

For larger ints and these values, you need to sign extend; one way is with logical operations

```
int y = (int )(x | 0xffff0000u); // assumes 16 to 32 extension, x is > 32767
```

If speed is not an issue, or divide is fast on your processor,

```
int y = ((int ) (x * 65536u)) / 65536;
```

The multiply shifts left 16 bits (again, assuming 16 to 32 extension), and the divide shifts right maintaining the sign.

Comment: This only works on little endian two's complement systems.

Comment: The questioner's machine is two's complement as evidenced by the values he reported. Endianess has nothing to do with it; I am only using int valves here, not individual bytes from memory.

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting that your `int` type is 16 bit wide, in which case you'd indeed get a negative value.  But most likely it's 32 bits wide, so a signed `int` can represent 65529 just fine.  You can check this by printing `sizeof(int)`.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question posted in the comment above - try something like this:

```
unsigned short int x = 65529U;
short int y = (short int)x;

printf("%d\n", y);
```

or

```
unsigned short int x = 65529U;
short int y = 0;

memcpy(&y, &x, sizeof(short int);
printf("%d\n", y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since converting unsigned values use to represent positive numbers converting it can be done by setting the most significant bit to 0. Therefore a program will not interpret that as a Two`s complement value. One caveat is that this will lose information for numbers that near max of the unsigned type.

```
template <typename TUnsigned, typename TSinged>
TSinged UnsignedToSigned(TUnsigned val)
{
    return val & ~(1 << ((sizeof(TUnsigned) * 8) - 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I think the responders may have misinterpreted it. I think what was intended was to convert a 16-digit bit sequence received as an unsigned integer (technically, an `unsigned short`) into a signed integer.  This might happen (it recently did to me) when you need to convert something received from a network from network byte order to host byte order.  In that case, use a union:

```
unsigned short value_from_network;
unsigned short host_val = ntohs(value_from_network);
// Now suppose host_val is 65529.
union SignedUnsigned {
  short          s_int;
  unsigned short us_int;
};
SignedUnsigned su;
su.us_int = host_val;
short minus_seven = su.s_int;
```

And now `minus_seven` has the value -7.

Comment: It isn't clear that OP required 16 bits, only that the conversion from `unsigned` to `signed` did not go as expected. Aside from that storing an out of range unsigned value in a signed type is always implementation-defined behavior, `short` and `unsigned short` are not required to be 16 bits wide; they are required to be a _minimum_ of 16 bits wide. If you require exact widths, use an exact width type such as `int16_t` or `uint16_t`. Note that the exact width types are optional types that are nonetheless supported on common platforms.

Comment: A `short` is not guaranteed to be 16 bits (although it probably will be on most platforms). If you want 16 bits, why not use the standard types `uint16_t` and `int16_t`, which ARE guaranteed to be 16 bits? Even the return type of `ntohs()` is `uint16_t`, for good reason. The union is a nice trick, but seems overly complicated. A cast/conversion from `uint16_t` to `int16_t` will have the same effect and is much more descriptive (and probably more efficient, depending on compiler and compiler options).