# How to use fgets() to avoid casting its second argument which is of type int?

Tags: c, casting

The declaration of the `fgets` function look like this:

```
char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream);
```

This means that the second argument is expected to be an `int`.

Which is the proper way to avoid this casting in the following program?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *buffer = "Michi";
    size_t len = strlen(buffer) + 1;
    char arr[len];

    printf("Type your Input:> ");
    if (fgets(arr, (int)len, stdin) == NULL) {
        printf("Error, fgets\n");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        printf("Arr = %s\n", arr);
    }
}
```

Here I used `(int)len` which looks fine, but what happens if `buffer` stores a very long string?

Lets say:

```
const char *buffer = "Very long long ..."; /* where length is beyond the range of the `int` type */
```

I already declared length of the type `size_t` which is fine here, but if I'll pass it to `fgets` is not OK because of:

```
conversion to ‘int’ from ‘size_t {aka long unsigned int}’ may alter its value
```

and if I cast it to `int` won't fit because the size of the `int` is smaller than the size of `length` and some information will be lost.

Maybe I'm missing something here...

Any way how should I avoid this situation?

Comment: Just saying, in that case, are you sure `char arr[len];` will work properly? It's on stack with gcc, anyways..

Comment: @SouravGhosh I could use malloc here , but the question is not about that

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317295/convert-unsigned-int-to-signed-int-c is helpful for you.

Comment: @Serhio Does that include `long unsigned int` too?

Comment: @Michi I think so. ... casting between signed/unsigned for values out of range is implementation-defined ... The only criteria is being out of range of destination type, regardless of `long` or `short` modifiers.

Comment: @Serhio could you provide an Example where I can check it?

Comment: In practice I've often come across: (1)`*buffer` being allocated to some reasonable size and file (stream) read in chunks of buffer size and transferred elsewhere, whereas casting `size_t` to `int` wouldn't compromise a temporary stack variable. (2) length of file known, "`*buffer`" memory is dynamically allocated upon size of file with entire content of file transferred to "buffer".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
char *fgets(char * restrict s, int n, FILE * restrict stream);
```

With `fgets()`, the input buffer `s[INT_MAX]` and beyond cannot be used.

---

OP's `size_t len` code could avoid the `int` cast of `len` by converting to a string and converting back to an `int`, that is just wasteful.  A cast is the right thing to do.

Rather than littering code with a `(int)`, reduce/control its usage and wrap the cast in a limiting helper function.

```
int fgets_len(size_t len) {
  return (len < INT_MAX) ? (int) len : INT_MAX;
}


size_t len = something_big;
char *arr = malloc(len);

...   
if ( fgets(arr, fgets_len(len), stdin) == NULL){
    printf("Error, Fgets\n");
    exit(1);
}else{
    printf("Arr = '%s'\n", arr);
}
```

If code truly needs to read *long* lines, consider `ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);` as defined [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html).  Note this is a non-standard C library function, yet its source code is readily available.

---

Concerning pedantic use of `fgets()`, there are at least 2 reasons for `fgets()` to return `NULL`: End-of-file and input error.  Now consider the corner case using OP's code

```
size_t len = strlen("") + 1;
char arr[len];
if ( fgets(arr, (int)len, stdin) == NULL){
```

and pathological cases like

```
if ( fgets(arr, 0, stdin) == NULL){
if ( fgets(arr, -1, stdin) == NULL){
```

Both are discussed at [Is fgets() returning NULL with a short bufffer compliant?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23388620/2410359)

Comment: *With `fgets()`, the input buffer `s[INT_MAX]` and beyond cannot be used.*: more precisely, a buffer of any size can be used, but if it is longer than `INT_MAX` its size cannot be used directly.  Note that `s[INT_MAX]` is not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid the trouble of integer overflow, you can do value checking and act accordingly. Note that, since `strlen()` returns value of type `size_t` you have 2 options. Either declare a variable of type `int` and assign it the return value of `strlen()`, which will do an implicit conversion from type `size_t` to `int`, or cast as you did in you function invocation.

Here is a possible solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char *buffer = "Michi";
    //size_t len = strlen(buffer) + 1;
    size_t len = 9999999999;

    if (len > INT_MAX) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, length exceeded desired value.Aborting...\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char arr[len];

    printf("Type your Input:> ");
    if (fgets(arr, (int)len, stdin) == NULL) {
        printf("Error, Fgets\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        printf("Arr = %s\n", arr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I already know that `len > INT_MAX` so here `if (len > INT_MAX)` my program will stop working which is wrong.

Comment: @Michi - If you call `fgets` with `n <= 0`, it will return `NULL` without even waiting for input so your program will terminate anyway. So the best thing to do, is to check `len` before going.

Comment: @Michi - Also the `size_t` to `int` could end up with a positive but meaningless value. Example `0x100000003` could become `3` which would make your program behave strange. So check that `len` doesn't exceed `INT_MAX` before doing the call.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't bother to link the dimension of the argument to `fgets()` with the dimension of `buffer` at all.

Instead, I'd ensure that the buffer being used for reading has a length that can be represented using an `int`  (say, does not exceed INT_MAX).    If you want to be truly portable, ensure the buffer length does not exceed `32767` (the standard specifies that the minimum allowed value of `INT_MAX` is `32767`).

Then make use of the fact that `fgets()` will read a line in parts, if the line length exceeds the buffer length.

For example, assuming that `len` exceeds the length of any line being read from `stdin`;

```
char arr[len] = {0};   
char read_buffer[10];    /*   I'm reasonably confident that 10 < 32767 */

while (fgets(read_buffer, 10, stdin) != NULL)
{
      size_t read_length = strlen(read_buffer);
      if (read_length > 0)
      {
           if (read_buffer[read_length-1] != `\n`)
           {
               strcat(arr, read_buffer);
           }
           else
           {
               strncat(arr, read_buffer, read_length-1);

               printf("Arr = %s\n", arr);

               arr[0] = '\0';    /*  clear arr so next line may be read */

               /*  break here if want to stop reading after the first line */

           }
      }
```

Note that, if end of file is not immediately preceded by a `'\n'`, then the above will discard the text after the last `'\n'`.

In the above, replacing `fgets(read_buffer, 10, stdin)` with `fgets(read_buffer, sizeof read_buffer, stdin)` is safe, since a `size_t` with value less than or equal to `INT_MAX` can always safely be converted to `int`.    So, if you want to shut up a compiler from issuing warnings, you can safely cast i.e.  `fgets(read_buffer, (int)(sizeof read_buffer), stdin)`

Answer (score 0):

[Draft](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#A.6.3.4) says that

> The result of converting an integer to a shorter signed integer, or
>   the result of converting an unsigned integer to a signed integer of
>   equal length, if the value cannot be represented

is implementation-defined. As result if you want safely convert value of unsigned type to signed - you must ensure that all possible source values can be represented with target, signed type.