# Can you convert a signed char array to an unsigned integer?

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion

I have a unsigned int that was converted to a signed char like this

```
  unsigned int b = 128;
  char a[4];    

  a[0] = b >> 24;
  a[1] = b >> 16;
  a[2] = b >> 8;
  a[3] = b >> 0;
```

Without knowing what value of `b` is, can I get back the number? The method below fails for numbers greater than 128. It seems like there is some ambiguity to getting the number back from the array.

```
  unsigned int c = 0;  
  c += a[0] << 24;
  c += a[1] << 16;
  c += a[2] << 8;
  c += a[3];

  cout<<c<<endl;
```

Comment: You need an `unsigned char` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unsigned int c = ((a[0] << 24) & 0xFF000000U)
               | ((a[1] << 16) & 0x00FF0000U)
               | ((a[2] <<  8) & 0x0000FF00U)
               | ( a[3]        & 0x000000FFU);
```

or

```
unsigned int c = unsigned(a[0]) << 24
               | unsigned(a[1]) << 16
               | unsigned(a[2]) <<  8
               | unsigned(a[3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting `signed` to `unsigned` is not advised.  If you do want to do it, you have to do it manually.  Not easy, AFAIK.

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605/signed-to-unsigned-conversion-in-c-is-it-always-safe) question.