# adding unsigned int to int

Tags: c++, types, int, unsigned-integer

```
#include <iostream>
int main ()
{
    using namespace std;
    unsigned int i = 4;
    int a = -40;
    cout<<a+i<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Executing this gives me 4294967260

I know there's a conversion taking place, from a signed int to unsigned int,
but how  and why this particular value?
I noticed it's close to the sum of | 2147483647 | +  2147483647

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605/signed-to-unsigned-conversion-in-c-is-it-always-safe) one too.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When an `unsigned int` and an `int` are added together, the `int` is first converted to `unsigned int` before the addition takes place (and the result is also an `unsigned int`).

-1, while being the first negative number, is actually equivalent to the largest unsigned number - that is, `(unsigned int) -1 === UINT_MAX`.

-2 in unsigned form is `UINT_MAX - 1`, and so on, so `-40 === UINT_MAX - 39 === 4294967256` (when using 32bit ints).

Of course, adding 4 then gives your answer:
`4294967256 + 4 = 4294967260`.

This is a great quiz where you can learn some of the rules of integers in C (and similarly C++): http://blog.regehr.org/archives/721

Comment: Correct. An alternative to this is to turn the 4 into an int and then add them, then if you want an unsigned int do an if block that if the result is >= 0 then it is converted to an unsigned int.

Comment: Why does the `int` is converted to `unsigned` and not the way around?

Comment: For two's complement you end up with the same bit pattern -- the context of the result (which evidently is unsigned by default) determines whether the result is signed or unsigned.

Answer (score 1):

Represent i and a in hexadecimal:

```
i =   4: 0x 0000 0004
a = -40: 0x FFFF FFD8
```

Following the implicit conversion rules of C++, **a** in **a + i** will be cast to unsigned int, that is, 4294967256. So **a + i = 4294967260**