# Does multiplying unsigned short cause undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, c++11, types, casting, integer-promotion

As a follow-up to "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33732041/why-static-castunsigned-intushrt-maxushrt-max-yields-correct-value"

I was asking myself if promoting all types (except some exceptions) with a lower rank than `int` to `int` to perform arithmetic operations might cause UB in some cases.

e.g.:

```
unsigned short a = 0xFFFF;
unsigned short b = a*a;
```

As unsigned short is promoted to `int` for arithmetic operations this would result in:

```
unsigned short a = 0xFFFF;
unsigned short b = (int)a*(int)a;
```

As `(int)0xFFFF*(int)0xFFFF` causes an overflow, and overflow of signed types is UB: **Can multiplying two unsigned shorts `x,y` cause undefined behaviour in the case that `x*y > INT_MAX`**

---

**UPDATE**:

The question specifically aims at the case that `int` is 32-bit and `short` is 16-bit.

Comment: Yes. The upshot is to not do arithmetic with unsigned types of lower conversion rank than `int`. A simpler rule is to not use unsigned types for numbers, but do use them for bit-fiddling.

Comment: Yes, this is signed integer overflow causing UB. An annoying historical wart, and it can strike in disguise because `uint16_t` is often implemented as a typedef for `unsigned short`.  Theoretically the same problem could even occur with `uint32_t`, as there is nothing stopping a compiler making `short` be 32-bit on a system with 64-bit `int` for example.

Comment: @M.M: Actually there is nothing special about `short` here. Just any unsigned type smaller than `int` will be promoted to `int` before arithmetic operations take place. In particular this goes for `uint32_t` if `int` is 64-bit.

Comment: I think you can (theoretically) incur the same UB by multiplying to `size_t`s, since I didn't find a constraint in the standard that it must be at least as big as int. https://twitter.com/fugueish/status/637715389519015941

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C++11 §3.9.1/4, full quote:

> **”** Unsigned integers, declared `unsigned`, shall obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2<sup>*n*</sup> where *n* is the number
>   of bits in the value representation of that particular size of integer.

Apart from the slightly misleading wording about “declared `unsigned`” this might seem to apply that every arithmetic expression that involve only argument of some given unsigned type, will yield a result modulo 2<sup>*n*</sup> for that type.

However, there are no arithmetic expressions at all for unsigned types of lower conversion rank than `int`: all arguments in an apparent such expression are converted up to <sup>(1)</sup>at least `int`, or depending on the number ranges of the C++ implementation, up to `unsigned int`.

As a result, `a*b` where `a` and `b` are `unsigned short` values, <sup>(2)</sup>can have formally Undefined Behavior. Because it's not an `unsigned short` expression. It's (in practice) an `int` expression.

That said, with a reasonable compiler that doesn't introduce special casing where it notices formal UB, and with in-practice 8 bit bytes and `unsigned short` max value that is representable by `int`, and common two's complement signed integer representation, the result, when converted back down to `unsigned short`, will be *as if* it was modular arithmetic in the range of `unsigned short`. That's because two's complement, at the machine code level, is just modular arithmetic with a range centered on 0.

---

<sup><sup>(1)</sup> In practice one will usually be using an 8 bits-per-byte implementation where the maximum value of `unsigned short` fits well within the `int` range, so in practice we're talking about a conversion up to `int`.

<sup>(2)</sup> E.g., for 16-bit `unsigned short` and 32-bit `int`, (2<sup>16</sup>−1)<sup>2</sup> = 2<sup>32</sup>−2×2<sup>16</sup>+1 > 2<sup>31</sup>−1, where the last value is the maximum positive `int` value.</sup>

Comment: Any idea why unsigned types aren't just promoted to `unsigned int`? This would solve the problem.

Comment: @SimonKraemer: I don't know. But as I recall James Kanze once remarked that the conversion rules were changed early on. That was in connection with the problems of mixing signed and unsigned in expressions.

Comment: Well, it shouldn't matter in real life. Thanks for digging up the rules.

Comment: Unfortunately C compilers are generally not reasonable according to your definition.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: It would be nice with at least one example compatible with your assertion. Here's an example where the gcc compiler, *for the given code*, is reasonable: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/036e12a08cedfd95

Comment: @Alf If there is one thing I learned about C/C++ compilers, it's to never mess with UB. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0217d57fe15e355e

Comment: @CodesInChaos: So, gcc uses the UB to optimize in some output that's contradicted by the identical final results. Jeez! Thanks. And that's common for C compilers? Unable to reproduce with MSVC, though.

Comment: @Alf the canonical example is optimizing `x + 1 > x` to `true` for signed integers. Controlled by [`-fstrict-overflow`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) which is part of `-O2` for GCC. See also [What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior #2/3](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_14.html) on the LLVM blog.

Comment: @SimonKraemer unsigned ints sometimes have surprising semantics in comparisons, as Alf alluded to. consider (on a 32-bit processor),  `ushortvar < intvar` where intvar is -1. This will always be false, as expected, since `ushortvar` is promoted to int, in the range 0..65535. If it instead gets promoted to `unsigned` in range 0..65535, the comparison will be true, since it becomes `(unsigned)ushortvar < (unsigned)-1` and `(unsigned)-1` is 0xFFFFFFFFu.  Another way to look at this: unsigned short is a reduced range int (unless it is the same width as int :-) )

Comment: Downvoted for the dangerously incorrect "reasonable compiler" final paragraph, as per @CodesInChaos comments. Ignoring "formal UB" might be OK if you never compile with optimizations turned on, but even then it wouldn't be my recommendation.

Answer (score 3):

When you multiply `unsigned short * unsigned short` then there is an [implicit conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast) and the value is casted to `int` in C++11. The [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast#Numeric_promotions) says:

> Prvalues of small integral types (such as char) may be converted to
>   prvalues of larger integral types (such as int). In particular,
>   arithmetic operators **do not accept types smaller than int** as arguments

So it will result in an Undefined behavior.